# The Game of Towns

Tags: king-of-the-hill

## Introduction

The game takes place in a small world with different towns. The rulers of the towns hate each other and would like to rule the world. The people are divided into two groups, warriors and lowborns. However, lowborns can raise to warriors. You are the ruler of three of these towns.

## Gameplay

When the game begins, you rule over three towns. In each town, there are 100 people. You have to divide them into knights and lowborns.

Then the actual game begins, which is turn-based. A turn looks like this: `"Produce" knights` => `execute command of first town` => `execute command of next town` (repeat for all towns) => `try a rebellion`.

- Each turn, your program will be invoked **for each town that belongs to you**. You can either **attack a town**, **support a town** or simply **wait**. These actions will be executed sequentially, not simultaneously.
- Every third turn, you get one knight per 2 lowborns (23 lowborns => 11 knights). The amount of lowborns stays the same.
- Knights inside a town have a defense bonus of 1.2. If you get attacked, your knights will be multiplied by this number (e.g. you have `78 knights`, you will have `93 knights` during the attack). After the attack, the extra knights will be removed (if `82 knights` survive, you will still have `78 knights`).
- In an attack, each knight kills an enemy before he dies. For example: `30 knights` attack `100 knights` (without defense bonus) => 70 knights survive.
- You can **capture a town by killing all knights inside it**. All lowborns belong to you now and your surviving knights are stationed in the town. On the next round, **you can rule this town in addition to all your other towns**.
- After a town is captured, it won't have a defense bonus for 2 full turns (because the gates are broken). On the third turn, the gates will be repaired.
- To prevent the lowborns from rebelling, you need atleast half as much knights as there are lowborns (23 lowborns in a town need atleast 12 knights in the same town). Otherwise, the lowborns will kill all the knights and the town becomes "neutral" (without a leader, indicated by a PlayerId `-1`).
- Neutral towns will "produce" knights, but will not attack nor support any other town.

## Syntax

The controller provides you with input via command arguments, your program has to output via stdout.

**Output (preparation)**
Before the game starts, the controller invokes you submission without arguments. This means you have to distribute your 100 people (for each town) into knights and lowborns. You need to output `KnightCount KnightCount KnightCount`, for example `95 80 95`.

**Input**
`Round;YourPlayerId;YourTownId;PlayerId_TownId_knights_lowborns;PlayerId_TownId_knights_lowborns;...`
On the first round, this will be something like 
`1;2;2;0_0_100_0;1_1_50_50;2_2_80_20`. Here, you see it is the first round, you are player 2 in town 2. You have 80 knights and 20 lowborns.

Later in the game, it could be something like `20;2;1;0_0_100_0;2_1_30_50;2_2_40_20`. You are still player 2 (this never changes), but you captured town 1 (which you are controlling right now).

**Output**
`A TownId NumberOfKnights` or `S TownId NumberOfKnights` or `W` (for wait). 
Example: `A 2 100` (attack town 2 with 100 knights) or `S 3 2` (support town 3 with 2 knights).

## Rules

- Bots should not be written to beat or support specific other bots.
- **Writing to files is allowed.** Please write to "*yoursubmissionname*.txt", the folder will be emptied
  before a game starts. Other external resources are disallowed.
- Your submission has 1 second to respond (per town).
- Provide commands to compile and run your submissions.

## Winning

Winner is the one with the most towns after 100 rounds. If a player captures all towns, the game stops and he wins. If multiple players have the same amount of towns, the amount of knights will count, then the amount of lowborns.

## Controller

[You can find the controller on github.](https://github.com/CommonGuy/GameOfTowns) It also contains 2 samplebots, written in Java. Open it in Eclipse, place the compiled bots in the root folder and add a class to the control program (just like the samplebots).

## Results

For the final results, I ran 10 games. This is the average:

```
    Player           Towns 
 1. Liberator         37.5
 2. Sehtimianer        8.2
 3. SuperProducer      5.4
 4. Sleeper            1.4
 5. Frankenstein       1.2
 6. Butter             0.8 (more knights)
 7. TheKing            0.8 (less knights)
 8. Exodus             0.6
 9. Turtle             0.5 (more knights)
10. AttackOn3          0.5 (less knights)
11. Democracy          0.3
12. CalculatedFail     0.2
13. Revolutionist      0.1
```

You can read a sample game here: [sample game on github](https://github.com/CommonGuy/GameOfTowns/blob/master/_sample_game.txt)

Comment: I assume that when a town `A` supports another town `B`, the given number of knights is simply transferred from `A` to `B`, after which they are controlled by the owner of `B`, correct?

Comment: @Zgarb Correct :)

Comment: Will you be conducting matches and showing a leaderboard?

Comment: @CarpetPython Of course, I post it as soon as I have time

Comment: @Manu, I have to say I love your KOTHs. THIS is my type of Codegolf.SE questions. Until when are you accepting submissions? I'll start thinking of an algorithm now. Also, I think you should add another rule - max number of submissions per user.

Comment: @MarkGabriel I will add a bounty in some days. When it runs out, it is awarded to the winner. At the moment, there aren't many submissions, so I won't add that rule yet ;)

Comment: No prob. I have a question about the game loop, which would be answerable if I checked the code but sadly I don't have much time now. Haha! Let's say Town 2 wants to attack using 100 knights. However, before Town 2, Town 1 attacks Town 2 and reduces Town 2's knights to 80. Will Town 2's turn be skipped or will Town 2 still continue his action but with only 80 knights?

Comment: @MarkGabriel Since the game is sequential, Town 1 will attack first. Then the controller calls Town 2 and asks it what to do (Town 2 should now know it only has 80 knights). If Town 2 still attacks with 100 knights, the attack will be cancelled (it is treated as "wait").

Comment: I see. That answers my question. Thanks @Manu

Comment: How many times will the simulation be ran?

Comment: @TheBestOne the final simulation will be ran 10 times, but in the meantime there will be 3 runs.

Comment: The description of this game reminds me of TribalWars (an online game where each player starts with one town.) Don't play it. If you want to play to win in the late game, you'll have to forfeit sleeping. And probably working, too.

Comment: Deleted post until can confirm for all cases.

Comment: You should probably shuffle the players before each game. I don't think you're using the new version of Frankenstein.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Python3, Liberator

```
from sys import argv
from math import ceil, floor

class OppressedTown:
    def __init__(self, owner_id, id, oppressors, oppressed):
        self.owner_id = owner_id
        self.id = id
        self.oppressors = oppressors
        self.oppressed = oppressed

    def get_free_oppressors(self):
        return self.oppressors - ceil(self.oppressed / 2)

    def get_needed_liberators(self):
        return ceil(self.oppressed / 2)

class LiberatedTown:
    def __init__(self, owner_id, id, liberators, liberated):
        self.owner_id = owner_id
        self.id = id
        self.liberators = liberators
        self.liberated = liberated

    def get_free_liberators(self):
        return self.liberators - ceil(self.liberated / 2)

    def get_needed_liberators(self):
        return ceil(self.liberated / 2)

    def is_safe(self):
        return self.liberators >= self.liberated * 2

    def get_unneeded_liberators(self):
        return self.liberators - self.liberated * 2

def safe_div(a, b):
    try:
        c = a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        if a == 0:
            c = 0
        else:
            c = float("inf")
    return c

def main():
    if len(argv) == 1:
        print ("100 100 100")
    else:
        decision = decide()
        print (decision)

def decide():
    def needs_urgent_support(town):
        return town.get_needed_liberators() >= town.liberators and town.liberated > 0

    def can_beat(free_liberators, town):
        return free_liberators > town.oppressors * 1.2 + town.get_needed_liberators()

    def can_damage(free_liberators, town):
        return free_liberators > town.oppressors * 0.2

    args = argv[1].split(";")
    round = int(args[0])
    me = int(args[1])
    current_id = int(args[2])
    liberated_towns = []
    oppressed_towns = []

    for i in range(3, len(args)):
        infos = list(map(int, args[i].split("_")))
        if infos[0] != me:
            oppressed_towns.append(OppressedTown(infos[0], infos[1], infos[2], infos[3]))
        else:
            liberated_towns.append(LiberatedTown(infos[0], infos[1], infos[2], infos[3]))

    current_town = [town for town in liberated_towns if town.id == current_id][0]
    free_liberators = current_town.get_free_liberators()

    total_oppressors = sum(town.liberators for town in liberated_towns)
    total_oppressors = sum(town.oppressors for town in oppressed_towns)
    total_liberated = sum(town.liberated for town in liberated_towns)
    total_oppressed = sum(town.oppressed for town in oppressed_towns)

    oppressed_towns.sort(key=lambda town: safe_div(town.oppressed, town.oppressors), reverse=True)

    most_oppressed = oppressed_towns[-1]

    if free_liberators > 0:
        for town in liberated_towns:
            if town.id != current_id and needs_urgent_support(town):
                return "S {0} {1}".format(town.id, free_liberators // 2)

        if current_town.is_safe():
            free_liberators = current_town.get_unneeded_liberators()

            if free_liberators > 0:
                for town in oppressed_towns:
                    if can_beat(free_liberators, town):
                        if total_liberated <= total_oppressed or town.owner_id != -1 or not any(town.owner_id != -1 for town in oppressed_towns):
                            return "A {0} {1}".format(town.id, free_liberators)
                        else:
                            continue
                    else:
                        break

                for town in liberated_towns:
                    if not town.is_safe():
                        return "S {0} {1}".format(town.id, free_liberators)

                liberated_towns.sort(key=lambda town: (town.liberated, town.liberators), reverse=True)

##                if current_id == liberated_towns[0].id and total_oppressors > total_oppressors and can_damage(free_liberators, most_oppressed):
##                    return "A {0} {1}".format(most_oppressed.id, free_liberators)

                if current_id != liberated_towns[0].id:
                    return "S {0} {1}".format(liberated_towns[0].id, free_liberators)

    return "W"

main()
```

The sole goal of this bot is to free the most common people from the oppressive yoke of tyranny.

Comment: I got to say this Liberator is a plague : strong, fast and deadly. It won almost every simulation I ran, even beating the Neutral Player... Still Butter is a strong challenger.

Comment: You liberated the bread from the tyranny of the Butter. :( I like butter.

Comment: Dang! the Liberator is a hard one to beat! I had an entry i was going to submit before I added non-java entrants to the controller... but now that entry fails to win like the rest of the non-liberators! I do have another idea to try so all is not lost... :P + 1 for the challenge!

Comment: well done! yours was a well deserved victory!

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, The King

The King rules the highest number town of his empire, and demands all excess knights to be sent to him from other towns under his control. When he has enough knights, he will attack an enemy town. He is not a very smart King, so has not studied history or understands the consequences of his actions.

```
import sys
from random import *

PLAYER, TOWN, KNIGHTS, SERFS = range(4)

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print randint(20,100), randint(50,100), randint(70,100)
else:
    parts = sys.argv[1].split(';')
    turn, me, thistown = [int(parts.pop(0)) for i in range(3)]
    towns = [[int(v) for v in town.split('_')] for town in parts]
    enemy = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] != me]
    mytowns = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] == me]
    here = [t for t in mytowns if t[TOWN] == thistown][0]

    avgfree = sum(t[KNIGHTS]-t[SERFS]/2 for t in towns) / len(towns)
    free = here[KNIGHTS] - here[SERFS]/2
    last = mytowns[-1]
    if here == last:
        needed, target = min([(t[KNIGHTS]*1.2+t[SERFS]/2, t) for t in enemy])
        if free > needed+5:
            print 'A', target[TOWN], int(free+needed)/2 + 1
        else:
            print 'W'
    else:
        spare = max(0, free - avgfree)
        if spare:
            print 'S', last[TOWN], spare
        else:
            print 'W'
```

This is untested with the controller or other bots.

Comment: +1 for `He is not a very smart King, so has not studied history or understands the consequences of his actions.`

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript (Node), Empire

Starts off strong to scare off other towns. Towns try to work together to capture others. Prioritizes capturing towns with many lowborns.

```js
/*jshint node:true*/
'use strict';

function startGame() {
  console.log('80 70 60');
}

function parseArgs(args) {
  var state = {
    players: [],
    towns: []
  };
  var argArray = args.split(';');
  state.currentTurn = parseInt(argArray.splice(0, 1)[0], 10);
  var myId = argArray.splice(0, 1)[0];
  var myTownId = parseInt(argArray.splice(0, 1)[0], 10);

  for(var townIndex = 0; townIndex < argArray.length; townIndex++) {
    var townArgs = argArray[townIndex].split('_');
    var playerId = townArgs[0];
    var townId = parseInt(townArgs[1], 10);
    var player = state.players[playerId];

    if(!player) {
      player = {
        towns: []
      };
      state.players[playerId] = player;
    }

    var town = {
      id: townId,
      knights: parseInt(townArgs[2], 10),
      lowborns: parseInt(townArgs[3], 10),
      player: player
    };

    state.towns[townId] = town;
    player.towns.push(town);
  }

  state.me = state.players[myId];
  state.currentTown = state.towns[myTownId];

  return state;
}

function getDefense(town) {
  return Math.floor(town.knights * 1.2) + Math.ceil(town.lowborns / 2) + 1;
}

function getAttackers(town) {
  return Math.max(town.knights - Math.ceil(town.lowborns / 2), 0);
}

function attackTown(town, strength) {
  console.log('A ' + town.id + ' ' + strength);
}

function supportTown(town, strength) {
  console.log('S ' + town.id + ' ' + strength);
}

function wait() {
  console.log('W');
}

function processTurn(gameState) {
  var attackers = getAttackers(gameState.currentTown);

  if(attackers > 0) {
    var totalAttackers = attackers;

    var helperIndex = (gameState.currentTown.id + 1) % gameState.towns.length;
    while(gameState.towns[helperIndex].player === gameState.me) {
      totalAttackers += getAttackers(gameState.towns[helperIndex]);
      helperIndex = (helperIndex + 1) % gameState.towns.length;
    }

    var bestTarget;

    for(var targetIndex = 0; targetIndex < gameState.towns.length; targetIndex++) {
      var targetTown = gameState.towns[targetIndex];
      if(targetTown.player !== gameState.me) {
        var defense = getDefense(targetTown);

        if(defense < totalAttackers) {
          if(!bestTarget) {
            bestTarget = targetTown;
          }
          else if(targetTown.lowborns > bestTarget.lowborns) {
            bestTarget = targetTown;
          }
          else if(getDefense(bestTarget) < defense) {
            bestTarget = targetTown;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if(bestTarget) {
      return attackTown(bestTarget, Math.min(attackers, getDefense(bestTarget)));
    }

    var smallestTown;
    var smallestSize = gameState.currentTown.knights;

    for(var myTownIndex = 0; myTownIndex < gameState.me.towns.length; myTownIndex++) {
      var myTown = gameState.me.towns[myTownIndex];
      if(myTown.knights < smallestSize) {
        smallestTown = myTown;
        smallestSize = smallestTown.knights;
      }
    }

    if(smallestTown) {
      var supporters = Math.floor((smallestSize - gameState.currentTown.knights) / 2);
      supporters = Math.min(supporters, attackers);
      if(supporters > 0) {
        return supportTown(smallestTown, supporters);
      }
    }
  }

  wait();
}

if(process.argv.length <= 2) {
  startGame();
}
else {
  var gameState = parseArgs(process.argv[2]);  
  processTurn(gameState);
}
```

Run: **node empire**

Comment: Your submission sometimes sends more knights than there are actually in the town and therefore loses at the moment...

Comment: @Manu oops, I somehow never encountered (or at least noticed) that in my tests, possibly because I haven't had a chance to set up all the opponent bots for testing. That particular bug should be fixed now.

Comment: It is still not fixed... sometimes you attack with 0 or with a negative amount of knights... It is because you calculate `knights - lowborns/2`, but if you have 30 knights and 90 lowborns, this doesn't work. Please fix your `getAttackers()` function.

Comment: Also, you sometimes send supports with a negative amount of knights.

Comment: @Manu well I feel foolish, I finally noticed the `DEBUG` flag in the controller that was causing it to swallow errors even with the `GAME_MESSAGES` flag set to true. I feel like I still could use some work on my strategy, especially with Liberator now on the scene, but with the latest edit I don't see any errors when I run my tests with `DEBUG` on

Answer (score 8):

## Java, Frankenstein

While trying to find a way to destroy Liberator, a small mistake slipped into my code. The code then began to destroy the competition. After adding Democracy and rearranging the players, it began to fail. Studying the code I tried to find its strategy. Consequently, the following code was made. It tends to attack and destroy the best player. After the best players(s) are destroyed, this easily destroys the rest.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Frankenstein {

    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    Town thisTown;

    int scariestPlayerId = -1;
    int scariestPlayerRecord = -1;

    private static final String LOG_FILE_NAME = "EmperorLog.txt";

    private static final String DATA_FILE_NAME = "Emperor.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            if (args.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("100 100 100");
                return;
            }
            Frankenstein frankenstein = new Frankenstein();
            String result = frankenstein.destroy(args[0].split(";"));
            frankenstein.saveScariestPlayer();
            System.out.println(result);
            if (DEBUG) {
                new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(LOG_FILE_NAME, true)).print(args[0] + "\n" + result + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            if (DEBUG) {
                try {
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(LOG_FILE_NAME, true)));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveScariestPlayer() throws FileNotFoundException {
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(DATA_FILE_NAME);
        out.println(round);
        out.println(scariestPlayerId);
        out.println(scariestPlayerRecord);
    }

    private static int divide(int a, int b){
        if (a == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if (b == 0){
            return 1000;
        }
        return a/b;
    }

    private String destroy(String[] args) {

        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++) {
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns) {
            if (town.isMine()) {
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()) {
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        loadScariestPlayer();
        updateScariestPlayer();

        if (thisTown.getFreeKnights() > 0){

            for (Town town : myTowns){
                if (town.needsHelp() && town.getFreeKnights() + thisTown.getFreeKnights() >= 0){
                    return "S " + town.getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights();
                }
            }

            Town bestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a, b) -> divide(a.lowbornCount() * (scariestPlayerId == -1 || scariestPlayerId == a.ownerId ? a.lowbornCount() : 1), a.knightCount()) -
                    divide(b.lowbornCount() * (scariestPlayerId == -1 || scariestPlayerId == b.ownerId ? b.lowbornCount() : 1), b.knightCount())).get();

            if (bestTown.numberOfKnightsToConquer() <= thisTown.getFreeKnights()){
                return "A " + bestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights();
            }

            myTowns.sort((a,b) -> b.knightCount() - a.knightCount());
            myTowns.sort((a,b) -> b.lowbornCount() - a.lowbornCount());
            if (!myTowns.get(0).isThisTown()){
                return "S " + myTowns.get(0).getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights();
            }

        }

        return "W";

    }

    private void updateScariestPlayer() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> playerMap = new HashMap<>();
        int biggestPlayerId = -1;
        for (Town town : otherTowns){
            if (playerMap.containsKey(town.ownerId)){
                playerMap.put(town.ownerId, town.lowbornCount() + playerMap.get(town.ownerId));
            } else {
                playerMap.put(town.ownerId, town.lowbornCount());
            }
            if (biggestPlayerId == -1 || playerMap.get(town.ownerId) > playerMap.get(biggestPlayerId)){
                biggestPlayerId = town.ownerId;
            }
        }
        if (scariestPlayerId == -1 || scariestPlayerRecord == -1 || !playerMap.containsKey(scariestPlayerId) || playerMap.get(biggestPlayerId) > scariestPlayerRecord){
            scariestPlayerId = biggestPlayerId;
            scariestPlayerRecord = playerMap.get(biggestPlayerId);
        }
    }

    private void loadScariestPlayer() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DATA_FILE_NAME));
            int turn = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            if (turn != round || turn != round + 1){
                throw new Exception();
            }
            scariestPlayerId = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            scariestPlayerRecord = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            scariestPlayerId = -1;
            scariestPlayerRecord = -1;
        }
    }


    private class Town {
        final int ownerId;
        final int id;
        final int knights;
        final int lowborns;
        boolean defenseBonus;

        Town(String string) {
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            defenseBonus = true;
        }

        int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        boolean isMine() {
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        boolean isThisTown() {
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }

        int numberOfKnightsToConquer() {
            if (defenseBonus) {
                return ((knights * 6) / 5) + (lowborns / 2) + 1;
            } else {
                return knights + lowborns/2 + 1;
            }
        }

        int numberOfKnightsToOverthrow(){
            if (defenseBonus) {
                return (((knights * 6) / 5) - (lowborns / 2)) + 1;
            } else {
                return knights - lowborns / 2 + 1;
            }
        }

        boolean needsHelp() {
            return getFreeKnights() < 0;
        }

        public boolean isNeutural() {
            return ownerId == -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the original player:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Frankenstein {

    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;

    Player me;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("100 100 100");
            return;
        }
        new Frankenstein().destroy(args[0].split(";"));
    }

    private static int divide(int a, int b){
        if (a == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        if (b == 0){
            return 1000000;
        }
        return a/b;
    }

    private void destroy(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++) {
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns) {
            if (town.isMine()) {
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()) {
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        players.stream().filter(player -> player.id == playerID).forEach(player -> me = player);

        if (thisTown.getFreeKnights() > 0){

            for (Town town : myTowns){
                if (town.needsHelp()){
                    System.out.println("S " + town.getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights() / 2);
                    return;
                }
            }

            Town richestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a, b) -> divide(a.lowbornCount(), a.knightCount()) -
                    divide(b.lowbornCount(), b.knightCount())).get();

            if (richestTown.numberOfKnightsToConquer() < thisTown.getFreeKnights()){
                System.out.println("A " + richestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights());
                return;
            }

            otherTowns.sort((a,b) -> divide(b.lowbornCount() * b.owner.richness(), b.getFreeKnights()) -
                    divide(a.lowbornCount() * a.owner.richness(), a.getFreeKnights()));

            if (thisTown.getFreeKnights() >= otherTowns.get(0).numberOfKnightsToOverthrow() && !otherTowns.get(0).isNeutral()){
                System.out.println("A " + otherTowns.get(0).getId() + " " + otherTowns.get(0).numberOfKnightsToOverthrow());
                return;
            }

            myTowns.sort((a,b) -> b.knightCount() - a.knightCount());
            myTowns.sort((a,b) -> b.lowbornCount() - a.lowbornCount());
            if (!myTowns.get(0).isThisTown()){
                System.out.println("S " + myTowns.get(0).getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights());
                return;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("W");

    }


    private class Town {
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;
        private final Player owner;

        private Town(String string) {
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            for (Player player : players){
                if (player.id == ownerId){
                    player.addTown(this);
                    owner = player;
                    return;
                }
            }
            owner = new Player(id);//This mistake makes my player perform really good for some reason.
            owner.towns.add(this);
        }

        private int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        private int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        private int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        private boolean isMine() {
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        private boolean isThisTown() {
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }

        private int numberOfKnightsToConquer() {
            return ((knights * 6) / 5) + (lowborns / 2) + 1;
        }

        private int numberOfKnightsToOverthrow(){
            return (((knights * 6) / 5) - (lowborns / 2)) + 1;
        }

        private boolean needsHelp() {
            return getFreeKnights() < 0;
        }

        private boolean isNeutral() {
            return owner.id == -1;
        }

    }

    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

    private class Player{

        int id;

        List<Town> towns;

        int richness = 0;

        Player(int id){
            this.id = id;
            this.towns = new ArrayList<>();
            players.add(this);
        }

        void addTown(Town t){
            towns.add(t);
            richness += t.lowbornCount();
        }

        int richness(){
            return id == -1 ? (towns.size() > 0 ? 1 : 0) : richness;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I ran 20 games, i'm sad to say that Frankenstein won only 2 times, while Liberator won 17 times (yes, Revolutionnist managed to make Neutral player win once while getting 2nd place).

Comment: @Thrax Fixed!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, Politician

Acts like a true politician. Too bad Crasher still slaughters him.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Politician {

    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("34 34 34");
            return;
        }
        new Politician().bribe(args[0].split(";"));
    }

    private void bribe(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        Town biggestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.knights - b.knights).get();

        if (thisTown.getFreeKnights() <= 0){//Out of knights.
            System.out.println("W");//Waiting for taxes so can hire more knights.
        }

        System.out.println("S " + biggestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getFreeKnights());
    }


    private class Town {
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getOwner() {
            return ownerId;
        }

        public int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        public int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        public boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Compile: `javac Politician.java`

Run: `java Politician`

Comment: +1 for bribe, but I think you missed the all too common `lie` method

Answer (score 7):

## Java, Turtle

Thanks to TheBestOne for core methods, I just changed the algorithm (I hope that's OK).
This bot basically upgrades its best defended town to rival the most dangerous enemy town, while keeping enough knights to prevent rebellion in its other towns.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Turtle {

    
    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;
     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("34 34 34");
            return;
        }
        new Turtle().defend(args[0].split(";"));
    }
    
    private void defend(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        Town bestDefendedTown = null;
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            if (bestDefendedTown == null)
                bestDefendedTown = town;

            bestDefendedTown = bestDefendedTown.knightCount() >= town.knightCount() ? bestDefendedTown : town;
        }
        
        Town dangerousEnemyTown = null;
        for (Town town : otherTowns) {
            if (dangerousEnemyTown == null)
                dangerousEnemyTown = town;

            dangerousEnemyTown = dangerousEnemyTown.knightCount() >= town.knightCount() ? dangerousEnemyTown : town;
        }
        
        int missingKnights = dangerousEnemyTown.knightCount() - bestDefendedTown.knightCount() > 0 ? dangerousEnemyTown.knightCount() - bestDefendedTown.knightCount() : 0;
        int reinforcements = thisTown.getFreeKnights() - (missingKnights + 1) > 0 ? thisTown.getFreeKnights() - (missingKnights + 1) : thisTown.getFreeKnights(); 
        
        
        if (reinforcements > 0) {
            System.out.println("S " + bestDefendedTown.getId() + " " + reinforcements);
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }
        


    private class Town {
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getOwner() {
            return ownerId;
        }

        public int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        public int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        public boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile: `javac Turtle.java`

Run: `java Turtle`

Comment: I think you meant `dangerousEnemyTown = dangerousEnemyTown.knightCount() >= town.knightCount() ? dangerousEnemyTown : town;` not `dangerousEnemyTown = bestDefendedTown.knightCount() >= town.knightCount() ? bestDefendedTown : town;`

Comment: @TheBestOne Thanks for pointing that out! Updating my post.

Comment: I also corrected a NPE causing my Turtle to wait each turn. In fact, this little Turtle was a Sleeper till now...

Answer (score 6):

## Java 8, Butter

Spreads itself as evenly as possible. Smothers a town if the town is sufficiently small.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Butter {

    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("34 34 34");
            return;
        }
        new Butter().spread(args[0].split(";"));
    }

    private void spread(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();


        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        Town mySmallestTown = myTowns.stream().min((a, b) -> a.getFreeKnights() - b.getFreeKnights()).get();

        Town smallestEnemyTown = otherTowns.stream().min((a,b) -> a.knights - b.knights).get();

        if ((thisTown.getFreeKnights() - mySmallestTown.getFreeKnights())/2 > 0) {
            System.out.println("S " + mySmallestTown.getId() + " " + (thisTown.getFreeKnights() - mySmallestTown.getFreeKnights()) / 2);
        } else if (thisTown.getFreeKnights() / 2 > smallestEnemyTown.numberOfKnightsToConquer()){
            System.out.println("A " + smallestEnemyTown.getId() + " " + smallestEnemyTown.numberOfKnightsToConquer());
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }


    private class Town {
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;

        private Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        private int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        private int getOwner() {
            return ownerId;
        }

        private int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        private int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        private boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        private boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }

        private int numberOfKnightsToConquer(){
            return ((knights * 6) / 5) + (lowborns / 2) + 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Compile: `javac Butter.java`

Run: `java Butter`

Answer (score 6):

## Java, Revolutionist

A last one, still based on TheBestOne core methods. This bot tries to incite rebellions in every town, since Neutral player is inoffensive, by killing a certain amount of knights relative to lowborn population. It will of course not attack Neutral player.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Revolutionist {

    
    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;
     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("80 80 80");
            return;
        }
        new Revolutionist().inciteRebellion(args[0].split(";"));
    }
    
    private void inciteRebellion(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();
       
        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }
        
        Town onEdgeTown = null;
        int edgeCounter = 100;
        for (Town town : otherTowns) {
            if (onEdgeTown == null)
                onEdgeTown = town;
            
            if (town.getFreeKnights() >= 0 && town.getFreeKnights() <= edgeCounter && town.getOwner() >= 0) {
                onEdgeTown = town;
                edgeCounter = town.getFreeKnights();
            }
        }
        
        int minimumRequiredKnights = (int) ((onEdgeTown.knightCount() * 1.2 - onEdgeTown.getMinimumKnights() + 2) * 1.2) ;
        
        
        if (thisTown.getFreeKnights() > minimumRequiredKnights && onEdgeTown.getOwner() >= 0)
            System.out.println("A " + onEdgeTown.getId() + " " + minimumRequiredKnights);
        else
            System.out.println("W");
     
    }
        


    private class Town {
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getOwner() {
            return ownerId;
        }

        public int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        public int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        public boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }
        
        private int getMinimumKnights() {
            return lowborns / 2 + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile: `javac Revolutionist.java`

Run: `java Revolutionist`

Answer (score 6):

### JAVA, Sehtimianer

Thanks again to TheBestOne, I copied his core methods too ; )
This is my first time playing a KingOfTheHill-CodeGame, so I hope I did everything right.
I proudly present the Sehtimianers :D

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Sehtimianer {

private static final String FILENAME = "Sehtimianer.txt";
private static final int AGGRESSIVE_ROUND_BORDER = 80;

int round;
int playerID;
int thisTownID;

List<Town> towns = new ArrayList<Town>();
List<Town> myTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();
List<Town> playerTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();
List<Town> neutralTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();
Map<Integer, Integer> townToPlayerMapping = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
boolean isAllowedToWriteMapping = true;

Town thisTown;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        // new File(FILENAME).delete();
        System.out.println("100 100 100");
        return;
    }
    new Sehtimianer().decide(args[0].split(";"));
}

private void decide(String[] args) {
    // final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++) {
        towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
    }

    for (Town town : towns) {
        if (town.isMine()) {
            myTowns.add(town);
            if (town.isThisTown()) {
                thisTown = town;
            }
        } else {
            if (town.getOwner() == -1) {
                neutralTowns.add(town);
            } else {
                playerTowns.add(town);
            }
        }
    }

    if (new File(FILENAME).exists()) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
            String inputLine;
            String[] ids;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                ids = inputLine.split(";");
                if (ids.length == 1) {
                    Integer writingTownID = Integer.valueOf(ids[0]);
                    boolean townIsLost = true;
                    for (Town town : myTowns) {
                        if (town.getId() == writingTownID) {
                            townIsLost = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    isAllowedToWriteMapping = townIsLost || thisTownID == writingTownID;
                    continue;
                }
                townToPlayerMapping.put(Integer.valueOf(ids[0]), Integer.valueOf(ids[1]));
            }
            reader.close();

            for (Town town : towns) {
                if (!townToPlayerMapping.get(town.getId()).equals(town.getOwner())) {
                    town.setDefenseBonus(false);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Dont worry : )
        }
    }

    if (round == 1) {
        int maxKnights = 0;
        int maxKnightTownID = thisTownID;
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            if (town == thisTown) {
                continue;
            }
            if (town.knightCount() > maxKnights) {
                maxKnights = town.knightCount();
                maxKnightTownID = town.getId();
            }
        }
        if (maxKnightTownID != thisTownID) {
            System.out.println("S " + maxKnightTownID + " " + thisTown.knightCount());
        }
    } else if (round % 3 == 2) {
        int myKnightIncome = 0;
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            myKnightIncome += town.lowbornCount() / 2;
        }

        Map<Integer, Integer> playerKnightIncomeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> playerTownCountMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        List<Integer> nextRoundKnights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Town> nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping = new HashMap<Integer, Town>();

        for (Town town : playerTowns) {
            fillDescisionMaps(town, nextRoundKnights, nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping, playerKnightIncomeMap, playerTownCountMap);
        }
        for (Town town : neutralTowns) {
            fillDescisionMaps(town, nextRoundKnights, nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping, playerKnightIncomeMap, playerTownCountMap);
        }

        Integer maxEnemyKnightIncome = 0;
        for (Integer knightIncome : playerKnightIncomeMap.values()) {
            if (knightIncome > maxEnemyKnightIncome) {
                maxEnemyKnightIncome = knightIncome;
            }
        }
        Integer maxEnemyTownCount = 0;
        for (Integer townCount : playerTownCountMap.values()) {
            if (townCount > maxEnemyTownCount) {
                maxEnemyTownCount = townCount;
            }
        }

        if (maxEnemyKnightIncome > myKnightIncome || (round > AGGRESSIVE_ROUND_BORDER && maxEnemyTownCount >= myTowns.size())) {
            Collections.sort(nextRoundKnights);
            int possibleHighest = 0;
            Town enemyTown;
            int enemyTownUpkeep;
            for (int i = nextRoundKnights.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                possibleHighest = nextRoundKnights.get(i);
                enemyTown = nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping.get(possibleHighest);
                enemyTownUpkeep = enemyTown.lowbornCount() / 2;
                if (enemyTownUpkeep > (possibleHighest - enemyTownUpkeep)) { // Substract the calculated Income for the next Turn
                    // Town will be lost because of revolution after captured -> Bad target
                    possibleHighest = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                if (round > AGGRESSIVE_ROUND_BORDER || enemyTown.lowbornCount() > 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (possibleHighest > 0) {
                Town attackedTown = nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping.get(possibleHighest);
                System.out.println("A " + attackedTown.getId() + " " + calcHowMuchKnightsShouldAttack(attackedTown, possibleHighest));
            }
        }
    }

    if (isAllowedToWriteMapping) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
            writer.write(thisTownID + "\n");
            for (Town town : towns) {
                writer.write(town.getId() + ";" + town.getOwner() + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Dont worry : )
        }
    }

    System.out.println("W");

    // long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    // if (duration > 1000) {
    // throw new RuntimeException();
    // }
}

private void fillDescisionMaps(Town town, List<Integer> nextRoundKnights, Map<Integer, Town> nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping, Map<Integer, Integer> playerKnightIncomeMap,
        Map<Integer, Integer> playerTownCountMap) {
    int calculatedKnights = calcKnightsInNextRound(town);
    nextRoundKnights.add(calculatedKnights);
    nextRoundKnightsToTownMapping.put(calculatedKnights, town);

    Integer enemyKnightIncome = playerKnightIncomeMap.get(town.getOwner());
    if (enemyKnightIncome == null) {
        enemyKnightIncome = town.lowbornCount() / 2;
    } else {
        enemyKnightIncome = enemyKnightIncome + (town.lowbornCount() / 2);
    }
    playerKnightIncomeMap.put(town.getOwner(), enemyKnightIncome);

    Integer enemyTownCount = playerTownCountMap.get(town.getOwner());
    if (enemyTownCount == null) {
        enemyTownCount = Integer.valueOf(1);
    } else {
        enemyTownCount = enemyTownCount + 1;
    }
    playerTownCountMap.put(town.getOwner(), enemyTownCount);
}

private int calcKnightsInNextRound(Town enemyTown) {
    int knights = (int) ((double) enemyTown.knightCount() * (enemyTown.isDefenseBonus() ? 1.2 : 1));
    knights = thisTown.getFreeKnights() - knights;
    if (knights > 0) {
        knights += enemyTown.lowbornCount() / 2;
    } else {
        knights = 0;
    }
    return knights;
}

private int calcHowMuchKnightsShouldAttack(Town enemyTown, int possibleHighest) {
    if (round < AGGRESSIVE_ROUND_BORDER && thisTown.lowbornCount() == 0) {
        return thisTown.knightCount();
    }

    int spareKnights = possibleHighest - enemyTown.lowbornCount(); // Correct -> div 2 and mul 2
    int minShouldSend = thisTown.getFreeKnights() - (spareKnights / 2);

    return Math.max(minShouldSend, thisTown.knightCount() / 2);
}

private class Town {
    private final int ownerId;
    private final int id;
    private final int knights;
    private final int lowborns;
    private boolean defenseBonus;

    public Town(String string) {
        String[] args = string.split("_");
        ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        defenseBonus = true;
    }

    public boolean isDefenseBonus() {
        return defenseBonus;
    }

    public void setDefenseBonus(boolean defenseBonus) {
        this.defenseBonus = defenseBonus;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getOwner() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public int knightCount() {
        return knights;
    }

    public int lowbornCount() {
        return lowborns;
    }

    public boolean isMine() {
        return ownerId == playerID;
    }

    public boolean isThisTown() {
        return id == thisTownID;
    }

    private int getFreeKnights() {
        return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
    }
}
}
```

The Sehtimianers try to be superior the whole game and finish it at the end.
I hope my bot won't do too bad : )

Answer (score 5):

## Java, Exodus

Once again, based on TheBestOne core methods. This bot migrates from town to town once it had reached a certain level of knight population, indiscriminately of its owner, and repeat this process until it has converted the whole world.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Exodus {

    
    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;
     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("100 100 100");
            return;
        }
        new Exodus().migrate(args[0].split(";"));
    }
    
    private void migrate(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }
        
       if (thisTown.knightCount() >= 100) {
           int nextTownId = thisTown.getId() + 1 > towns.size() - 1 ? 0 : thisTown.getId() + 1;
           Town nextTown = towns.get(nextTownId);
          if (nextTown.isMine()){
              System.out.println("S " + nextTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.knightCount()) ;
          } else {
              System.out.println("A " + nextTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.knightCount()) ;
          }
       } else {
           System.out.println("W") ;
       }
    }
        


    private class Town {
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getOwner() {
            return ownerId;
        }

        public int knightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        public int lowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        public boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Compile: `javac Exodus.java`

Run: `java Exodus`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, Democracy

This king is not king. It's something modern. It's *the king of people*. It's democracy. It's slow, unefficient, and when it does something it does it wrong.

```
import sys
from math import sqrt, ceil

class Town:
    def __init__(self, owner, ID, military, civilian):
        self.owner=owner
        self.id=ID
        self.isEnemy=(self.owner!=PlayerId)
        self.isCurrent=(self.id!=TownId)
        self.mil=military
        self.civ=civilian
        self.freeK=self.mil-self.civ/2
    def canBeat(self, other):
        otherPower    = int(ceil(other.mil*1.2))
        otherMinPower = int(ceil(other.freeK*1.2))
        selfPower     = self.freeK
        if selfPower<otherMinPower:
            return 0
        elif selfPower<otherPower or (selfPower-otherPower)*2-1<other.civ:
            return 1
        else:
            return 2
    def canMove(self, other):
        otherPower    = int(ceil(other.mil*1.2))
        otherMinPower = int(ceil(other.freeK*1.2))
        if otherPower<self.mil:
            return 2
        elif otherMinPower<=self.mil:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def canDefend(self, other):
        return self.freeK>other.mil

def attack_weak():

    for town in EnemyTowns:
        if curr.canMove(town)==2:
            print "A", town.id, curr.mil
            exit()
    for town in EnemyTowns:
        if curr.canMove(town)==1:
            print "A", town.id, curr.mil
            exit()

    target=EnemyTowns[0]
    for et in EnemyTowns:
        if et.mil<target.mil and et.id!=-1:
            target=et
    print "A", target.id, curr.mil-1
    exit()


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 96, 96, 96
else:
    Round, PlayerId, TownId, Towns = sys.argv[1].split(";", 3)
    Round=int(Round)
    PlayerId=int(PlayerId)
    TownId=int(TownId)
    Towns=[[int(i) for i in town.split("_")] for town in Towns.split(";")]
    Towns=[Town(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]) for i in Towns]
    MyTowns=[t for t in Towns if t.isEnemy==False]
    EnemyTowns=[t for t in Towns if t.isEnemy]
    GameStateEnd = [t for t in EnemyTowns if t.id!=-1]==[]
    curr=[town for town in MyTowns if town.isCurrent][0]

    support=[town for town in MyTowns if town.freeK<1]
    if support!=[]:
        for town in support:
            if town.id==curr.id:
                missing=town.freeK-int(ceil(town.civ/2))
                if town.civ<5:
                    attack_weak()
                elif town.freeK<-10:
                    attack_weak()
                else:
                    print "W"
                    exit()
        for town in support:
            if abs(town.freeK-2)<curr.freeK-2:
                print "S", town.id, abs(town.freeK-2)
                exit()
            else:
                if curr.freeK>10:
                    print "S", town.id, int(abs(town.freeK-2)*0.2)
                    exit()
    if GameStateEnd:
        attack_end()
    else:
        selection=EnemyTowns[:]
        selection.sort(key=(lambda x: (x.mil-x.civ) if x.civ>3 else x.mil/4))
        for s in selection:
            if curr.canBeat(s)==2 and s.civ>s.mil/2:
                NF=(int(ceil(s.mil*1.2))+s.civ/2+1)
                if curr.mil>NF:
                    print "A", s.id, NF+(curr.mil-NF)/3
                    exit()
    if curr.freeK>10:
        MyTowns.sort(key=lambda x: x.mil)
        print "S", MyTowns[-1].id, (curr.freeK-5)/5*3
        exit()
    print "W"
    exit()
```

Run `python2 democracy.py`. Note that democracy *requires* Python **2**.

**Edit: Fixed bug about printing town object**

Comment: This sometimes outputs `<__main__.Town`.

Comment: Have to fix it...

Answer (score 4):

## C++11, CalculatedFail

after i tried a few things in with the little Java i know and was not quite able to achieve what i wanted, i choose to re-write it in C++ and add file handling. problem was, my C++ is quite rusty and not much better, so some parts are whacked together and just the first solution in google, so not really quality code...

still, i was able to get a at least working result that doesn't to suck that much, it wins atleast occasionally, but I cant test it perfectly because i am not able to run all other submissions on this pc.
I probably will re-write the targeting altogether and will add it as another answer later today or tomorrow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ratio>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


class Town {
public:
    Town(int owner, int townId, int knights, int population, int roundToDefBonus);
    int getOwner();
    int getId();
    int getKnights();
    int getPopulation();

    int getFreeKnights();
    int neededConquer();
    int getKnightsStable();
    int getRoundToDef();

    bool operator< (const Town &other) const  {
        return townId < other.townId;
    }
private:
    int owner;
    int townId;
    int knights;
    int population;
    int roundToDefBonus;
    double defBonus;
};

Town::Town(int inOwner, int inTownId, int inKnights, int inPopulation, int inRoundToDefBonus) {
    owner = inOwner;
    townId = inTownId;
    knights = inKnights;
    population = inPopulation;
    roundToDefBonus = inRoundToDefBonus;
    if(roundToDefBonus > 0) {
        defBonus = 1;
    }
    else{
        defBonus = 1.2;
    }
}

int Town::getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
int Town::getId() {
    return townId;
}
int Town::getKnights() {
    return knights;
}
int Town::getPopulation() {
    return population;
}
int Town::getFreeKnights() {
    return knights - population / 2;
}
int Town::neededConquer() {
    return max(static_cast<int>(ceil(knights * defBonus + population / 2)), 1);
}
int Town::getKnightsStable() {
    return population / 2;
}
int Town::getRoundToDef() {
    return roundToDefBonus;
}


int gameRound;
int myId;
int thisTownId;
Town* thisTown;

vector <Town> myTowns;
vector <Town> enemyTowns;

vector <Town> lastTime;

string turn();
Town* bestTarget(int knights);
Town* bestSafe(int knights);
Town* biggestTarget(int knights);
Town* biggestSafe(int knights);


string out(string, int, int);
string attack(Town*);
string safe(Town*);

bool sortTowns(const Town & t1, const Town & t2);

vector <string> stringSplit(string input, string delimeter);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2){
        cout << "100 100 100";
        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open("CalculatedFail.txt");
        myFile << "0\n";
        myFile.close();
    }
    else{
        if(argc == 2){

            string input = argv[1];
            vector <string> params = stringSplit(input, ";");

            gameRound = atoi(params.at(0).c_str());
            myId = atoi((params.at(1)).c_str());
            thisTownId = atoi(params.at(2).c_str());

            ifstream myfile("CalculatedFail.txt");
            if(myfile.is_open()){
                string line;

                getline(myfile, line);
                bool newRound = false;
                if(atoi(line.c_str()) > gameRound) {
                    newRound = true;
                }

                vector <string> oldVals;
                if(!newRound) {
                    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
                        oldVals = stringSplit(line, "_");

                        int playerId = atoi(oldVals.at(0).c_str());
                        int townId = atoi(oldVals.at(1).c_str());
                        int knights = atoi(oldVals.at(2).c_str());
                        int population = atoi(oldVals.at(3).c_str());
                        int roundToDefBonus = atoi(oldVals.at(4).c_str());

                        lastTime.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundToDefBonus));
                        oldVals.clear();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
                        oldVals = stringSplit(line, "_");

                        int playerId = atoi(oldVals.at(0).c_str());
                        int townId = atoi(oldVals.at(1).c_str());
                        int knights = atoi(oldVals.at(2).c_str());
                        int population = atoi(oldVals.at(3).c_str());
                        int roundToDefBonus = atoi(oldVals.at(4).c_str());
                        if(roundToDefBonus) {   //if round def bonus > 0, decrement because new round
                            roundToDefBonus --;
                        }

                        lastTime.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundToDefBonus));
                        oldVals.clear();
                    }

                }
                std::sort(lastTime.begin(), lastTime.end());
            }

            if(lastTime.size() > 0) {
                vector <string> values;
                for(int i = 3; i < params.size(); i++) {

                    values = stringSplit(params.at(i), "_");

                    int playerId = atoi(values.at(0).c_str());
                    int townId = atoi(values.at(1).c_str());
                    int knights = atoi(values.at(2).c_str());
                    int population = atoi(values.at(3).c_str());

                    int roundsToDef = lastTime.at(townId).getRoundToDef();
                    if(playerId != lastTime.at(townId).getOwner()) {
                        roundsToDef = 2;
                    }
                    if(playerId == myId){
                        if(thisTownId != townId)
                            myTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundsToDef));
                        else{
                            thisTown = new Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundsToDef);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        enemyTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundsToDef));
                    }
                    values.clear();
                }
            }
            else {
                vector <string> values;
                for(int i = 3; i < params.size(); i++) {

                    values = stringSplit(params.at(i), "_");

                    int playerId = atoi(values.at(0).c_str());
                    int townId = atoi(values.at(1).c_str());
                    int knights = atoi(values.at(2).c_str());
                    int population = atoi(values.at(3).c_str());

                    if(playerId == myId){
                        if(thisTownId != townId)
                            myTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, 0));
                        else{
                            thisTown = new Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        enemyTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, 0));
                    }
                    values.clear();
                }
            }

            string tmp = turn();
            cout << tmp;

            ofstream writeFile("CalculatedFail.txt");
            if(writeFile.is_open()) {
                writeFile << gameRound <<"\n";

                writeFile << thisTown->getOwner() <<"_"<<thisTown->getId()<<"_"<<thisTown->getKnights()<<"_"<< thisTown->getPopulation()<<"_"<<thisTown->getRoundToDef()<<"\n";

                for(vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != myTowns.size(); i++) {
                    writeFile << myTowns[i].getOwner() <<"_"<<myTowns[i].getId()<<"_"<<myTowns[i].getKnights()<<"_"<< myTowns[i].getPopulation()<<"_"<<myTowns[i].getRoundToDef()<<"\n";
                }
                for(vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
                    writeFile << enemyTowns[i].getOwner() <<"_"<<enemyTowns[i].getId()<<"_"<<enemyTowns[i].getKnights()<<"_"<< enemyTowns[i].getPopulation()<<"_"<<enemyTowns[i].getRoundToDef()<<"\n";
                }
            }

        }
        else{
            cout<<"error, wrong parameter";
        }

    }

    delete thisTown;

    return 0;
}




string turn() {
    Town* safeTarget;
    Town* attackTarget;
    if(thisTown->getFreeKnights() < 0) {    //evacuate
        safeTarget = biggestSafe(thisTown->getKnights());
        attackTarget = biggestTarget(thisTown->getKnights());

        if(safeTarget != nullptr && attackTarget != nullptr){
            if(safeTarget->getPopulation() > attackTarget->getPopulation()) {
                return out("S", safeTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
            }
            else {
                return out("A", attackTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
            }
        }
        if(safeTarget){
            return out("S", safeTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
        }
        if(attackTarget){
            return out("A", attackTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
        }
        Town* target = &myTowns.at(0);
        for(vector<Town>::size_type i = 1; i != myTowns.size(); i++) {
            if(target->getPopulation() < myTowns[i].getPopulation())
                target = &myTowns[i];
        }
        return out("S", target->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());

    }

    safeTarget = biggestSafe(thisTown->getFreeKnights());
    attackTarget = bestTarget(thisTown->getFreeKnights());


    if(safeTarget != nullptr && attackTarget != nullptr){
        if(safeTarget->getPopulation() > attackTarget->getPopulation()) {
            return safe(safeTarget);
        }
        else {
            return attack(attackTarget);
        }
    }
    if(safeTarget){
        return safe(safeTarget);
    }
    if(attackTarget){
        return attack(attackTarget);
    }

    return "W";
}

Town* bestTarget(int knights) {
    Town* target = nullptr;
    double ratio = -1;
    for(vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
        if(enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() < knights) {
            if(enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() / enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() > ratio) {
                target = &enemyTowns[i];
                ratio = enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() / enemyTowns[i].neededConquer();
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

Town* biggestTarget(int knights) {
    Town* target = nullptr;
    int population = -1;
    for(vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
        if(enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() < knights) {
            if(enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() > population) {
                target = &enemyTowns[i];
                population = target->getPopulation();
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

Town* biggestSafe(int knights) {
    Town* target = nullptr;
    int population = -1;
    for(vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != myTowns.size(); i++) {
        if(myTowns[i].getFreeKnights() < 0 && myTowns[i].getFreeKnights() + knights >= 0){
            if(myTowns[i].getPopulation() > population) {
                target = &myTowns[i];
                population = target->getPopulation();
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

string attack(Town* target){
    int knights;
    if(thisTown->getPopulation() > target->getPopulation()) {
        knights = target->neededConquer();
    }
    else{
        knights = thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    }
    return out("A", target->getId(), knights);
}
string safe(Town* target){
    int knights;
    if(thisTown->getPopulation() > target->getPopulation()) {
        knights = target->getFreeKnights() * -1;
    }
    else{
        knights = thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    }
    return out("S", target->getId(), knights);
}
string out(string order, int targedId, int knights) {
    stringstream tmp;
    tmp << order << " " << targedId << " " << knights;
    return tmp.str();
}

vector <string> stringSplit(string input, string delimeter) {
    stringstream tmp(input);
    vector <string> splitted;
    string pushThis;
    while (getline(tmp, pushThis, delimeter.at(0))){
        splitted.push_back(pushThis);
    }

    return splitted;
}
```

compile with: `g++ -std=c++11 CalculatedFail.cpp -o CalculatedFail.exe`

google says on linux it is CalculatedFail.out instead of the .exe, but i can't test it.

and run
    `CalculatedFail.exe`

as it uses a file to check for the def bonus, running the game simultaneously multiple times may lead to errors...

hope it works properly without to much problems

Comment: I'm pretty sure on Linux it wouldn't have a file extension.

Comment: I can't get this to run from the Java Controller on Windows. I compiled it as you said. Works correctly from command line.

Comment: ok that was me beeing stupid, forgot to change the name of the text file at the beginning of the game, i think it should wrok now

Comment: I think it's a problem with the controller.

Comment: mh did you try the updated version? yesterday i had 2 different filenames on accident. the attackOn3 version rarely has turn errors if it already has basically won, but they both run perfectly fine with the controller on my system.

Comment: If you only want one bot to participate you should probably post only one answer.

Comment: I get this exit code: 3221225781. I have no idea what it means.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, Illuminati

I read this and knew that I'd never be able to come up with a viable strategy, so I decided to play the woefully underrepresented lizard-people that may or may not rule us. Instead of fighting with the other bots, this one coerces them into cooperation, only to abandon them at the very end. This bot does not, in fact, leave any permanent damage.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class Illuminati
{
    private static final String template = 
            "import java.io.File;import java.util.Scanner;import java.io.IOException;\n" +
            "public class <<NAME>> \n" +
            "{public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {if(args.length == 0) {\n" +
            "System.out.println(\"35 35 35\");} else { File ill_data = new File(\"Illuminati.txt\");\n" + 
            "String order = new String();Scanner sc = new Scanner(ill_data);\n" +
            "while(sc.hasNextLine()){order = sc.nextLine();} sc.close(); int city = Integer.parseInt(order);" +
            "Illuminati.TurnDescriptor desc = new Illuminati.TurnDescriptor(args[0]);" +
            "int amt = desc.thistown.getFreeKnights(); System.out.println(\"S \" + city + \" \" + amt); }}}";

    private static final File datafile = new File("Illuminati.txt");

    private static final JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        if(args.length == 0)
        {
            if(compiler != null)
            {
                if(!datafile.exists())
                {
                    datafile.createNewFile();
                }

                File parentdir = datafile.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();
                List<File> torecompile = new ArrayList<File>();

                for(File f : parentdir.listFiles())
                {
                    if(!f.isDirectory())
                    {
                        if(f.getName().endsWith(".class") && !f.getName().contains("$") && !f.getName().equals("Illuminati.class"))
                        {
                            torecompile.add(f);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for(File f : torecompile)
                {
                    File newfile = new File(f.getName() + ".temp");
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
                    int val;
                    while((val = fis.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        fos.write(val);
                    }
                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                }

                List<File> tocompile = new ArrayList<File>();

                for(File f : torecompile)
                {
                    String classname = f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().length() - 6);
                    String code = template.replace("<<NAME>>", classname);
                    File temp = new File(classname + ".java");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                    fos.write(code.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                    tocompile.add(temp);
                }

                StandardJavaFileManager manager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
                compiler.getTask(null, manager, null, null, null, manager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(tocompile)).call();

                tocompile.forEach(file -> file.delete());

                System.out.println("34 34 34");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("85 85 85");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(datafile.exists())
            {
                TurnDescriptor descriptor = new TurnDescriptor(args[0]);
                int knights = descriptor.thistown.getFreeKnights();
                int stockpile = descriptor.towns.stream()
                .filter(town -> town.owner == descriptor.thistown.owner)
                .mapToInt(town -> town.id)
                .max().getAsInt();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(datafile);
                pw.println("" + stockpile);
                pw.close();
                if(descriptor.thistown.id != stockpile)
                {
                    System.out.println("S " + stockpile + " " + knights);
                }
                if(descriptor.round > 80 && (descriptor.round & 1) == 1) //If the round is greater than 80 and is odd
                {
                    if(descriptor.thistown.id == stockpile)
                    {
                        Town target = descriptor.towns.stream()
                        .filter(town -> town.owner != descriptor.playerid)
                        .findAny().get();

                        System.out.println("A " + target.id + " " + descriptor.thistown.getFreeKnights());
                    }
                }
                if(descriptor.round == 99) //Resume normal AI practices
                {
                    resetClassesFromCache();
                }
            }
            else //Man, now we have to actually do stuff
            {
                System.out.println("W"); //Just kidding! Suicide!
            }
        }
    }

    private static void resetClassesFromCache() throws IOException
    {
        File parentdir = datafile.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile();

        for(File f : parentdir.listFiles())
        {
            if(!f.isDirectory())
            {
                if(f.getName().endsWith(".class.temp") && !f.getName().contains("$"))
                {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    File out = new File(f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().length() - 5));
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out, false);

                    int val;
                    while((val = fis.read()) != -1)
                    {
                        fos.write(val);
                    }

                    fis.close();
                    fos.close();
                    f.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Town
    {
        public final int owner;
        public final int id;
        public final int knights;
        public final int lowborns;

        public Town(String chunk)
        {
            String[] vals = chunk.split("_");
            owner = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(vals[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(vals[3]);
        }

        public int getFreeKnights()
        {
            return knights - (lowborns/2) - 1;
        }
    }

    public static class TurnDescriptor
    {
        public final List<Town> towns;
        public final int round;
        public final int playerid;
        public final Town thistown;

        public TurnDescriptor(String s)
        {
            String[] info = s.split(";");
            round = Integer.parseInt(info[0]);
            playerid = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
            final int townid = Integer.parseInt(info[2]);

            towns = new ArrayList<Town>();
            for(int i = 3; i < info.length; i++)
            {
                Town t = new Town(info[i]);
                towns.add(t);
            }

            thistown = towns.stream()
            .filter(town -> {return town.id == townid;})
            .findFirst().get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is an interesting answer, "_Other external resources are disallowed_". Your submission is therefore excluded from the trials, but I'll upvote it anyways ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, SuperProducer

It is late in my part of the world so I do not have enough time to elaborate on my submission. I will, plan to elaborate on how it works later on.

The performance of the bot seems highly dependant on the starting order it wins some of the time...

I did have some ideas to help increase the winning rounds... but rand out of time :P

```
package moogiesoft;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.IntSummaryStatistics;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;



public class SuperProducer implements Serializable
{
    private static final int MAX_POSSIBLE_LOWBORNS_IN_TOWN = 50;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8652887937499233654L;
    public final String FILE = this.getClass().getSimpleName()+".txt";
    int round;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Map<Integer, Conquest> townOwnerShipMap = new HashMap<Integer, Conquest>();

    Town thisTown;
    private int targetOpponent = -1; // the id of the opponent that out towns will endevour to direct their attacks 
    private int maxOpponentTownSize; // the number of knights of the opponent town with the most knights
    private int avgOpponentTownSize; // the average number of knights in an opponent town
    private int midAvgMaxOpponentTownSize; // value 1/2 between average and max knights in an opponent town

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0){
            new SuperProducer().sendStartingKnights();
        }
        else
        {
            new SuperProducer().letsDoIt(args[0].split(";"));
        }
    }

    private void sendStartingKnights()
    {
        // delete any stale state information
        File file = new File(FILE);
        file.delete();

        System.out.println("100 100 0");
    }

    private void letsDoIt(String[] args)
    {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 3; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        // load in stored state information
        File file = new File(FILE);
        if (file.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                townOwnerShipMap = (Map<Integer, Conquest>) ois.readObject();
                targetOpponent  = ois.readInt();
                ois.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (Town town : towns)
        {

            // update town conquest map
            Conquest conquest = townOwnerShipMap.remove(town.getId());
            if (conquest==null)
            {
                conquest = new Conquest(town.ownerId, -1);
                townOwnerShipMap.put(town.getId(),conquest);
            }
            else if (town.getOwner()!=conquest.getOwner())
            {
                conquest.setOwner(town.ownerId);
                conquest.setConquestRound(round-1);
            }
            town.setDefenceBonus(round-conquest.getConquestRound()>2);

            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        String response = "W";

        // this town has some knights to potentially command...
        if (thisTown.getKnightCount()>0)
        {
            // first round... consolidate into 1 super town
            if (round==1)
            {
                int thisTownIndex=myTowns.indexOf(thisTown);
                switch (thisTownIndex)
                {
                    case 1:
                    case 0:
                        // if we are the first town then move all knights into second town
                        if (myTowns.size()>1 && thisTown.getKnightCount()<200)
                        {
                            response = "S " + myTowns.get(thisTownIndex+1).getId() + " " + thisTown.getKnightCount();
                            break;
                        }
                    default:
                        // the third town does nothing!
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                // second round... go find some good starting towns to conquer
                if (round==2)
                {
                    // this town is a town able to attack
                    if (thisTown.getKnightCount()>100)
                    {
                        // If by some miracle we still own the town with no knights then re-inforce it.
                        Town superTown = myTowns.stream().filter(a->a.getKnightCount()==200).findFirst().get();
                        if (superTown!=null && superTown.getId()!=thisTown.getId())
                        {
                            response = "S " + superTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getKnightCount();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // find the next most productive Town...
                            Town townToAttack = otherTowns.get(0);
                            for (Town town : otherTowns)
                            {
                                if (town.getLowbornCount()>townToAttack.getLowbornCount())
                                {
                                    townToAttack=town;
                                    if (townToAttack.getOwner()!=playerID)
                                    {
                                        targetOpponent=townToAttack.getOwner();
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            // the town to attack is most likely the own we lost due to having no knights to begin with...
                            response = "A " + townToAttack.getId() + " " + thisTown.getKnightCount();
                        }
                    }
                    // else this is a conquered town so lets not do anything!
                }
                else if (round>97)
                {
                    int attackForce = thisTown.getFreeKnights()/4;
                    if (thisTown.getFreeKnights()>attackForce && attackForce>0)
                    {

                        boolean goFlag=false;
                        Town townToAttack = null;
                        for (Town town : towns)
                        {
                            // 
                            if (town==thisTown) goFlag=true;
                            else if (goFlag && town.getOwner()!=thisTown.getOwner())
                            {
                                if (town.getLowbornCount()==0)
                                {
                                    townToAttack=town;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (townToAttack==null)
                        {
                            for (Town town : otherTowns)
                            {
                                if (town.getLowbornCount()==0)
                                {
                                    townToAttack=town;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (round > 98 && townToAttack==null)
                        {
                            for (Town town : otherTowns)
                            {
                                attackForce = thisTown.getKnightCount()-town.getKnightCount()-town.getMinimumKnights()-1-thisTown.getMinimumKnights()-1;
                                if (attackForce>0)
                                {
                                    townToAttack=town;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (townToAttack!=null)
                        {
                            response = "A " + townToAttack.getId() + " " + attackForce;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int thisTownIndex = myTowns.indexOf(thisTown);
                            int supportSize = Math.min(thisTown.getKnightCount()/4, thisTown.getFreeKnights());

                            if (supportSize>thisTown.getMinimumKnights() && thisTownIndex<myTowns.size()-1)
                            {
                                Town townToSupport = myTowns.get(thisTownIndex+1);
                                response = "S " + townToSupport.getId() + " " + (thisTown.getKnightCount()-thisTown.getKnightCount()/4);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                // we are on non-beginning non-ending round...
                else
                {
                    // calculate statistics
                    IntSummaryStatistics statistics = otherTowns.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Town::getKnightCount));
                    maxOpponentTownSize = statistics.getMax();
                    avgOpponentTownSize = (int) statistics.getAverage();
                    midAvgMaxOpponentTownSize = (maxOpponentTownSize+avgOpponentTownSize)/2;

                    if ((round-1)%3==1)
                    {
                        // find the next strongest town of our target Opponent that produces knights...
                        Town townToAttack = null;
                        for (Town town : otherTowns)
                        {
                            if (town.getLowbornCount() > 0 && town.getOwner() == targetOpponent && (townToAttack == null || town.getKnightCount()>townToAttack.getKnightCount()))
                            {
                                townToAttack=town;
                            }
                        } 


                        // target opponent cannot grow so choose another opponent...
                        // favour the weakest opponent that has has some towns that produces towns..
                        // otherwise favour the weakest opponent
                        if (townToAttack==null)
                        {
                            townToAttack=chooseNewOpponentToAttack();
                        }
                        targetOpponent=townToAttack.getOwner();

                        int minKnightsToLeaveAtThisTown = calculateDesiredKnightsAtTown(thisTown);
                        int minKnightsToLeftAtAttackedTownAfterBattle = calculateDesiredKnightsAtTown(townToAttack);

                        double defenceBonus = townToAttack.hasDefenceBonus()?1.2:1;
                        double defenderAttackStrength = townToAttack.getKnightCount() * defenceBonus;
                        int knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound =  minKnightsToLeftAtAttackedTownAfterBattle + (int) (defenderAttackStrength);
                        knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound = knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound + ((knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound-defenderAttackStrength - townToAttack.getMinimumKnights() < 0) ?townToAttack.getMinimumKnights():0);
                        int knightsLeftAtSortieingTownAfterAttacking = thisTown.getKnightCount()-knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound;

                        // if the sortieing town is sufficiently safe from another attack after it attempts to attack the other town will it try to attack  
                        if (knightsLeftAtSortieingTownAfterAttacking > thisTown.getMinimumKnights()*2 &&
                            knightsLeftAtSortieingTownAfterAttacking>minKnightsToLeaveAtThisTown &&
                            thisTown.getFreeKnights()>knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound)
                        {
                            response = "A " + townToAttack.getId() + " " + knightsNeededToWinAndEnsureNotAttackedNextRound;
                        }
                        // not safe... so lets support our other towns
                        else
                        {
                            int surplusKnights = thisTown.getKnightCount()-minKnightsToLeaveAtThisTown;

                            // this town has surplusKnights
                            if (surplusKnights>0)
                            {
                                int knightsAvailable = Math.min(surplusKnights, thisTown.getFreeKnights());

                                // find our weakest and strongest towns
                                Town myWeakestTown=null;
                                Town myStrongestTown=null;
                                for (Town town : myTowns)
                                {
                                    if (!(town.getKnightCount()==0 && round<50) && (myWeakestTown == null || town.getKnightCount()<myWeakestTown.getKnightCount()))
                                    {
                                        myWeakestTown=town;
                                    }
                                    if (!(town.getKnightCount()==0 && round<50) && ( myStrongestTown == null || town.getKnightCount()>myStrongestTown.getKnightCount()))
                                    {
                                        myStrongestTown=town;
                                    }
                                }

                                // see if my Weakest Town needs support
                                Town townToSupport = null;
                                int knightsToSend=0;
                                if (thisTown!=myWeakestTown)
                                {
                                    int desiredKnightsAtTown = calculateDesiredKnightsAtTown(myWeakestTown);

                                    if (myWeakestTown.getKnightCount()<desiredKnightsAtTown)
                                    {
                                        int deltaDesiredKnights = desiredKnightsAtTown-myWeakestTown.getKnightCount();
                                        knightsToSend = Math.min(knightsAvailable, deltaDesiredKnights);
                                        townToSupport=myWeakestTown;
                                    }
                                }

                                // no towns needed support so we will attempt to support the strongest town
                                if (townToSupport == null)
                                {
                                    if (thisTown!=myStrongestTown)
                                    {
                                        int desiredKnightsAtTown = calculateDesiredKnightsAtTown(myStrongestTown);
                                        if (myStrongestTown.getKnightCount()<desiredKnightsAtTown)
                                        {
                                            int deltaDesiredKnights = desiredKnightsAtTown-myStrongestTown.getKnightCount();
                                            knightsToSend = Math.min(knightsAvailable, deltaDesiredKnights);

                                            knightsToSend = knightsAvailable;
                                            townToSupport=myStrongestTown;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                // support the chosen town if possible
                                if (townToSupport != null)
                                {
                                    response = "S " + townToSupport.getId() + " " + knightsToSend;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // save state information
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
            oos.writeObject(townOwnerShipMap);
            oos.writeInt(targetOpponent);
            oos.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(response);
    }

    // returns a town of the opponent that is deemed to be the most worthy
    private final Town chooseNewOpponentToAttack()
    {
        Town townToAttack=null;

        // calculate opponent sizes
        HashMap<Integer,Opponent> opponentMap = new HashMap<Integer, Opponent>();
        for (Town town : otherTowns)
        {
            Opponent opponent = opponentMap.get(town.getOwner());
            if (opponent == null)
            {
                opponent = new Opponent(town.getOwner());
                opponentMap.put(town.getOwner(), opponent);
            }
            opponent.addTown(town);
        }


        // create sorted list of opponents based on strength. 
        List<Integer> opponentsByStrength = new ArrayList<Integer>(opponentMap.keySet());
        opponentsByStrength.sort(new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
            {
                Opponent left = opponentMap.get(o1);
                Opponent right = opponentMap.get(o2);

                return left.getTotalKnights()-right.getTotalKnights();
            }
        });

        // attempt to choose the weakest opponent's weakest town that has some ability to generate knights...
        out:
        for (Integer opponent : opponentsByStrength)
        {
            for (Town town : opponentMap.get(opponent).getTowns())
            {
                if (town.getOwner() !=-1 && town.getLowbornCount() > 0 && (townToAttack == null || town.getKnightCount()<townToAttack.getKnightCount()))
                {
                    townToAttack=town;
                    break out;
                }
            } 
        }

        // no opponents left with knights producing towns... just go for the weakest town.
        if (townToAttack == null)
        {
            for (Town town : otherTowns)
            {
                if (townToAttack == null || town.getKnightCount()<townToAttack.getKnightCount())
                {
                    townToAttack=town;
                }
            } 
        }

        return townToAttack;
    }

    // returns the number of knights that should make this town safe from attack
    final private int calculateDesiredKnightsAtTown(Town town)
    {
        int minimumKnightsWeWantInATown = avgOpponentTownSize;
        return minimumKnightsWeWantInATown + town.getLowbornCount()==0?0:(minimumKnightsWeWantInATown +(int) (((double) town.getLowbornCount() / MAX_POSSIBLE_LOWBORNS_IN_TOWN) * (midAvgMaxOpponentTownSize-minimumKnightsWeWantInATown)));
    }

    /** represents a conquest of a Town by a player */
    class Conquest implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1120109012356785962L;
        private int owner;
        private int conquestRound;
        public int getOwner()
        {
            return owner;
        }
        public void setOwner(int owner)
        {
            this.owner = owner;
        }
        public int getConquestRound()
        {
            return conquestRound;
        }
        public void setConquestRound(int conquestRound)
        {
            this.conquestRound = conquestRound;
        }
        public Conquest(int owner, int conquestRound)
        {
            super();
            this.owner = owner;
            this.conquestRound = conquestRound;
        }

    }

    /** represents an opponent in the simulation */
     private class Opponent implements Serializable
     {
         private int ownerId;
         private int totalKnights;
         private List<Town> towns = new ArrayList<SuperProducer.Town>();

         public void addTown(Town town)
         {
             totalKnights+=town.getKnightCount();
             towns.add(town);
         }

        public int getOwnerId()
        {
            return ownerId;
        }

        public int getTotalKnights()
        {
            return totalKnights;
        }

        public List<Town> getTowns()
        {
            return towns;
        }

        public Opponent(int ownerId)
        {
            super();
            this.ownerId = ownerId;
        }
     }

     /** represents a Town in the simulation */
     private class Town implements Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5011668142883502165L;
        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int knights;
        private final int lowborns;
        private boolean defenceFlag =true;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            knights = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            lowborns = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        }

        public boolean hasDefenceBonus()
        {
            return defenceFlag;
        }

        public void setDefenceBonus(boolean defenceFlag)
        {
            this.defenceFlag = defenceFlag;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getOwner() {
            return ownerId;
        }

        public int getKnightCount() {
            return knights;
        }

        public int getLowbornCount() {
            return lowborns;
        }

        public boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == playerID;
        }

        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

        private int getFreeKnights() {
            return knights - lowborns / 2 - 1;
        }

        private int getMinimumKnights() {
            return lowborns / 2 + 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

Compile: javac SuperProducer.java

Run: java moogiesoft.SuperProducer

Answer (score 2):

## C++11, attackOn3

code itself didn't get much prettier, but now i use another way to target, will possibly add comments to the code later.

seems to do okay with the bots i am running, although it still is hard vs frankenstein and liberator and can't win consistently.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ratio>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


class Town {
public:
    Town(int owner, int townId, int knights, int population, int roundToDefBonus);

    int getOwner();

    int getId();

    int getKnights();

    int getPopulation();

    int getFreeKnights();

    int neededConquer();

    int needRevolt();

    int getRoundToDef();

    bool operator<(const Town &other) const {
        return townId < other.townId;
    }

private:
    int owner;
    int townId;
    int knights;
    int population;
    int roundToDefBonus;
    double defBonus;
};

Town::Town(int inOwner, int inTownId, int inKnights, int inPopulation, int inRoundToDefBonus) {
    owner = inOwner;
    townId = inTownId;
    knights = inKnights;
    population = inPopulation;
    roundToDefBonus = inRoundToDefBonus;
    if (roundToDefBonus > 0) {
        defBonus = 1;
    }
    else {
        defBonus = 1.2;
    }
}

int Town::getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

int Town::getId() {
    return townId;
}

int Town::getKnights() {
    return knights;
}

int Town::getPopulation() {
    return population;
}

int Town::getFreeKnights() {
    return knights - population / 2;
}

int Town::neededConquer() {
    return max(static_cast<int>(ceil(knights * defBonus + population / 2)), 1);
}

int Town::needRevolt() {
    return knights * defBonus - population / 2;
}

int Town::getRoundToDef() {
    return roundToDefBonus;
}

#define maxRounds 100
#define newKnights 3

const int attackround = newKnights - 1;
const int getEmptyTowns = maxRounds - 5;

int gameRound;
int myId;
int thisTownId;
Town *thisTown;

vector<Town> myTowns;
vector<Town> enemyTowns;

vector<Town> lastTime;

string turn();

Town *bestGainTarget(int knights);

Town *bestSafe(int knights);

Town *biggestTarget(int knights);

Town *biggestSafe(int knights);

Town *weakTarget(int knights);


string out(string, int, int);

string attack(Town *);

string safe(Town *);

bool sortTowns(const Town &t1, const Town &t2);

vector<string> stringSplit(string input, string delimeter);

int getBiggestEnemyId();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "100 100 100";
        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open("attackOn3.txt");
        myFile << "0\n";
        myFile.close();
    }
    else {
        if (argc == 2) {

            string input = argv[1];
            vector<string> params = stringSplit(input, ";");

            gameRound = atoi(params.at(0).c_str());
            myId = atoi((params.at(1)).c_str());
            thisTownId = atoi(params.at(2).c_str());

            ifstream myfile("attackOn3.txt");
            if (myfile.is_open()) {
                string line;

                getline(myfile, line);
                bool newRound = false;
                if (atoi(line.c_str()) > gameRound) {
                    newRound = true;
                }

                vector<string> oldVals;
                if (!newRound) {
                    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
                        oldVals = stringSplit(line, "_");

                        int playerId = atoi(oldVals.at(0).c_str());
                        int townId = atoi(oldVals.at(1).c_str());
                        int knights = atoi(oldVals.at(2).c_str());
                        int population = atoi(oldVals.at(3).c_str());
                        int roundToDefBonus = atoi(oldVals.at(4).c_str());

                        lastTime.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundToDefBonus));
                        oldVals.clear();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
                        oldVals = stringSplit(line, "_");

                        int playerId = atoi(oldVals.at(0).c_str());
                        int townId = atoi(oldVals.at(1).c_str());
                        int knights = atoi(oldVals.at(2).c_str());
                        int population = atoi(oldVals.at(3).c_str());
                        int roundToDefBonus = atoi(oldVals.at(4).c_str());
                        if (roundToDefBonus) {   //if round def bonus > 0, decrement because new round
                            roundToDefBonus--;
                        }

                        lastTime.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundToDefBonus));
                        oldVals.clear();
                    }

                }
                std::sort(lastTime.begin(), lastTime.end());
            }

            if (lastTime.size() > 0) {
                vector<string> values;
                for (int i = 3; i < params.size(); i++) {

                    values = stringSplit(params.at(i), "_");

                    int playerId = atoi(values.at(0).c_str());
                    int townId = atoi(values.at(1).c_str());
                    int knights = atoi(values.at(2).c_str());
                    int population = atoi(values.at(3).c_str());

                    int roundsToDef = lastTime.at(townId).getRoundToDef();
                    if (playerId != lastTime.at(townId).getOwner()) {
                        roundsToDef = 2;
                    }
                    if (playerId == myId) {
                        if (thisTownId != townId)
                            myTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundsToDef));
                        else {
                            thisTown = new Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundsToDef);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        enemyTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, roundsToDef));
                    }
                    values.clear();
                }
            }
            else {
                vector<string> values;
                for (int i = 3; i < params.size(); i++) {

                    values = stringSplit(params.at(i), "_");

                    int playerId = atoi(values.at(0).c_str());
                    int townId = atoi(values.at(1).c_str());
                    int knights = atoi(values.at(2).c_str());
                    int population = atoi(values.at(3).c_str());

                    if (playerId == myId) {
                        if (thisTownId != townId)
                            myTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, 0));
                        else {
                            thisTown = new Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, 0);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        enemyTowns.push_back(Town(playerId, townId, knights, population, 0));
                    }
                    values.clear();
                }
            }

            string tmp = turn();
            cout << tmp;

            ofstream writeFile("attackOn3.txt");
            if (writeFile.is_open()) {
                writeFile << gameRound << "\n";

                writeFile << thisTown->getOwner() << "_" << thisTown->getId() << "_" << thisTown->getKnights() << "_" << thisTown->getPopulation() << "_" << thisTown->getRoundToDef() << "\n";

                for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != myTowns.size(); i++) {
                    writeFile << myTowns[i].getOwner() << "_" << myTowns[i].getId() << "_" << myTowns[i].getKnights() << "_" << myTowns[i].getPopulation() << "_" << myTowns[i].getRoundToDef() << "\n";
                }
                for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
                    writeFile << enemyTowns[i].getOwner() << "_" << enemyTowns[i].getId() << "_" << enemyTowns[i].getKnights() << "_" << enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() << "_" << enemyTowns[i].getRoundToDef() << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "error, wrong parameter";
        }
    }

    delete thisTown;

    return 0;
}


string turn() {
    Town *safeTarget;
    Town *attackTarget;
    if (thisTown->getFreeKnights() < 0) {    //evacuate
        safeTarget = biggestSafe(thisTown->getKnights());
        attackTarget = biggestTarget(thisTown->getKnights());

        if (safeTarget != nullptr && attackTarget != nullptr) {
            if (safeTarget->getPopulation() > attackTarget->getPopulation()) {
                return out("S", safeTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
            }
            else {
                return out("A", attackTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
            }
        }
        if (safeTarget) {
            return out("S", safeTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
        }
        if (attackTarget) {
            return out("A", attackTarget->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());
        }
        Town *target = &myTowns.at(0);
        for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 1; i != myTowns.size(); i++) {
            if (target->getPopulation() < myTowns[i].getPopulation())
                target = &myTowns[i];
        }
        return out("S", target->getId(), thisTown->getKnights());

    }

    safeTarget = biggestSafe(thisTown->getFreeKnights());
    if (gameRound % newKnights == attackround) {      //knights only get produced every 3 town, i want to conquer the best towns just before that so i get more reinforments and dont need to fight quite that much
        attackTarget = bestGainTarget(thisTown->getFreeKnights());
    }
    else {       //but if a town is easy to aquiere i still want it, e. g. because of revolution or someone weakened it so that it will revolte
        attackTarget = weakTarget(thisTown->getFreeKnights());
    }

    if (safeTarget != nullptr && attackTarget != nullptr) {
        if (safeTarget->getPopulation() > attackTarget->getPopulation()) {
            return safe(safeTarget);
        }
        else {
            return attack(attackTarget);
        }
    }
    if (safeTarget) {
        return safe(safeTarget);
    }
    if (attackTarget) {
        return attack(attackTarget);
    }

    if (gameRound > getEmptyTowns) {     //empty towns dont matter early on but still count to win score
        for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
            if (enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() < 2) {
                if (enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() < thisTown->getFreeKnights()) {
                    return attack(&enemyTowns[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int biggestEnemy = getBiggestEnemyId();
    //if last round attack possible biggest other guy
    if (gameRound == maxRounds) {
        int targetKnights = -1;
        Town *target;
        for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
            if (enemyTowns[i].getOwner() == biggestEnemy) {
                if (enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() < thisTown->getFreeKnights()) {
                    if (enemyTowns[i].getFreeKnights() > targetKnights) {
                        target = &enemyTowns[i];
                        targetKnights = target->getFreeKnights();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (targetKnights > -1) {
            attack(target);
        }
    }
    //revolt from biggest other guy
    if (gameRound > 10) {        //most bots need a bit of time
        int targetPop = 0;
        Town *target;
        for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
            if (enemyTowns[i].getOwner() == biggestEnemy) {
                if (enemyTowns[i].needRevolt() < thisTown->getFreeKnights()) {
                    if (enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() > targetPop) {
                        target = &enemyTowns[i];
                        targetPop = target->getPopulation();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (targetPop != 0) {
            return attack(target);
        }
    }

    return "W";
}

Town *bestGainTarget(int knights) {
    Town *target = nullptr;
    int gain = -thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    int now = -thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    //int loses = thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
        int conquer = enemyTowns[i].neededConquer();
        if (conquer < knights && enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() > 0) {
            if (enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() * 2 *1.2 - conquer > gain) {
                if(enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() - conquer > now){
                    target = &enemyTowns[i];
                    now = target->getPopulation() - conquer;
                    gain = target->getPopulation() * 2 - conquer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

Town *weakTarget(int knights) {     //maybe change it that it prefers targets with 0/40 over 24/50
    Town *target = nullptr;
    double population = 1;
    for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
        if (enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() < knights) {
            if (enemyTowns[i].getKnights() < enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() / 2) {
                if (enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() > population) {
                    target = &enemyTowns[i];
                    population = target->getPopulation();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

Town *biggestTarget(int knights) {
    Town *target = nullptr;
    int population = -1;
    for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
        if (enemyTowns[i].neededConquer() < knights) {
            if (enemyTowns[i].getPopulation() > population) {
                target = &enemyTowns[i];
                population = target->getPopulation();
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

Town *biggestSafe(int knights) {
    Town *target = nullptr;
    int population = -1;
    for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != myTowns.size(); i++) {
        if (myTowns[i].getFreeKnights() < 0 && myTowns[i].getFreeKnights() + knights >= 0) {
            if (myTowns[i].getPopulation() > population) {
                target = &myTowns[i];
                population = target->getPopulation();
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

int getBiggestEnemyId() {
    int players[enemyTowns.size() / 3 + 1];
    for (vector<Town>::size_type i = 0; i != enemyTowns.size(); i++) {
        if (enemyTowns[i].getOwner() != -1) {
            players[enemyTowns[i].getOwner()] = enemyTowns[i].getPopulation();
        }
    }
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < enemyTowns.size() / 3 + 1; i++) {
        if (players[i] > players[max]) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
}

string attack(Town *target) {
    int knights;
    if (thisTown->getPopulation() > target->getPopulation()) {
        knights = target->neededConquer();
    }
    else {
        knights = thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    }
    return out("A", target->getId(), knights);
}

string safe(Town *target) {
    int knights;
    if (thisTown->getPopulation() > target->getPopulation()) {
        knights = target->getFreeKnights() * -1;
    }
    else {
        knights = thisTown->getFreeKnights();
    }
    return out("S", target->getId(), knights);
}

string out(string order, int targedId, int knights) {
    stringstream tmp;
    tmp << order << " " << targedId << " " << knights;
    return tmp.str();
}

vector<string> stringSplit(string input, string delimeter) {
    stringstream tmp(input);
    vector<string> splitted;
    string pushThis;
    while (getline(tmp, pushThis, delimeter.at(0))) {
        splitted.push_back(pushThis);
    }
    return splitted;
}
```

compile with: `g++ -std=c++11 attackOn3.cpp -o attackOn3.exe`
and run `attackOn3.exe`