# KOTH: Warring Towns

Tags: king-of-the-hill

**Final results are here !**

## Introduction

The game takes is strongly inspired by [Manu's Game of Town](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44491/the-game-of-towns/44531). It takes place in a world of swords and magic. The king who ruled the whole continent just died, and the lords of the many city-states are now fighting over territory. You are one of these lords and your goal is to conquer and rule every single town.

## Principle

People are divided into **8 classes** :

```
Warlocks : Fighter (magic)
Crusaders : Fighter (melee)
Amazons : Fighter (range)
Corsairs : Utility (steal, guard, transport)
Bishops : Utility (convert, exorcize)
Necromancers : Utility (resurrect)
Architects : Utility (build)
Peons : Resource (income, recruits)
```

When the game begins, you rule over one town. In each town, there are **100 people**. You have to split them up between those 8 categories.

Then the actual game begins, which is turn-based. A turn consists of **12 phases**, 7 of which are interactive (asking bots for a command). Next phase begins when previous phase has been executed by every town (Phase 1 : Town 1, Town 2, Town 3... ; Phase 2 : Town 1, Town 2, Town 3...) :

```
1. Raise Taxes                              - AUTOMATED 
2. Steal Money                              - INTERACTIVE
3. Recruit Troops                           - INTERACTIVE
4. Pay Wages                                - AUTOMATED
5. Try Revolt                               - AUTOMATED
6. Convert Soldiers                         - INTERACTIVE
7. Attack Town                              - INTERACTIVE
8. Raise Corpses                            - INTERACTIVE
9. Move Army or Tribute                     - INTERACTIVE
10. Defend against Threats                  - AUTOMATED
11. Construct Buildings                     - INTERACTIVE
12. Make Children                           - AUTOMATED
```

The controller provides you with input via command arguments, your program has to output via stdout.

## Syntax

**Output (preparation)**
Before the game starts, the controller invokes you submission without arguments. This means you have to distribute your 100 people into into the 8 categories.

You need to output :
`Warlocks Crusaders Amazons Corsairs Bishops Necromancers Architects Peons`

For example : `15 10 12 10 7 5 1 40`.

Each town also starts with 500 gold and 5 corpses.

**Input**
Each time your program is called, it will receive arguments in this format : `Round;Phase;YourPlayerId;YourTownId;PlayerId_TownId_Gold_Corpses_Warlocks_Crusaders_Amazons_Corsairs_Bishops_Necromances_Architects_Peons_Temples_Barracks_Estates_Palaces;PlayerId_TownId_Gold_Corpses_Warlocks_Crusaders_Amazons_Corsairs_Bishops_Necromances_Architects_Peons_Temples_Barracks_Estates_Palaces;...`

**Example input**
`1;2;1;1;0_0_600_5_15_10_12_10_7_5_1_40_0_0_0_0;1_1_700_5_15_10_12_10_7_5_1_40_0_1_0_2;...`

Here, you see it is the 1st round, 2nd phase, you are player 1 in town 1. You have 700 gold, 5 corpses, 15 warlocks, 10 crusaders, 12 amazons, 10 corsairs, 7 bishops, 5 necromancers, 1 architect, 40 peons, 0 temples, 1 barracks, 0 estates and 2 palaces.

**Output**

See gameplay.

## Gameplay

**All phases**

*Command* `W` = WAIT

*Invalid command* = WAIT

**Phase 1 : Raise Taxes**

Income is generated according to your population and your completed buildings :

```
+5 gold * Peons
+2 gold * (Warlocks + Bishops + Necromancers) * TEMPLES
+2 gold * (Crusaders + Amazons) * BARRACKS
+2 gold * (Corsairs + Peons) * ESTATES
+10 gold * PALACES
```

**Phase 2 : Steal Money**

During this phase, you can steal money from one town by sending Corsairs. Each Corsair can steal up to **10 gold** (i.e. 12 Corsairs can steal up to 120 gold). If the target town doesn't have enough gold, your corsairs will steal everything, up to the maximum debt amount : **200 gold**. If you try to send more Corsairs than you own, the program will use all your available Corsairs.

*Command syntax* : `S DestinationId Corsairs`

**Phase 3 : Recruit Troops**

Here you can train your peons by spending some gold. You can recruit as much units as you want, as long as you have enough peons and gold available. If you try to recruit more than you actually can, the game will recruit randomly till everything has been spent. The program respects your maximum quotas (if you try to recruits 10 crusaders and 5 amazons with only 8 peons, it will for example recruit 6 crusaders and 2 amazons, and not 8 amazons or 8 warlocks).

```
Warlock :       10 gold
Crusader :      10 gold
Amazon :        10 gold
Corsair :       12 gold 
Bishop :        20 gold
Necromancer :   20 gold
Architect :     15 gold
```

*Command syntax* : `R Warlocks Crusaders Amazons Corsairs Bishops Necromancers Architects`

**Phase 4 : Pay Wages**

Salaries are debited according to your population :

```
-1 gold * (Warlock + Crusaders + Amazons)
-2 gold * (Corsairs + Bishops + Necromancers + Architects)
```

**Phase 5 : Try Revolt**

If your balance is negative, you loose the control of your town to the **Outlaws**. After a revolt, the gold of the town is resetted to start value : **500 gold**. The population is maintained at its current levels.

**Phase 6 : Convert Soldiers**

Each of your Bishops can convert 1 enemy soldier (Warlock, Crusader or Amazon) from a choosen Town for a fee of 50 gold per unit. The converted units join the forces stationned in your town. As with the recruitment, if you don't have enough gold or bishops available, the program will convert randomly while respecting the quotas.

*Command syntax* : `C DestinationId Warlocks Crusaders Amazons`

**Phase 7 : Attack Town**

You can send an army of Warlocks, Crusaders and Amazons to conquer a Town. If you try to send more than you have, the program will send everyone.

The soldiers have a **1.5 fighting bonus** following this pattern : `Mage > Range > Melee > Mage` (ie. A Warlock fighting an Amazon gains 1.5 power). Only the units in excess get this bonus (ie. A Warlock fighting a Warlock and an Amazon doesn't get this bonus). The bonus is attributed to both offense and defense.

Losses are distributed randomly between the units of the victor according to looser total power (ie. Offense power: 12 vs. Defense power: 14, Defense wins and looses 12 units). The looser looses all his units. Every dead unit is added to the corpses count of the town attacked.
If the offense wins, the town is captured and is now owned by the attacker. He also keeps the gold, corpses and peons that were in this town. Corsairs, Bishops, Necromancers and Architects flee in front of potential oppression.

The defense gets nothing.

*Command syntax* : `A DestinationId Warlocks Crusaders Amazons`

**Phase 8 : Raise Corpses**

Each of your necromancers can resurrect up to 5 peons by consuming corpses and spending gold. Each resurrected Peons cost 1 corpse and 20 gold. If you try to resurrect more than you can, the program will spend everything you have.

*Command syntax* : `R Corpses`

**Phase 9 : Move Army or Tribute**

You can send units to another town. If you try to send more than you have, the program will send everyone.

*Command syntax* : `M DestinationId Warlocks Crusaders Amazons Corsairs Bishops Necromancers Architects`

Or, you can send gold by chartering Corsairs's ships. Each corsair can transport up to **200 gold**. If you try to send more than you have, the program will send what you have.

*Command syntax* : `T DestinationId Gold`

**Phase 10 : Defend against Threats**

Several menaces threats to harm your town :

> - Zombies : The dead are not always as dead as they look. 10% (floored) of the corpses in your town will awake and eat brains. Each zombie will eat 1 Peon and then wander into the nothingness (Corpses of both Zombies and eaten Peons are consumed).
> - Demons : Your peons need to hear sermons or they will start to invoke Dark Spirits. Each of your Bishop cover the needs of up to 50 Peons. 10% (floored) of your Heretics (Peons in excess) will spawn Demons. Demons kill 1 Peon each and return to hell (Corpses of Peons are added to town count).
> - Bandits : Outlaws are dwelling in the neighbourhood. The total Outlaws population is divided equitably between towns and sent to steal wealth. Your only defense is your Corsairs patrols. Each corsair can stop up to 5 outlaws. Each outlaw not stopped steals 10 gold from your town (maximum town debt is 200 gold)

At least 1 town of Outlaws (100 population) is generated at the start of the game, then 1 more for each 5 players (ie. 1-4 Players : 1 Outlaws, 5-9 Players : 2 Outlaws...).
Outlaws can be recognized with `id = -1`

**Phase 11 : Construct Building**

When reaching this phase, the construction of the buildings in your town progress according to the number of Architects. Each Architect increases the completion of a single Building by 8%. When a Building reaches 100%, it is completed and start to generate revenues in the next "Taxes" Phase. The construction queue is auto-managed (first come, first served).

You can then also start the construction of other Buildings (BuildingId = Letter in parenthesis) :

```
TEMPLE (T) :        200 Gold
BARRACKS (B) :      200 Gold
ESTATE (E) :        200 Gold
PALACE (P) :        500 Gold
```

You can start the construction of as many Building as you want, and if you don't have enough gold, Building will be ignored. The construction of your new Buildings will only start next round.

*Command syntax* : `B BuildingId BuildingId BuildingId ...`

**Phase 12 : Make Children**

Every five round (round 5, 10, 15...), new Peons will be born and ready to fight. Each pair of Peons will make 1 Peon (ie. 23 Peons generate 11 new Peons).

## Rules

- Bots should not be written to beat or support specific other bots.
- Writing to files is allowed. Please write to "yoursubmissionname.txt", the folder will be emptied before a game starts. Other external resources are disallowed.
- Your submission has 1 second to respond (per town).
- Provide commands to compile and run your submissions.

## Winning

Winner is the one with the most towns after 100 rounds. If a player captures all towns, the game stops and he wins. If multiple players have the same amount of towns, the total population will count, then the amount of gold.

## Controller

[You can find the controller on github.](https://github.com/Thrax37/koth-master/) It also contains 2 samplebots, written in Java. Open it in Eclipse, place the compiled bots in the root folder and add a class to the control program (just like the samplebots).

## Fights

The fighting formula is something like this :

For each soldier class (Warlock, Crusader, Amazon) :

- Calculate balance between offense and defense (ie. Who has more of each class and how many more?)
- For the excess soldiers (ie. value of positive balance), see how many "weak targets" (see Phase 7 diagram) there is.
- Multiply the eligible soldiers' (ie. "weak targets" compared to "excess soldiers") fighting strength by the bonus and add the rest with a fighting strength of 1.

You can try a simulator here : http://ideone.com/ArJosE (just change the values of the soldiers, you'll get bonuses and total strengths)

Here are a few test cases :

```
Attack      Defense     A. Bonus    D. Bonus   A. Str      D. Str    Winner
20/10/0     12/12/12    8/0/0       0/2/10     34.0        42.0      Defense
40/0/5      12/12/12    12/0/0      0/12/0     51.0        42.0      Attack
0/60/8      10/30/2     0/10/6      8/0/0      76.0        46.0      Attack
20/20/40    90/5/5      0/15/5      40/0/0     90.0        120.0     Defense
```

## Final Results

Average of 10 games. Syntax : `Player(Towns, Population, Gold)`

```
1. Opportunist(6.4, 4165, 2895626)
2. Politician(6.4, 1048, 42542)
3. Outlaw(2.8, 1575, 349073)
4. YoungEarl(0.4, 3424, 941624)
5. Aegis(0, 0, 0)
 . Butter(0, 0, 0)
 . Commander(0, 0, 0)
 . Lannister(0, 0, 0)
 . Machiaveli(0, 0, 0)
 . Monarch(0, 0, 0)
 . Serenity(0, 0, 0)
 . Sehtimianer(0, 0, 0)
 . Sleeper(0, 0, 0)
 . Zealots(0, 0, 0)
```

Results of 10 games : http://pastebin.com/GdufEYjm

Complete logs of 2 games : http://pastebin.com/GQDZ0JdY & http://pastebin.com/m3UBTDuC

Well played everyone, the fight has been really close between Politician and Oppotunist.

Comment: By increasing the number of player interaction, I am hoping to see a diversification in strategies. However, a simple bot can be achieved in very few lines.

Comment: `The total Outlaws population is divided equitably between towns and sent to steal wealth.` How many bandits are there total?

Comment: @MegaTorn At start, there is one town of Outlaws for 5 players (minimum 1) and 100 people inside each of them. Then as the game progress, Outlaws can appear from revolts or be killed by other players.

Comment: how do we know how many buildings an opponent town has? the controller does not seem to send that information. This is necessary to determine how much taxes will be raised so to determine whether an successful attack may actually end up in being unable to pay wages and promptly loose the town to a revolution

Comment: When a town falls in phase 5, can other player towns take over that town? If so, is the population class types maintained? ie: If they had 20/20/40 fighters in Warlocks, Crusaders, Amazons, this is what you need to fight to take that town?

Comment: Who is "Commander"? I don't see that as a submission.

Comment: I am still confused on how the combat is calculated. I have added a note to my answer with a suggested table that would really help explain it. Thanks.

Comment: There is a bug in the tribut-code. `int goldToTransport = Math.max(goldAvailable, goldToMove);` should be `Math.min(...)`. The same with the line below.

Comment: @Claudiu Commander is my example bot. Its source is available on GIT. I'll post it here as an anwser too, I guess.

Comment: You might have a bug in `executeAttack`. When attackers win, `setCorpses` should sum the _destination_ Warlocks etc.

Comment: According to the code, when taking a town the Utility Classes all flee but the attacker keeps the gold, corpses (including new corpses from the recent battle), peons and buildings.

Comment: @CarpetPython I updated the controller for the corpses. And you're right, utility classes flee when the town is captured but not when the towns revolts. I'll update the specifications.

Comment: Do we start out with only 1 town? :(

Comment: @TheBestOne Yes. If need be, I'll think about giving more than 1 to each player.

Comment: @Thrax I have found a bug in Game.java, the executeConversion() method does a check to see how many conversions are possible, however it double counts crusaders and does not count amazons.

Comment: @TheBestOne Yes, the 5 corpses of the elderly and diseased people who died overnight

Comment: @TheBestOne No, the Outlaws population consists of the people from the 8 basic classes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Opportunist, Java v2

He tries to take opportunities as they present themselves... but if none present themselves (and he is still in contention) at the end of the game then he will go all out.

UDPATE:

Incorporated some of durron597's ideas. Now stops recruiting bishops when able to fully convert the strongest opponent's force and instead focuses on purchasing soldiers.

Also v1 had an initial handicap where the starting population spread did not add up to 100... only 98!

```java
package moogiesoft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Opportunist  {

private static final float FIGHTING_BONUS = 1.5f;
public static final int GOLD_PER_PEON = 5;
public static final int GOLD_PER_TEMPLE = 2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_BARRACKS = 2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_ESTATE = 2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_PALACE = 10;
private static final int CONVERSION_COST = 50;
private static final int GOLD_PER_STEAL = 10;
private static final int GOLD_MAX_DEBT = 200;
private static final int CORSAIR_COST = 12;
private static final int BISHOP_COST = 20;
private static final int ARCHITECT_COST = 15;
private static final int BARRACKS_COST = 200;
private static final int MILITARY_COST = 10;

int round;
int phase;
int playerID;
int thisTownID;


List<Town> towns;
List<Town> myTowns;
List<Town> otherTowns;
List<Town> otherNonOutlawTowns;
List<Town> otherOutlawTowns;

Town thisTown;

public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("8 8 9 22 8 0 13 32");
    } else {
        new Opportunist().respond(args[0].split(";"));
    }
}

private void respond(String[] args) {

    round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    towns = new ArrayList<>();
    myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
    otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();
    otherNonOutlawTowns= new ArrayList<>();
    otherOutlawTowns= new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++){
        towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
    }

    for (Town town : towns){
        if (town.isMine()){
            myTowns.add(town);
            if (town.isThisTown()){
                thisTown = town;
            }
        } else {
            otherTowns.add(town);
            if (town.getOwnerId()!=-1)
            {
                otherNonOutlawTowns.add(town);
            }
            else
            {
                otherOutlawTowns.add(town);
            }
        }
    }


    switch (phase)
    {
        case 2: steal(); break;
        case 3: recruit(); break;
        case 6: convert(); break;
        case 7: attack(); break;
        case 8: resurrect(); break;
        case 9: move(); break;
        case 11: build(); break;
        default: System.out.println("W"); break;
    }
}

private void steal() {
    ArrayList<Town> architectSoldierSortedNonOutlawTowns = new ArrayList<>(otherNonOutlawTowns);
    architectSoldierSortedNonOutlawTowns.sort((a,b)->b.getArchitects()-a.getArchitects()==0?a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers():b.getArchitects()-a.getArchitects());
    Town targetTown =null;
    int targetTownStolenGold = 0;

    // Try to steal from the towns that have the most architects as they are the long term threat.
    for (Town town : architectSoldierSortedNonOutlawTowns)
    {
        if (estimateProceedsOfTheft(town,thisTown)>thisTown.calculateTaxes())
        {
              targetTown=town;
              break;
        }
    }

    // see if we can cause revolution in any non outlaw towns or if the target proceeds of theft is not sufficent to support this town...
    if (targetTown==null || estimateProceedsOfTheft(targetTown,thisTown)+thisTown.calculateTaxes()<thisTown.calculateSalary()*2)
    {
        for (Town town : otherNonOutlawTowns)
        {

            if (town.getGold()-town.calculateSalary()-thisTown.getCorsairs()*GOLD_PER_STEAL<0)
            {
               int stolenGold = estimateProceedsOfTheft(town,thisTown);
               if (stolenGold>targetTownStolenGold)
               {
                   targetTownStolenGold=stolenGold;
                   targetTown=town;
               }
            }

        }
    }

    // just pick the strongest opponent
    if (targetTown==null && round<5)
    {
        targetTown = otherNonOutlawTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).orElse(null);
    }

    // or if the target proceeds of theft is not sufficent to support this town... select the non outlaw town with the most gold!
    if (targetTown==null || estimateProceedsOfTheft(targetTown,thisTown)+thisTown.calculateTaxes()<thisTown.calculateSalary()*2)
    {
        targetTown = otherNonOutlawTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.gold - b.gold).orElse(null);
    }

    // otherwise just pick the outlaw town with the most gold.
    if (targetTown==null)
    {
        targetTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.gold - b.gold).orElse(null);
    }

    System.out.println("S " + targetTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getCorsairs());

}

private void recruit() {
    Town strongestTown=otherTowns.stream().max((a,b)->a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers()).orElse(null);
    Town mostRepoductiveTown=otherTowns.stream().max((a,b)->a.getPeons()-b.getPeons()).orElse(null);

    int originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert = 0;
    boolean recruitSoldiers=true;
    // last round... no point in keeping any peons... make them soldiers. 
    if (round==100)
    {
        originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert = thisTown.getPeons();
    }
    // looks like our bishops can recruit the full force of the strongest enemy... so lets just recruit soldiers.
    else if (strongestTown!=null && strongestTown.getSoldiers()<thisTown.getBishops())
    {
        originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert = thisTown.getPeons()-mostRepoductiveTown.getPeons();
    }
    // ok so we need more bishops...
    else if (round>5)
    {
        recruitSoldiers=false;
        originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert = thisTown.getPeons()/10;
    }

    int amazonRecruit = 0;
    int crusaderRecruit = 0;
    int warlockRecruit = 0;
    int bishopRecruit = 0;
    int corsairRecruit = 0;
    int architectRecruit = 0;

    while (originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert>0)
    {
        int noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert=originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert;
        int recruitsLeft;
        do
        {
            recruitsLeft=noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert;

            if (recruitSoldiers)
            {
                if (noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert-->0) amazonRecruit++;
                if (noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert-->0) crusaderRecruit++;
                if (noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert-->0) warlockRecruit++;
            }
            // see if we want to recruit more bishops...
            else if (thisTown.getBishops()<(round<30?Math.pow(2,round/4):thisTown.getPeons()-50))
            {
               if (noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert-->0) bishopRecruit++;
            }
        } while (noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert>0 && noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert!=recruitsLeft);

        noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert = noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert<0?0:noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert;
        Town simulatedTown = new Town(thisTown);
        simulatedTown.setPeons(thisTown.getPeons()-(originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert-noOfPeonsAvailableToConvert));
        simulatedTown.setAmazons(simulatedTown.getAmazons()+amazonRecruit);
        simulatedTown.setCrusaders(simulatedTown.getCrusaders()+crusaderRecruit);
        simulatedTown.setWarlocks(simulatedTown.getWarlocks()+warlockRecruit);
        simulatedTown.setBishops(simulatedTown.getWarlocks()+bishopRecruit);
        simulatedTown.setCorsairs(simulatedTown.getWarlocks()+corsairRecruit);
        simulatedTown.setArchitects(simulatedTown.getWarlocks()+architectRecruit);
        simulatedTown.setGold(simulatedTown.getGold()-amazonRecruit*MILITARY_COST
                                                     -crusaderRecruit*MILITARY_COST
                                                     -warlockRecruit*MILITARY_COST
                                                     -bishopRecruit*BISHOP_COST
                                                     -corsairRecruit*CORSAIR_COST
                                                     -architectRecruit*ARCHITECT_COST
                                                     -BARRACKS_COST // aways have enough to build a building!
                                                     );

        // ensure that we can afford (both now and in the future) to recruit this number of bishops...
        if (estimateProceedsOfTheft(thisTown) + simulatedTown.calculateTaxes()-simulatedTown.calculateSalary()>0 && simulatedTown.getGold()>simulatedTown.calculateSalary())
            break;
        originalNoOfPeonsAvailableToConvert--;
    }

    System.out.println("R " + warlockRecruit + " " + crusaderRecruit + " " + amazonRecruit + " " + corsairRecruit + " " + bishopRecruit + " 0 " + architectRecruit);
}

private void convert() {
    int currentGold = thisTown.getGold();
    int futureTaxGeneration = thisTown.calculateTaxes();
    int futureSalaryCost = thisTown.calculateSalary();
    int futureProceedsOfCrime = estimateProceedsOfTheft(thisTown);
    int futureCashFlow = futureTaxGeneration+futureProceedsOfCrime-futureSalaryCost;
    int goldAvailableToSpend = currentGold-=BARRACKS_COST;

    if (goldAvailableToSpend>CONVERSION_COST && futureCashFlow>0)
    {
        Town strongestTown = null;

        // sort towns by architects and then soldiers...
        ArrayList<Town> architectSoldierSortedNonOutlawTowns = new ArrayList<>(otherNonOutlawTowns);
        architectSoldierSortedNonOutlawTowns.sort((a,b)->b.getArchitects()-a.getArchitects()==0?a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers():b.getArchitects()-a.getArchitects());
        for (Town town :architectSoldierSortedNonOutlawTowns)
        {
            // if we could use all our bishops...then we shall target this town...
            if (town.getSoldiers()-thisTown.getBishops()>0)
            {
                strongestTown =town;
                break;
            }
        }

        // no town targeted... select the town with the most soldiers then.
        if (strongestTown == null)
        {
            strongestTown = findStrongestTownThatCanDefeatGivenTown(thisTown);
        }

        if (strongestTown == null)
        {
            // this town is already surpreme! lets see if we can be fivolous and attempt to convert anyway...
            if (thisTown.getGold()>thisTown.calculateSalary()*2)
            {
                strongestTown=otherNonOutlawTowns.stream().max((a,b)->a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers()).orElse(null);
            }
        }

        // no town targeted... select the town with the most soldiers then.
        if (strongestTown == null)
        {
            strongestTown=otherTowns.stream().max((a,b)->a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers()).orElse(null);
        }

        // we have selected a town... try to convert from it...
        if (strongestTown != null)
        {
            Town simulatedThisTown = new Town(thisTown);
            int amazonConversionCount=0;
            int warlockConversionCount=0;
            int crusaderConversionCount=0;

            // iterate until we are unable to pay for conversion or unable to support converted forces
            while(true)
            {
                futureTaxGeneration = simulatedThisTown.calculateTaxes();
                futureSalaryCost = simulatedThisTown.calculateSalary();
                futureCashFlow = futureTaxGeneration+futureProceedsOfCrime-futureSalaryCost;

                goldAvailableToSpend-=CONVERSION_COST;

                // see if we can afford to convert another military unit or have run out of bishops to use...
                if (amazonConversionCount+warlockConversionCount+crusaderConversionCount==thisTown.getBishops() || goldAvailableToSpend < 0 || futureCashFlow<0) break;

                // convert a amazon... if any...
                if (strongestTown.getAmazons()>0)
                {
                    amazonConversionCount++;
                    simulatedThisTown.setAmazons(simulatedThisTown.getAmazons()+1);
                    strongestTown.setAmazons(strongestTown.getAmazons()-1);
                }
                // convert a crusader... if any...
                else if (strongestTown.getCrusaders()>0)
                {
                    crusaderConversionCount++;
                    simulatedThisTown.setCrusaders(simulatedThisTown.getCrusaders()+1);
                    strongestTown.setCrusaders(strongestTown.getCrusaders()-1);
                }
                // convert a warlock... if any...
                else if (strongestTown.getWarlocks()>0)
                {
                    warlockConversionCount++;
                    simulatedThisTown.setWarlocks(simulatedThisTown.getWarlocks()+1);
                    strongestTown.setWarlocks(strongestTown.getWarlocks()-1);
                }
                // no more units to convert from the targeted town...
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("C " + strongestTown.getId() + " " + warlockConversionCount + " " + crusaderConversionCount + " " + amazonConversionCount);
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("W");
}

private void attack() {

    // nearing end game.. lets just attack every thing blindly :P
    if (round>=99)
    {
        for (Town town : towns)
        {
            if (!town.isMine())
            {
                Town simulatedThisTown = new Town(thisTown);
                Town simulatedOtherTown = new Town(town);

                // attempt to attack the opponent with all our soldiers.
                if (battle(simulatedThisTown,simulatedOtherTown,thisTown.getWarlocks(),thisTown.getCrusaders(),thisTown.getAmazons()))
                {
                    System.out.println("A "+ town.getId()+ " " + thisTown.getWarlocks()+ " " + thisTown.getCrusaders()+ " " + thisTown.getAmazons() );
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // we should be in a good position... lets try to take over strongest opponent...
    if (round>32)
    {
        Town strongestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b)->a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers()).orElse(null);
        Town simulatedThisTown = new Town(thisTown);
        Town simulatedStrongestTown = new Town(strongestTown);

        int warlockRegiment = thisTown.getWarlocks();
        int crusaderRegiment = thisTown.getCrusaders();
        int amazonRegiment = thisTown.getAmazons();

        List<Town> remainderNonOutLawTowns = new ArrayList<Town>(otherNonOutlawTowns);
        remainderNonOutLawTowns.remove(strongestTown);

        Town nextStrongestTown = remainderNonOutLawTowns.stream().max((a,b)->a.getSoldiers()-b.getSoldiers()).orElse(null);
        boolean firstLoop=true;

        // attempt to attack the strongest opponent with the least number of soldiers possible and still be in a position to likely not succumb to the next strongest opponent.
        while (nextStrongestTown!=null && warlockRegiment+crusaderRegiment+amazonRegiment>0 && battle(simulatedThisTown,simulatedStrongestTown,warlockRegiment,crusaderRegiment,amazonRegiment))
        {

            Town simulatedThisTownAfterWinning = new Town(simulatedThisTown);
            Town simulatedNextStrongestTown = new Town(nextStrongestTown);

            if (nextStrongestTown==null ||
                battle(simulatedNextStrongestTown,simulatedThisTownAfterWinning,
                       simulatedNextStrongestTown.getWarlocks()*2/3,
                       simulatedNextStrongestTown.getCrusaders()*2/3,
                       simulatedNextStrongestTown.getAmazons()*2/3))
            {
                if (firstLoop) break;
                System.out.println("A "+ strongestTown.getId()+ " " + warlockRegiment+ " " + crusaderRegiment+ " " + amazonRegiment );
                return;
            }
            firstLoop=false;
            warlockRegiment-=warlockRegiment>0?1:0;
            crusaderRegiment-=crusaderRegiment>0?1:0;
            amazonRegiment-=amazonRegiment>0?1:0;

            simulatedThisTown = new Town(thisTown);
            simulatedStrongestTown = new Town(strongestTown);
        }

        // it looks like we are in a power deadlock with one other town... lets see if going all out will make us the victor....
        if (otherNonOutlawTowns.size()==1)
        {
            simulatedThisTown = new Town(thisTown);
            Town simulatedRemainingTown = new Town(otherNonOutlawTowns.get(0));

            if (battle(simulatedThisTown,simulatedRemainingTown,thisTown.getWarlocks(),thisTown.getCrusaders(),thisTown.getAmazons()))
            {
                System.out.println("A "+ simulatedRemainingTown.getId()+ " " + thisTown.getWarlocks()+ " " + thisTown.getCrusaders()+ " " + thisTown.getAmazons() );
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("W");
}

private void move() {

    // give half our funds to the most needy town...
    List<Town> poorMyTowns = myTowns.stream().filter(a->a.calculateTaxes()-a.calculateSalary()<0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (poorMyTowns.size()>0)
    {
        Town poorTown = poorMyTowns.get(new Random().nextInt(poorMyTowns.size()));

        if (poorTown.getId() != thisTownID)
        {
            System.out.println("T "+poorTown.getId()+ " "+ thisTown.getGold()/2);
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("W");

}

private void resurrect() {
    // zombie shmozies!
    System.out.println("W");
}

private void build() {
    // endevour to always build a barracks or estate (which ever is more lucrative)
    int currentGold = thisTown.getGold();
    int futureTaxGeneration = thisTown.calculateTaxes();
    int futureSalaryCost = thisTown.calculateSalary();
    int futureProceedsOfCrime = estimateProceedsOfTheft(thisTown);
    int futureCashFlow = futureTaxGeneration+futureProceedsOfCrime-futureSalaryCost;
    int goldAvailableToSpend = currentGold;

    if (goldAvailableToSpend>BARRACKS_COST && futureCashFlow>0)
    {
        if (thisTown.getAmazons()+thisTown.getCrusaders()>thisTown.getCorsairs()+thisTown.getPeons())
        {
            System.out.println("B B");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("B E");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("W");
}

private class Town  {

    private int ownerId =-1;
    private int id = -1;
    private int gold;
    private int corpses;
    private int warlocks;
    private int crusaders;
    private int amazons;
    private int corsairs;
    private int bishops;
    private int necromancers;
    private int architects;
    private int peons;
    private int temples;
    private int barracks;
    private int estates;
    private int palaces;

    public Town(String string){
        String[] args = string.split("_");
        ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        warlocks = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
        crusaders = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
        amazons = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
        corsairs = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
        bishops = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
        necromancers = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
        architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
        peons = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
        temples = Integer.parseInt(args[12]);
        barracks = Integer.parseInt(args[13]);
        estates = Integer.parseInt(args[14]);
        palaces = Integer.parseInt(args[15]);
    }

    //Copy constructor
    public Town(Town source)
    {
        this.ownerId=source.ownerId;
        this.id=source.id;
        this.gold=source.gold;
        this.corpses=source.corpses;
        this.warlocks=source.warlocks;
        this.crusaders=source.crusaders;
        this.amazons=source.amazons;
        this.corsairs=source.corsairs;
        this.bishops=source.bishops;
        this.necromancers=source.necromancers;
        this.architects=source.architects;
        this.peons=source.peons;
        this.temples = source.temples;
        this.barracks = source.barracks;
        this.estates = source.estates;
        this.palaces = source.palaces;

    }

    public void setOwnerId(int ownerId)
    {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public void setGold(int gold)
    {
        this.gold = gold;
    }

    public void setCorpses(int corpses)
    {
        this.corpses = corpses;
    }

    public void setWarlocks(int warlocks)
    {
        this.warlocks = warlocks;
    }

    public void setCrusaders(int crusaders)
    {
        this.crusaders = crusaders;
    }

    public void setAmazons(int amazons)
    {
        this.amazons = amazons;
    }

    public void setCorsairs(int corsairs)
    {
        this.corsairs = corsairs;
    }

    public void setBishops(int bishops)
    {
        this.bishops = bishops;
    }

    public void setNecromancers(int necromancers)
    {
        this.necromancers = necromancers;
    }

    public void setArchitects(int architects)
    {
        this.architects = architects;
    }

    public void setPeons(int peons)
    {
        this.peons = peons;
    }

    public int getTemples()
    {
        return temples;
    }

    public int getBarracks()
    {
        return barracks;
    }

    public int getEstates()
    {
        return estates;
    }

    public int getPalaces()
    {
        return palaces;
    }

    public int getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getGold() {
        return gold;
    }

    public int getCorpses() {
        return corpses;
    }

    public int getWarlocks() {
        return warlocks;
    }

    public int getCrusaders() {
        return crusaders;
    }

    public int getAmazons() {
        return amazons;
    }

    public int getCorsairs() {
        return corsairs;
    }

    public int getBishops() {
        return bishops;
    }

    public int getNecromancers() {
        return necromancers;
    }

    public int getArchitects() {
        return architects;
    }

    public int getPeons() {
        return peons;
    }

    public int getSoldiers() {
        return getWarlocks() + getCrusaders() + getAmazons();
    }

    public boolean isMine(){
        return getOwnerId() == playerID;
    }

    public boolean isThisTown(){
        return id == thisTownID;
    }

    public int calculateSalary()
    {
        return (getWarlocks() + getCrusaders() + getAmazons()) + 2*(getCorsairs()+getBishops()+ getArchitects()+ getNecromancers());
    }

 // algorithm taken from Game.java
    public int calculateTaxes()
    {
        int taxes = 0;
        taxes += (getPeons() * GOLD_PER_PEON);
        taxes += ((getWarlocks() + getBishops() + getNecromancers()) * (getTemples() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE));
        taxes += ((getCrusaders() + getAmazons()) * (getBarracks() * GOLD_PER_BARRACKS));
        taxes += ((getPeons() + getCorsairs()) * (getEstates() * GOLD_PER_ESTATE));
        taxes += (getPalaces() * GOLD_PER_PALACE);
        return  taxes; 
    }

}

// algorithm taken from Game.java
private boolean battle(Town attackingTown, Town defendingTown, int attackingWarlocks, int attackingCrusaders, int attackingAmazons)
{
    int sourceWarlocks = Math.min(attackingTown.getWarlocks(), Math.max(0, attackingWarlocks));
    int sourceCrusaders = Math.min(attackingTown.getCrusaders(), Math.max(0, attackingCrusaders));
    int sourceAmazons = Math.min(attackingTown.getAmazons(), Math.max(0, attackingAmazons));

    int destinationWarlocks = defendingTown.getWarlocks();
    int destinationCrusaders = defendingTown.getCrusaders();
    int destinationAmazons = defendingTown.getAmazons();

    int sourceWarlocksBalance = Math.max(0, sourceWarlocks - destinationWarlocks);
    int sourceWarlocksBonus = Math.min(sourceWarlocksBalance, destinationAmazons);
    float sourceWarlocksStrength = (sourceWarlocks - sourceWarlocksBonus + (sourceWarlocksBonus * FIGHTING_BONUS));
    int sourceCrusadersBalance = Math.max(0, sourceCrusaders - destinationCrusaders);
    int sourceCrusadersBonus = Math.min(sourceCrusadersBalance, destinationWarlocks);
    float sourceCrusadersStrength = (sourceCrusaders - sourceCrusadersBonus + (sourceCrusadersBonus * FIGHTING_BONUS));
    int sourceAmazonsBalance = Math.max(0, sourceAmazons - destinationAmazons);
    int sourceAmazonsBonus = Math.min(sourceAmazonsBalance, destinationCrusaders);
    float sourceAmazonsStrength = (sourceAmazons - sourceAmazonsBonus + (sourceAmazonsBonus * FIGHTING_BONUS));
    float sourceTotalStrength = sourceWarlocksStrength + sourceCrusadersStrength + sourceAmazonsStrength;

    int destinationWarlocksBalance = Math.max(0, destinationWarlocks - sourceWarlocks);
    int destinationWarlocksBonus = Math.min(destinationWarlocksBalance, sourceAmazons);
    float destinationWarlocksStrength = (destinationWarlocks - destinationWarlocksBonus + (destinationWarlocksBonus * FIGHTING_BONUS));
    int destinationCrusadersBalance = Math.max(0, destinationCrusaders - sourceCrusaders);
    int destinationCrusadersBonus = Math.min(destinationCrusadersBalance, sourceWarlocks);
    float destinationCrusadersStrength = (destinationCrusaders - destinationCrusadersBonus + (destinationCrusadersBonus * FIGHTING_BONUS));
    int destinationAmazonsBalance = Math.max(0, destinationAmazons - sourceAmazons);
    int destinationAmazonsBonus = Math.min(destinationAmazonsBalance, sourceCrusaders);
    float destinationAmazonsStrength = (destinationAmazons - destinationAmazonsBonus + (destinationAmazonsBonus * FIGHTING_BONUS));
    float destinationTotalStrength = destinationWarlocksStrength + destinationCrusadersStrength + destinationAmazonsStrength;


    if (sourceTotalStrength > destinationTotalStrength) {

        RandomNumberGenerator rand = new RandomNumberGenerator();
        int[] limits = new int[3];
        limits[0] = sourceWarlocks;
        limits[1] = sourceCrusaders;
        limits[2] = sourceAmazons;
        int[] losses = rand.genNumberWithLimits((int) Math.ceil(destinationTotalStrength), limits);

        attackingTown.setWarlocks(attackingTown.getWarlocks() - sourceWarlocks);
        attackingTown.setCrusaders(attackingTown.getCrusaders() - sourceCrusaders);
        attackingTown.setAmazons(attackingTown.getAmazons() - sourceAmazons);

        defendingTown.setWarlocks(sourceWarlocks - losses[0]);
        defendingTown.setCrusaders(sourceCrusaders - losses[1]);
        defendingTown.setAmazons(sourceAmazons - losses[2]);
        defendingTown.setCorsairs(0);
        defendingTown.setBishops(0);
        defendingTown.setNecromancers(0);
        defendingTown.setArchitects(0);

        defendingTown.setCorpses(defendingTown.getCorpses() + destinationWarlocks + destinationCrusaders + destinationAmazons + losses[0] + losses[1] + losses[2]);
        defendingTown.setOwnerId(attackingTown.getOwnerId());
        return true;
    } else if (sourceTotalStrength <= destinationTotalStrength) {

        RandomNumberGenerator rand = new RandomNumberGenerator();
        int[] limits = new int[3];
        limits[0] = destinationWarlocks;
        limits[1] = destinationCrusaders;
        limits[2] = destinationAmazons;
        int[] losses = rand.genNumberWithLimits((int) Math.ceil(sourceTotalStrength), limits);

        attackingTown.setWarlocks(attackingTown.getWarlocks() - sourceWarlocks);
        attackingTown.setCrusaders(attackingTown.getCrusaders() - sourceCrusaders);
        attackingTown.setAmazons(attackingTown.getAmazons() - sourceAmazons);

        defendingTown.setWarlocks(destinationWarlocks - losses[0]);
        defendingTown.setCrusaders(destinationCrusaders - losses[1]);
        defendingTown.setAmazons(destinationAmazons - losses[2]);

        defendingTown.setCorpses(defendingTown.getCorpses() + sourceWarlocks + sourceCrusaders + sourceAmazons + losses[0] + losses[1] + losses[2]);
    }
    return false;

}

/**
 * Taken from Game.java
 *
 * Generate N random numbers when their SUM is known
 *
 * @author Deepak Azad
 */

public class RandomNumberGenerator  {

    public int[] genNumbers(int n, int sum){
        int[] nums = new int[n];
        int upperbound = Long.valueOf(Math.round(sum*1.0/n)).intValue();
        int offset = Long.valueOf(Math.round(0.5*upperbound)).intValue();

        int cursum = 0;
        Random random = new Random(new Random().nextInt());
        for(int i=0 ; i < n ; i++){
            int rand = random.nextInt(upperbound) + offset;
            if( cursum + rand > sum || i == n - 1) {
                rand = sum - cursum;
            }
            cursum += rand;
            nums[i]=rand;
            if(cursum == sum){
                break;
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }

    public int[] genNumberWithLimits(int sum, int[] limits) {

        int n = limits.length;
        int[] nums = new int[n];
        int total = 0;

        for (int l : limits) {
            total += l;
        }

        if (total <= sum)
            return limits;

        Random random = new Random(new Random().nextInt());
        while (sum > 0) { 
            int x = random.nextInt(n);
            if (nums[x] < limits[x]) {
                nums[x] += 1;
                sum--;
            }
        }
        return nums;
    }
}

// algorithm taken from Game.java
private int estimateProceedsOfTheft(Town theivingTown)
{
    int bestTownToTheiveProceedsAmount = -1;
    for (Town town : towns)
    {
        int goldStolen = estimateProceedsOfTheft(town,theivingTown);

        if (goldStolen > bestTownToTheiveProceedsAmount)
        {
            bestTownToTheiveProceedsAmount=goldStolen;
        }             
    }
    return bestTownToTheiveProceedsAmount;
}

// algorithm taken from Game.java
private int estimateProceedsOfTheft(Town victimTown,Town theivingTown)
{
    int goldStolen = 0;

    if (victimTown.getOwnerId()!= theivingTown.getOwnerId())
    {
        int goldReserve = victimTown.getGold() + GOLD_MAX_DEBT > 0 ? victimTown.getGold() + GOLD_MAX_DEBT : GOLD_MAX_DEBT - Math.abs(victimTown.getGold());
        int goldToSteal = theivingTown.getCorsairs() * GOLD_PER_STEAL;
        goldStolen = Math.min(goldReserve, goldToSteal);
    }

    return goldStolen;
}

// exactly as the method name states :)
private Town findStrongestTownThatCanDefeatGivenTown(Town defendingTown)
{
    int strongestSurvivingForce=-1;
    Town strongestTown=null;
    for (Town town : towns)
    {
        if (town.getOwnerId()!=defendingTown.getOwnerId() && town.getOwnerId()!=-1)
        {
            Town simulatedThisTown = new Town(defendingTown);
            Town simulatedOtherTown = new Town(town);

            // check to see if the other town could defeat this town
            if (battle(simulatedOtherTown,simulatedThisTown,simulatedOtherTown.getWarlocks(), simulatedOtherTown.getCrusaders(), simulatedOtherTown.getAmazons()))
            {
                //and if so, if it is the most overwhelming win, then that town is the target of conversion.
                int survivingForce=simulatedOtherTown.getAmazons()+simulatedOtherTown.getCrusaders()+simulatedOtherTown.getWarlocks()+
                                simulatedThisTown.getAmazons()+simulatedThisTown.getCrusaders()+simulatedThisTown.getWarlocks();
                if (survivingForce>strongestSurvivingForce)
                {
                    strongestSurvivingForce=survivingForce;
                    strongestTown = town;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return strongestTown;
}
}
```

To run:
1. Place into moogiesoft directory
2. In parent directory: java moogiesoft.Opportunist

Comment: Wow! This does pretty good!

Comment: This is great obviously, but I think you could marginally improve it by 1. stopping buying Bishops if you have more bishops than everyone else has troops combined, 2. attacking outlaw towns before turn 100 if they are undefended and there are no other bots. Should make your final score a lot higher.

Comment: Thanks, they are good suggestions. I will endevour to incorporate them :)

Comment: Well done, Opportunist's strategy was really interesting!

Comment: @Thrax thanks for the challenge! From my experiments, chance has a large factor on how well the Opportunist plays. It can easily be swamped in the beginning melee rounds. Normally by Zealot.

Comment: When recruiting you should probably reinitialize all recruitments to 0 between iterations of the outer while loop.

Answer (score 8):

## The Young Earl, Python 2

version 3.1

#### Update:

The Young Earl's mother will put up with his war mongering no longer. He is to
engage in town building instead. The Earl now has economic advisors and a lot of
spreadsheets. He wishes for a simpler life were he can just chase the chamber
maids.

```
import sys, re
from random import *
from operator import itemgetter

(PLAYER, TOWN, GOLD, CORPSES, WARLOCKS, CRUSADERS, AMAZONS, 
CORSAIRS, BISHOPS, NECROMANCERS, ARCHITECTS, PEONS, 
TEMPLES, BARRACKS, ESTATES, PALACES) = range(16)
OUTLAW = -1

def seqalloc(seq, num):
    outseq = []
    totalw = float(sum(seq))
    for weight in seq:
        share = int(round(num * weight / totalw)) if weight else 0
        outseq.append(share)
        totalw -= weight
        num -= share
    return outseq

def getstrength(t): return sum(t[WARLOCKS:AMAZONS+1])
def calcprofit(t): return t[GOLD] + 20*t[PEONS] + 200*t[ESTATES]
def getincome(t): return 5*t[PEONS] + 2*(t[PEONS]+t[CORSAIRS])*t[ESTATES]

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 5,20,5,   12,4,1,13,   40
else:
    try:
        output = 'W'

        parts = sys.argv[1].split(';')
        turn, phase, me, thistown = [int(parts.pop(0)) for i in range(4)]
        # Catagorize towns:
        towns = [map(int, re.split(r'_', town)) for town in parts]
        outlaws = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] == OUTLAW]
        mytowns = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] == me]
        enemy = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] not in (me, OUTLAW)]
        # Situation:
        here = [t for t in mytowns if t[TOWN] == thistown][0]
        strength = sorted(enemy, key=getstrength)
        strengthoutlaw = sorted(outlaws, key=getstrength)
        profenemy = sorted(enemy, key=calcprofit)
        profoutlaw = sorted(outlaws, key=calcprofit)
        rich = outlaws + sorted(enemy, key=itemgetter(GOLD))
        bandits = sum(sum(t[4:12]) for t in outlaws)
        # Planning:
        siblings = [t for t in mytowns if t != here]
        bodytowns = [t for t in mytowns if t[CORPSES] > 0]
        myincome = getincome(here)
        isrich = all(t[GOLD] < here[GOLD]*1.5 for t in enemy)
        wages = getstrength(here) + sum(here[CORSAIRS:ARCHITECTS+1]) * 2
        newpeons = (turn % 5 == 1) if turn > 1 else 0
        theft = 10 * max(0, bandits/len(enemy+mytowns) - here[CORSAIRS]*5)

        if phase == 2:
            output = 'S %u %u' % (rich[-1][TOWN], here[CORSAIRS])

        elif phase == 3:
            cash = max(0, here[GOLD] - wages)
            if theft < myincome:
                if here[ARCHITECTS] and cash > 200:
                    cash -= 200
                cash = max(0, cash - 150)
            # must haves:
            cors = (bandits/len(mytowns+enemy)) / 5 + 1
            cors = cors if cors < 25 else 0
            bish = here[PEONS]/50 + 1
            necro = here[CORPSES]/20 + 1
            require = [cors, bish, necro, 0]
            need = [0]*3 + [max(0, p-q) for p,q in zip(require, here[7:11])]
            if sum(need)*22 < cash:
                train = need
            else:
                train = seqalloc(need, cash/22)
            now = [p+q for p,q in zip(here[4:11], train)]
            cash -= sum(p*q for p,q in zip(train[3:], [12,20,20,15]))
            cash -= sum(train)*2   # new wages
            # nice to have:
            raises = min(here[CORPSES]/4+1, now[5]*5, cash/20)
            cash -= raises * 20
            archreq = max(0, 13 - here[ARCHITECTS])
            if theft < myincome and archreq * 17 < cash:
                train[6] += archreq
                cash -= archreq * 17
                if cash > 200:
                    cash -= 200
            newbish = max(0, cash/50 - now[4])
            if newpeons:
                bishreq = (myincome - 200 - wages)/50 * 12/10
                newbish += max(0, bishreq - (now[4]+newbish))
            newbish = min(newbish, cash/22)
            train[4] += newbish
            cash -= newbish * 22

            if sum(train) > 0:
                output = 'R %u %u %u %u %u %u %u' % tuple(train)

        elif phase == 6:
            cash = here[GOLD]
            if theft < myincome:
                if here[ARCHITECTS] and cash > 200:
                    cash -= 200
                cash = max(0, cash - 150)
            raises = min(here[CORPSES]/4+1, here[NECROMANCERS]*5, cash/20)
            cash -= raises * 20
            count = min(cash/50, here[BISHOPS])
            if count > 0:
                target = (strengthoutlaw + strength)[-1]
                count = min(count, sum(target[4:7]))
                ftrs = seqalloc(target[4:7], count)
                output = 'C %u %u %u %u' % tuple([target[TOWN]] + ftrs)

        elif phase == 7:
            force = getstrength(here)
            target = None
            if not enemy or force > getstrength(strength[-1])*2:
                for town in profenemy[::-1]+profoutlaw[::-1]:
                    if force > getstrength(town)*4:
                        target = town
                        break
            if target:
                raiders = seqalloc(here[4:7], force/2)
                output = 'A %u %u %u %u' % tuple([target[TOWN]] + raiders)

        elif phase == 8:
            cash = here[GOLD]
            if theft < myincome:
                if here[ARCHITECTS] and cash > 200:
                    cash -= 200
                cash = max(0, cash - 150)
            raises = min(here[CORPSES]/4+1, here[NECROMANCERS]*5, cash/20)
            if raises > 0:
                output = 'R %s' % raises

        elif phase == 9:
            if here[CORPSES] == 0 and bodytowns:
                dest = max(bodytowns, key=itemgetter(CORPSES))
                necro = min(here[NECROMANCERS], dest[CORPSES]/20+1)
                output = 'M %u 0 0 0 0 0 %u 0' % (dest[TOWN], necro)
            elif siblings and theft < 100 and isrich:
                given = min(here[GOLD]/33, here[CORSAIRS]*200)
                dest = max(siblings, key=getincome)
                output = 'T %u %u' % (dest[TOWN], given)

        elif phase == 11:
            if here[ARCHITECTS] and here[GOLD] >= 200:
                output = 'B E'
    except:
        pass
    print output
```

#### Performance Analysis

In the game competition, the latest Earl did well. In 2 games of the 10, he managed to win against the player towns but then froze up when it was time to conquer the bandit towns. I have fixed that bug - I never thought he would get that far ;-). In hindsight, I should have downloaded the controller and tested the Earl.

Congratulations to @Moogie and @TheBestOne for the best entries. It is a shame only one can win. They are both very good.

If there are more games, I would like to see how the repaired Earl survives against the two champions. I hope @Thrax will have some time free for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20634/discussion-between-thrax-and-carpetpython).

Comment: I'll run 3 more games with the new Earl to see the results. I also keep the git updated if you want to test it yourself. (and I'm almost done working on the next KOTH, expect a new one very soon!)

Comment: Here are the results : `1. Outlaw(12, 6671, 2233682)
2. YoungEarl(3, 6346, 208215)
3. Politician(1, 96, 0)` then `1. YoungEarl(16, 2514, 72315)` and finally `1. Politician(16, 1562, 53467)`. YoungEarl is indeed doing a pretty godd job.

Comment: Thanks Thrax. The Earl seems to be getting the hang of it. Better late than never eh?

Comment: Since Moogie & TheBestOne are still in the run too, I'll try to run 100 games for another bounty. (I'm a bit short on reputation though, I need at least twice what I already spent i.e. 300 rep)

Comment: I don't think a bonus is required. I am just keen to see some close competition. Thanks your effort in creating and running this challenge.

Answer (score 8):

## Aegis, Java

Aegis tries to play it safe and wait for other players to fight among themselves while building a nice residential block, full of luxurious estates. Since gold is a precious resource, Aegis recruits enough Corsairs to steal from its neighbours and protect its hard-earned money.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Aegis {

    int round;
    int phase;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    final int PEONS_PER_BISHOPS = 50;
    final int GOLD_STOLEN_PER_CORSAIR = 10;
    final int AVERAGE_COST_PER_UNIT = 2;
    final int GOLD_SAFETY = 100;
    final int PEONS_SAFETY = 20;
    final int COST_CORSAIR = 12;
    final int COST_SOLDIER = 10;
    final int COST_ESTATE = 200;
    final int MAX_CORSAIRS = 30;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("10 10 10 10 1 1 3 55");
        } else {
            new Aegis().protect(args[0].split(";"));
        }
    }

    private void protect(String[] args) {

        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        switch (phase) {
        case 2: steal(); break;
        case 3: recruit(); break;
        case 6: convert(); break;
        case 7: attack(); break;
        case 8: move(); break;
        case 9: resurrect(); break;
        case 11: build(); break;
        }
    }

    private void steal() {
        Town richestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.gold - b.gold).get();
        System.out.println("S " + richestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getCorsairs());
    }

    private void recruit() {
        Town richestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.gold - b.gold).get();
        Town soldierTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> (a.amazons + a.warlocks + a.crusaders) - (b.amazons + b.warlocks + b.crusaders)).get();
        int requiredBishops = Math.max(0, Math.floorDiv(thisTown.getPeons(), PEONS_PER_BISHOPS) - thisTown.getBishops());
        int requiredNecromancers = Math.max(0, 1 - thisTown.getNecromancers());
        int requiredArchitects = Math.max(0, 5 - thisTown.getArchitects());
        int requiredCorsairs = Math.max(0, Math.min(MAX_CORSAIRS - thisTown.getCorsairs(), Math.floorDiv(richestTown.getGold(), GOLD_STOLEN_PER_CORSAIR)));
        int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (AVERAGE_COST_PER_UNIT * thisTown.getUnits()) - GOLD_SAFETY;
        int peonsAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getPeons() - PEONS_SAFETY);
        int recruitedCorsairs = 0;
        int[] recruits = new int[3];
        int i = 0;
        while (peonsAvailable >= 5 && goldAvailable >= 50 && recruitedCorsairs < requiredCorsairs) {
            recruitedCorsairs++;
            peonsAvailable--;
            goldAvailable-=COST_CORSAIR;
        }
        while (peonsAvailable >= 5 && goldAvailable >= 50) {
            if (soldierTown.getSoldiers() > thisTown.getSoldiers()) {
                i = (i >= recruits.length - 1 ? 0 : i+1);
                recruits[i]++;
                peonsAvailable--;
                goldAvailable-=COST_SOLDIER;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (recruits[0] + recruits[1] + recruits[2] + recruitedCorsairs + requiredBishops + requiredNecromancers + requiredArchitects > 0) {
            System.out.println("R " + recruits[0] + " " + recruits[1] + " " + recruits[2] + " " + recruitedCorsairs + " " + requiredBishops + " " +  requiredNecromancers + " " + requiredArchitects);
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }

    private void convert() { 
        System.out.print("W");
    }

    private void attack() {
        if (this.countOtherPlayers() <= 1) {
            Town richestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.getGold() - b.getGold()).get();
            int neededWarlocks =  thisTown.getWarlocks() - richestTown.getWarlocks();
            int neededCrusaders = thisTown.getCrusaders() - richestTown.getCrusaders();
            int neededAmazons = thisTown.getAmazons() - richestTown.getAmazons() ;

            if (neededWarlocks > 0 && neededCrusaders > 0 && neededAmazons > 0) {
                System.out.println("A " + richestTown.getId() + " " + (richestTown.getWarlocks() + 1) + " " + (richestTown.getCrusaders() + 1) + " " + (richestTown.getAmazons() + 1));  
            } else {
                System.out.println("W");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }

    private void move() {
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            int goldBalance = town.getGold() - (AVERAGE_COST_PER_UNIT * thisTown.getUnits()) + GOLD_SAFETY;
            if (goldBalance <= 0) {
                System.out.println("T " + town.getId() + " " + (-goldBalance + GOLD_SAFETY));
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("W");
    }

    private void resurrect() {
        if (thisTown.getCorpses() > 0) {
            int corpses = Math.min(5, thisTown.getCorpses());
            System.out.print("R " + corpses);
        } else {
            System.out.print("W");
        }
    }

    private void build() {
        int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (AVERAGE_COST_PER_UNIT * thisTown.getUnits()) - GOLD_SAFETY;
        if (goldAvailable >= (COST_ESTATE + 50)) {
            System.out.println("B E");
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }

    public int countOtherPlayers() {
        List<Integer>players = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Town town : otherTowns) {
            if (!players.contains(town.getOwnerId()) && town.getOwnerId() >= 0) players.add(town.getOwnerId());
        }
        return players.size();
    }

    private class Town {

        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int gold;
        private final int corpses;
        private final int warlocks;
        private final int crusaders;
        private final int amazons;
        private final int corsairs;
        private final int bishops;
        private final int necromancers;
        private final int architects;
        private final int peons;
        private final int temples;
        private final int barracks;
        private final int estates;
        private final int palaces;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            warlocks = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            crusaders = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
            amazons = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
            corsairs = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
            bishops = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
            necromancers = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
            architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
            peons = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
            String[] args2 = args[12].split("-");
            temples = Integer.parseInt(args2[0]);
            barracks = Integer.parseInt(args2[1]);
            estates = Integer.parseInt(args2[2]);
            palaces = Integer.parseInt(args2[3]);
        }
        public int getOwnerId() {
            return ownerId;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public int getGold() {
            return gold;
        }
        public int getCorpses() {
            return corpses;
        }
        public int getWarlocks() {
            return warlocks;
        }
        public int getCrusaders() {
            return crusaders;
        }
        public int getAmazons() {
            return amazons;
        }
        public int getCorsairs() {
            return corsairs;
        }
        public int getBishops() {
            return bishops;
        }
        public int getNecromancers() {
            return necromancers;
        }
        public int getArchitects() {
            return architects;
        }
        public int getPeons() {
            return peons;
        }
        public int getTemples() {
            return temples;
        }
        public int getBarracks() {
            return barracks;
        }
        public int getEstates() {
            return estates;
        }
        public int getPalaces() {
            return palaces;
        }
        public int getBuildings() {
            return getTemples() + getBarracks() + getEstates() + getPalaces();
        }
        public int getSoldiers() {
            return getWarlocks() + getCrusaders() + getAmazons();
        }
        public int getUnits() {
             return getSoldiers() + getCorsairs() + getBishops() + getNecromancers() + getArchitects();
        }
        public int getCitizens() {
            return getUnits() + getPeons();
        }
        public boolean isMine(){
            return getOwnerId() == playerID;
        }
        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }
    }

}
```

Compile with `javac Aegis.java`

Run with `java Aegis`

Answer (score 6):

### TheLannisters (Java)

I choose this name because this submission gets rich as hell. Also, the sentence `TheLannisters gave birth to 30 children` sounds funny :D

**Edit:** It now waits with attacks for a long time and annoys players by stealing away their soldiers. It can also recruit every type of unit.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TheLannisters {
    private static final int COST_PER_SOLDIER = 11;
    private static final int COST_PER_CORSAIR = 14;
    private static final int COST_PER_BISHOP = 22;
    private static final int COST_PER_CONVERTION = 50;
    private final int MIN_PEONS;
    private final int phase;
    private final int myId;
    private final int round;
    private final List<Town> myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Town> enemyTowns = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Town> enemyPlayerTowns = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Town> outlawTowns = new ArrayList<>();
    private Town thisTown = null;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("12 14 10 11 3 5 5 40");
        } else {
            new TheLannisters(args[0].split(";")).command();
        }
    }

    public TheLannisters(String[] args) {
        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        myId = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        MIN_PEONS = 40 + round/2;
        int thisTownId = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        boolean hasAlreadyCommanded = false;
        for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++){
            Town town = new Town(args[i], hasAlreadyCommanded);
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.id == thisTownId){
                    thisTown = town;
                    hasAlreadyCommanded = true;
                }
            } else {
                enemyTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isOutlawTown()) {
                    outlawTowns.add(town);
                } else {
                    enemyPlayerTowns.add(town);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void command() {
        switch (phase) {
            case 2: steal(); break;
            case 3: recruit(); break;
            case 6: convert(); break;
            case 7: attack(); break;
            case 8: resurrect(); break;
            case 9: move(); break;
            case 11: build(); break;
        }
    }

    private void steal() {
        int goldToSteal = thisTown.corsairs * 10;

        int mostSoldiers = -1;
        Town richestTown = null;
        for (Town town : enemyPlayerTowns) {
            if (town.getSoldiers() > mostSoldiers && town.gold >= goldToSteal) {
                richestTown = town;
                mostSoldiers = town.getSoldiers();
            }
        }
        if (richestTown != null) {
            printCommand("S " + richestTown.id + " " + thisTown.corsairs);
        }

        // player with most gold (could be an outlaw)
        int mostGold = -1;
        for (Town town : enemyTowns) {
            if (town.gold > mostGold) {
                richestTown = town;
                mostGold = town.gold;
            }
        }
        printCommand("S " + richestTown.id + " " + thisTown.corsairs);
    }

    private void recruit() {
        int freePeons = (thisTown.peons - MIN_PEONS);
        if (!thisTown.isWeak()) {
            freePeons /= 2;
        }
        int freeGold = thisTown.gold - thisTown.getSoldiers() - thisTown.getCitizens() * 2;

        if (freePeons <= 0 || freeGold < COST_PER_SOLDIER) {
            printCommand("W");
        }

        int bishops = 0;
        if ((thisTown.bishops * 50 < thisTown.peons || thisTown.gold > 500) && freeGold >= COST_PER_BISHOP) {
            bishops = 1;
            freeGold -= COST_PER_BISHOP;
            freePeons--;
        }

        int necromancers = 0;
        if (thisTown.necromancers == 0 && freeGold >= COST_PER_BISHOP) {
            necromancers = 1;
            freeGold -= COST_PER_BISHOP;
            freePeons--;
        }

        int corsairs = 0;
        if (thisTown.getsRobbed() && freeGold >= COST_PER_CORSAIR) {
            corsairs = 1;
            freeGold -= COST_PER_CORSAIR;
            freePeons--;
        }

        int architects = 0;
        if (thisTown.architects == 0 && freeGold > 500) {
            architects = 1;
            freeGold -= COST_PER_BISHOP;
            freePeons--;
        }

        int producableSoldiers = Math.min(freePeons, freeGold / COST_PER_SOLDIER);
        int soldierPerType = producableSoldiers / 3;
        int crusaders = soldierPerType + (producableSoldiers % 3);
        printCommand("R " + soldierPerType + " " + crusaders + " " + soldierPerType + " " + corsairs + " " + bishops + " " + necromancers + " " + architects);
    }

    private void convert() {
        int freeGold = 0;
        if (thisTown.isWeak() || thisTown.corpses <= 0) {
            freeGold = thisTown.gold - 300;
        }
        if (freeGold < COST_PER_CONVERTION || thisTown.bishops == 0 || (round < 2 && thisTown.getSoldiers() > 35)) {
            printCommand("W");
        }
        int soldiersToConvert = freeGold / COST_PER_CONVERTION;
        int soldiersPerType = soldiersToConvert / 3;
        int amazons = soldiersPerType + (soldiersToConvert % 3);

        Town destination = null;        
        int mostSoldiers = -1;
        if (destination == null) {
            for (Town town : enemyPlayerTowns) {
                if (town.getSoldiers() > mostSoldiers) {
                    destination = town;
                    mostSoldiers = town.getSoldiers();
                }
            }
        }
        if (destination == null) {
            destination = outlawTowns.get(0);
        }
        printCommand("C " + destination.id + " " + soldiersPerType + " " + soldiersPerType + " " + amazons);
    }

    private void attack() {
        int leastSoldiers = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Town destination = null;

        if (thisTown.isWeak() || round < 21) {
            printCommand("W");
        }

        for (Town town : enemyTowns) {
            if (town.getSoldiers() < leastSoldiers) {
                destination = town;
                leastSoldiers = town.getSoldiers();
            }
        }

        boolean attackTogether = false;
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            if (!town.hasAlreadyCommanded && !town.isWeak() && !town.equals(thisTown)) {
                attackTogether = true;
            }
        }

        if (thisTown.getSoldiers() / 3.5 > destination.getSoldiers() || (attackTogether && thisTown.getSoldiers() / 2 >= destination.getSoldiers())) {
            int warlocks = thisTown.warlocks/2;
            int crusaders = thisTown.crusaders/2;
            int amazons = thisTown.amazons/2;
            while (warlocks + crusaders + amazons > (destination.getSoldiers() + 3) * 3) {
                warlocks = Math.max(0, --warlocks);
                crusaders = Math.max(0, --crusaders);
                amazons = Math.max(0, --amazons);
            }
            if (enemyPlayerTowns.size() == 0) {
                // dont send too many soldiers => otherwise they revolt
                printCommand("A " + destination.id + " " + (destination.warlocks + 2) + " " + (destination.crusaders + 2) + " " + (destination.amazons + 2));
            }
            printCommand("A " + destination.id + " " + warlocks + " " + crusaders + " " + amazons);
        } else {
            printCommand("W");
        }
    }

    private void resurrect() {
        printCommand("R 999");      
    }

    private void move() {
        if (myTowns.size() == 1 || thisTown.corpses > 10) {
            printCommand("W");
        }
        int leastGold = thisTown.gold;
        Town destination = null;
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            if (town.gold < leastGold) {
                leastGold = town.gold;
                destination = town;
            }
        }
        if (destination != null && (thisTown.hasMostGold() || (thisTown.gold > 100 && destination.gold - destination.getSoldiers() - destination.getCitizens() * 2 < 300) || (thisTown.gold > 300 && destination.getsRobbed()))) {
            printCommand("T " + destination.id + " " + Math.max(thisTown.gold / 10, 30));
        }
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            if (town.isWeak()) {
                printCommand("M " + town.id + " " + (thisTown.warlocks / 4) + " "  + (thisTown.crusaders / 4) + " "  + (thisTown.amazons / 4) + " 0 0 0 0");
            }
        }
        printCommand("W");
    }

    private void build() {
        if (thisTown.gold >= 500) {
            printCommand("B P");
        } else if (thisTown.gold > 300) {
            if (round % 2 == 0) {
                printCommand("B E");
            }
            printCommand("B B");    
        }
    }

    private class Town {

        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int gold;
        private final int corpses;
        private final int warlocks;
        private final int crusaders;
        private final int amazons;
        private final int corsairs;
        private final int bishops;
        private final int necromancers;
        private final int architects;
        private final int peons;
        private final boolean hasAlreadyCommanded;

        public Town(String string, boolean hasAlreadyCommanded){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            warlocks = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            crusaders = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
            amazons = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
            corsairs = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
            bishops = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
            necromancers = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
            architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
            peons = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
            this.hasAlreadyCommanded = hasAlreadyCommanded;
        }

        public int getSoldiers() {
            return warlocks + crusaders + amazons;
        }

        public int getCitizens() {
            return corsairs + bishops + necromancers + architects;
        }

        public boolean isMine(){
            return ownerId == myId;
        }

        public boolean isOutlawTown() {
            return ownerId == -1;
        }

        public boolean isWeak() {
            return willBeWeak(1);
        }

        public boolean willBeWeak(double divisor) {
            if (enemyPlayerTowns.size() == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            int mySoldiers = (int) (getSoldiers() * divisor);
            int weakerTowns = 0;
            for (Town town : enemyTowns) {
                if (town.getSoldiers() < mySoldiers) {
                    weakerTowns++;
                }
            }
            for (Town town : myTowns) {
                if (town.getSoldiers() < mySoldiers) {
                    weakerTowns++;
                }
            }
            return weakerTowns <= 2;
        }

        public boolean getsRobbed() {
            int outlaws = 0;
            for (Town town : outlawTowns) {
                outlaws += town.getSoldiers() + town.getCitizens() + town.peons;
            }
            int notOutlawTowns = enemyTowns.size() + myTowns.size() - outlawTowns.size();
            int outlawsPerTown = outlaws / notOutlawTowns;
            return outlawsPerTown - corsairs * 5 > 0;
        }

        public boolean hasMostGold() {
            for (Town town : enemyTowns) {
                if (gold < town.gold) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void printCommand(String command) {
        System.out.println(command);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a NPE when you're fighting only against Outlaws. This snippet : `for (Town town : enemyPlayerTowns)` is not getting anything, so your `Town richestTown = null;` or equivalent stay null.

Comment: @Thrax Thank you, should be fixed by now :)

Answer (score 6):

## Politician, Java

v3

**Update:** Added annoying commentary and better planning.

**Update:** Recruits much less trains(corsairs) and focuses on building up the economy(peons).

**Update:** Tweaked a couple of parameters.

**Update:** Attacks much more often. Listens to scientists more.

He has two goals.

1. Unlimited gold.
2. Unlimited armies.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Politician {

    private static final int SOLDIER_COST = 11;
    private static final int AMBASSADOR_COST = 22;
    private static final int SCIENTIST_COST = 22;
    private static final int TRAIN_COST = 14;
    private static final int ARCHITECT_COST = 17;
    private static final int CONVERSION_COST = 50;
    private static final double MIN_SOLDIER_RATIO = .75;
    private static final int MIN_PEOPLE = 30;
    private static final int MIN_ARCHITECTS = 13;
    private static final int MAX_PEOPLE = 200;
    int round;
    int phase;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<State> states;
    List<State> myStates;
    List<State> otherStates;

    State thisState;

    public Politician(String... args) {
        args = args[0].split(";");

        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        states = new ArrayList<>();
        myStates = new ArrayList<>();
        otherStates = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++){
            states.add(new State(args[i]));
        }


        for (State state : states){
            if (state.isMine()){
                myStates.add(state);
                if (state.isThisTown()){
                    thisState = state;
                }
            } else {
                otherStates.add(state);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("8 8 8 26 4 1 13 32");
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println(new Politician(args).conquer());
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("We, the enslaved people, declare Politician the winner.");
            }
        }
    }

    private String conquer() {

        switch (phase){
            case 2:
                return steal();
            case 3:
                return conscript();
            case 6:
                return bribe();
            case 7:
                return orderAttack();
            case 8:
                return topSecret();
            case 9:
                return handouts();
            case 11:
                return roadConstruction();
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException();//Civil war!!!
        }
    }

    private String steal() {
        State bestState = otherStates.stream().max((a, b) -> a.profit() - b.profit()).get();
        return "S " + bestState.getId() + " " + thisState.getTrains();
    }

    private String conscript() {
        int gold = thisState.getFreeGold();

        int neededTrains = Math.max(neededTrains() - thisState.getTrains(), 0);
        neededTrains = Math.min(neededTrains, thisState.getRegularPeople());
        neededTrains = Math.min(neededTrains, gold / TRAIN_COST);
        thisState.regularPeople -= neededTrains;
        gold -= neededTrains * TRAIN_COST;

        int neededSoldiers = soldiersNeeded();
        neededSoldiers = Math.min(gold / SOLDIER_COST, neededSoldiers);
        int neededAmbassadors = Math.min(neededSoldiers, (gold - 200 - 10 * thisState.getCorpses() -
                CONVERSION_COST * thisState.getAmbassadors()) / (CONVERSION_COST + AMBASSADOR_COST));
        neededAmbassadors = Math.min(maxSoldiers() - thisState.getAmbassadors(), neededAmbassadors);
        neededSoldiers -= neededAmbassadors;
        thisState.regularPeople -= neededSoldiers;
        gold -= neededSoldiers * SOLDIER_COST;

        neededAmbassadors += (int) Math.max(Math.round(Math.ceil(thisState.getRegularPeople() / 50.0) -
                thisState.getAmbassadors() - neededAmbassadors), 0);
        neededAmbassadors = Math.min(gold / AMBASSADOR_COST, neededAmbassadors);
        thisState.regularPeople -= neededAmbassadors;
        gold -= neededAmbassadors * AMBASSADOR_COST;

        int neededScientists = (int) Math.max(Math.round(Math.ceil(thisState.getCorpses() / 10.0) -
                thisState.getScientists()), 0);
        neededScientists = Math.min(gold / SCIENTIST_COST, neededScientists);
        thisState.regularPeople -= neededScientists;
        gold -= neededScientists * SCIENTIST_COST;

        int neededArchitects = 0;

        if (thisState.getRegularPeople() > MIN_PEOPLE){
            int freePeople = thisState.getRegularPeople() - MIN_PEOPLE;

            neededArchitects = Math.max(MIN_ARCHITECTS - thisState.getArchitects(), 0);
            neededArchitects = Math.min(neededArchitects, freePeople);
            neededArchitects = Math.min(neededArchitects, gold / ARCHITECT_COST);
            freePeople -= neededArchitects;
            gold -= neededArchitects * ARCHITECT_COST;

            if (freePeople + MIN_PEOPLE > MAX_PEOPLE){

                if (freePeople + MIN_PEOPLE > MAX_PEOPLE){
                    freePeople = freePeople + MIN_PEOPLE - MAX_PEOPLE;
                }

                neededAmbassadors += Math.min(gold / AMBASSADOR_COST, freePeople);
                neededAmbassadors = Math.min(neededAmbassadors, maxSoldiers() - thisState.getAmbassadors());
                gold -= neededAmbassadors * AMBASSADOR_COST;
                freePeople -= neededAmbassadors;

                neededSoldiers += Math.min(gold / SOLDIER_COST, freePeople);
            }

        }

        int neededAirmen = neededSoldiers / 3;
        int neededSailors = neededSoldiers / 3;
        int neededPrivates = neededSoldiers / 3;


        return "R " + neededAirmen + " " + neededSailors + " " + neededPrivates + " " + neededTrains + " " +
                neededAmbassadors + " " + neededScientists + " " + neededArchitects;
    }

    private int neededTrains() {
        int totalOutlaws = 0;
        int totalStates = myStates.size();
        for (State state : otherStates){
            if (state.isOutlaw()){
                totalOutlaws += state.getTotalCitizens();
            } else {
                totalStates++;
            }
        }
        return (int) Math.round(Math.ceil(.2 * totalOutlaws / totalStates));
    }

    private int soldiersNeeded(){
        int soldiers = (int) ((MIN_SOLDIER_RATIO * thisState.getRegularPeople() - thisState.getTotalSoldiers()) /
                        (MIN_SOLDIER_RATIO + 1));
        soldiers = Math.max(soldiers, minSoldiers() + 5 - thisState.getTotalSoldiers());
        soldiers = Math.max(soldiers, maxSoldiers() / 2 - thisState.getTotalSoldiers());
        soldiers = Math.max(soldiers, 0);
        return soldiers;
    }

    private String bribe() {
        int soldiersToConvert = Math.min(thisState.ambassadors, (thisState.getGold() - 200 - 10 *
                thisState.getCorpses()) / CONVERSION_COST);
        soldiersToConvert = Math.max(soldiersToConvert, 0);
        State toughest = otherStates.stream().max((a,b) -> a.getTotalSoldiers() - b.getTotalSoldiers()).get();
        soldiersToConvert = Math.min(soldiersToConvert, toughest.getTotalSoldiers());
        int airmen = (int) ((1.0 * toughest.getAirmen() / toughest.getTotalSoldiers()) * soldiersToConvert);
        soldiersToConvert -= airmen;
        int sailors = (int) ((1.0 * toughest.getSailors() / toughest.getTotalSoldiers()) * soldiersToConvert) * 3 / 2;
        soldiersToConvert -= sailors;
        int privates = soldiersToConvert;
        return "C " + toughest.getId() + " " + airmen + " " + sailors + " " + privates;
    }

    private String orderAttack() {
        if (round < 99 && otherTowns.size() < 2){
            return "W";
        }
        int soldiers = thisState.getFreeSoldiers();
        otherStates.sort((a,b) -> b.getRegularPeople() / Math.max(b.getTotalSoldiers(), 1) - a.getRegularPeople() / Math.max(a.getTotalSoldiers(), 1));
        if (otherStates.get(0).getTotalSoldiers() < soldiers){//Attack!!!!
            int airmen = (int) (((thisState.getAirmen()*1.0) / thisState.getTotalSoldiers()) * soldiers);
            int sailors = (int) (((thisState.getSailors()*1.0) / thisState.getTotalSoldiers()) * soldiers);
            int privates = (int) (((thisState.getPrivates()*1.0) / thisState.getTotalSoldiers()) * soldiers);
            return "A " + otherStates.get(0).getId() + " " + airmen + " " + sailors + " " + privates;
        }
        return getWaitString();
    }

    private String handouts() {

        State poorestState = null;
        int goldOfPoorestTown = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for (State state : myStates){
            if (state.getGold() < goldOfPoorestTown){
                poorestState = state;
                goldOfPoorestTown = state.getGold();
            }
        }
        if (thisState.getGold() <= goldOfPoorestTown){
            return getWaitString();
        }
        return "T " + poorestState.getId() + " " + (thisState.getGold() - poorestState.getGold())  / 2;
    }

    private String topSecret() {
        return "R " + thisState.getCorpses();
    }

    private String roadConstruction() {
        int airportPriority = thisState.getAirmen() + thisState.getAmbassadors() + thisState.getScientists();
        int highwayPriority = thisState.getSailors() + thisState.getPrivates();
        int railroadPriority = thisState.getTrains() + thisState.getRegularPeople();
        int palacePriority = 5;//Why would we build a palace???
        if (airportPriority > highwayPriority && airportPriority > railroadPriority && airportPriority >
                palacePriority && thisState.getGold() > 200){
            return "B T";
        } else if (highwayPriority > railroadPriority && highwayPriority > palacePriority && thisState.getGold() > 200){
            return "B B";
        } else if (railroadPriority > palacePriority && thisState.getGold() > 200){
            return "B E";
        } else if (thisState.getGold() > 500){
            return "B P";
        } else {
            return getWaitString();
        }
    }

    private int maxSoldiers(){
        int max = 0;
        for (State state : otherStates){
            if (state.getTotalSoldiers() > max){
                max = state.getTotalSoldiers();
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    private int minSoldiers(){
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (State state : otherStates){
            if (state.getTotalSoldiers() < min){
                min = state.getTotalSoldiers();
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    private class State {

        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int gold;
        private final int corpses;
        private final int airmen;
        private final int sailors;
        private final int privates;
        private final int trains;
        private final int ambassadors;
        private final int scientists;
        private final int architects;
        private int regularPeople;
        private final int airports;
        private final int highways;
        private final int railroads;
        private final int palaces;

        public State(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            airmen = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            sailors = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
            privates = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
            trains = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
            ambassadors = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
            scientists = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
            architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
            regularPeople = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
            airports = Integer.parseInt(args[12]);
            highways = Integer.parseInt(args[13]);
            railroads = Integer.parseInt(args[14]);
            palaces = Integer.parseInt(args[15]);
        }
        public int getOwnerId() {
            return ownerId;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public int getGold() {
            return gold;
        }
        public int getCorpses() {
            return corpses;
        }
        public int getAirmen() {
            return airmen;
        }
        public int getSailors() {
            return sailors;
        }
        public int getPrivates() {
            return privates;
        }
        public int getTrains() {
            return trains;
        }
        public int getAmbassadors() {
            return ambassadors;
        }
        public int getScientists() {
            return scientists;
        }
        public int getArchitects() {
            return architects;
        }
        public int getRegularPeople() {
            return regularPeople;
        }
        public int getAirports() {
            return airports;
        }
        public int getHighways() {
            return highways;
        }
        public int getRailroads() {
            return railroads;
        }
        public int getPalaces() {
            return palaces;
        }
        public int getTotalBuildings() {
            return getAirports() + getHighways() + getRailroads() + getPalaces();
        }
        public int getTotalSoldiers() {
            return getAirmen() + getSailors() + getPrivates();
        }
        public int getTotalUnits() {
            return getTotalSoldiers() + getTrains() + getAmbassadors() + getScientists() + getArchitects();
        }
        public int getTotalCitizens() {
            return getTotalUnits() + getRegularPeople();
        }
        public boolean isMine(){
            return getOwnerId() == playerID;
        }
        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }
        public int neededGold(){
            return 2 * getTotalUnits() - getTotalSoldiers();
        }
        public int getFreeGold(){
            return gold - neededGold();
        }

        public int getFreeSoldiers() {
            int soldiers = Math.max((int) (getTotalSoldiers() - regularPeople * MIN_SOLDIER_RATIO), 0);
            soldiers = Math.min(soldiers, getTotalSoldiers() - minSoldiers() - 5);
            soldiers = Math.min(soldiers, getTotalSoldiers() - maxSoldiers() / 2);
            soldiers = Math.max(soldiers, 0);
            return soldiers;
        }

        public boolean isOutlaw() {
            return ownerId == -1;
        }

        public int income() {
            return 5 * regularPeople + 10 * trains + 2 * (airmen + ambassadors + scientists) * airports + 2 * (sailors +
                    privates) * highways + 2 * (trains + regularPeople) * railroads + 10 * palaces;
        }

        public int wages() {
            return airmen + sailors + privates + 2 * (trains + ambassadors + scientists + architects);
        }

        public int profit() {
            return income() - wages();
        }
    }

    private static String getWaitString(){
        switch ((int) (Math.random() * 7)){
            case 0:
                return "We will win!";
            case 1:
                return "Winny the Pooh, Winny the Pooh";
            case 2:
                return "Who washed Washington's white woolen underwear when Washington's laundry woman, went west?";
            case 3:
                return "What's up doc?";
            case 4:
                return "Why is this taking so long?";
            case 5:
                return "Wool is better than cotton.";
            case 6:
                return "Will I win?";
            case 7:
                return "What's your favorite color?";
            default:
                return "What! This message should not be being printed.";
        }
    }

}
```

## Explanation

He has two goals.

1. Unlimited gold.
2. Unlimited armies.

**How to get gold:**

Politician merely hires architects to build airports, highways, and railroads. Piles of money start pouring in rather quickly. After increasing taxes, Politician has unlimited money.

**How to get armies:**

This is a little harder. With limited people, you can only attain a small army. With ambassadors, he can hire even bigger armies, but they still aren't quite big enough. After some contemplation Politician figured out that conquering other nations and then enslaving the people gives him fairly large armies. But they are still not nearly big enough. After hiring some scientists, they tell him they have discovered the secret to raise the dead, unfortunately, they are no longer soldiers after resurrection. After deep contemplation Politician figures out that this is to his advantage, and hires the risen dead as ambassadors that hire even more soldiers, ad infinitum.

Comment: Unfortunately, this Politician - like every politician - is all empty promises and can't stand up to Sehtimianer. (Lost round 30, second to last alive)

Comment: Now it is ruling over the world, congrats!

Comment: @Thrax And he still is!

Comment: I am impressed... like all Politicians... he his very adaptable to change :)

Comment: Battle is fierce, but Politician didn't come on top for now!

Comment: Great job, Politician was really close to victory!

Comment: Awesome job on your entry. I would like to think that your bot and Opportunist bot are pretty evenly matched. Given another random seed, the final results could have gone your way. Perhaps if Thrax is willing, he might like to run a 100 game super series to lessen the random effects.

Comment: @Moogie I'm actually going to post another bot soon that will hopefully win both entries. Good job on winning the bounty :)

Comment: @Moogie I could start another bounty if you're willing to compete again (since CarpetPython is too). I'll just need a way to collect the results of 100 games and calculate the scores (it will be a bit tedious to do manually).

Comment: @Thrax I'm willing to compete again. However, the current Politician is the final version. As I said to Moogie, I might post another entry in a while.

Comment: @Thrax yes i am willing to compete again :) This might be a good time to fix some rules. e.g. the palaces are next to worthless as it takes 50 turns to recoup the cost of buying them. And I feel that perhaps there is too much risk in fighting...

Comment: @Moogie You're right about palaces, `+50 gold/turn` and price at `300 gold` would be better I think. And what do you mean by "too much risk in fighting"?

Comment: well, think it is a product of the binary nature of the fighting... not matter if you win or loose you will loose all your fighters, opening yourself up to attack from other towns. While i do not have a solution per se, Perhaps battles can occur in bouts, where chance can have an affect. How about bout each unit type (for both attacker and defender) gets a random .8 to 1.2 multiplier (unknown to the players) and then they fight. At the end of each bout the attacker has the option to withdraw or continue to attack. If continue then a new bout occurs

Comment: @Thrax Multiple starting towns would force the bots to actually use teamwork.

Comment: @TheBestOne Yes I think that multiple towns would add an interesting dimension.

Comment: Further to my bout suggestion. I am thinking perhaps 3 or 5 bouts per attack. The defending and attacking forces are split evenly though across the bouts. If the attacker wins all bouts then he takes the city.

Answer (score 5):

## The Zealots (Python)

(Based on CarpetPython's code.)

Build as meany temples as possible! Raise the dead! Convert the infidel!

```
import sys
from random import *
from operator import itemgetter

(PLAYER, TOWN, GOLD, CORPSES, WARLOCKS, CRUSADERS, AMAZONS, 
CORSAIRS, BISHOPS, NECROMANCERS, ARCHITECTS, PEONS, 
TEMPLES, BARRACKS, ESTATES, PALACES) = range(16)

def getstrength(t):
    return t[WARLOCKS]+t[CRUSADERS]*1.5+t[AMAZONS]/1.5

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 20, 5, 5, 10, 8, 5, 7, 40
else:
    parts = sys.argv[1].split(';')
    turn, phase, me, thistown = [int(parts.pop(0)) for i in range(4)]
    towns = [[int(v) for v in town.split('_')] for town in parts]
    enemy = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] != me]
    mytowns = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] == me]
    here = [t for t in mytowns if t[TOWN] == thistown][0]
    otherids = [t[TOWN] for t in enemy]
    strength = sorted(enemy, key=getstrength)
    rich = sorted(enemy, key=itemgetter(GOLD))

    output = ''
    if phase == 2:
        output = 'S %s %s' % (rich[-1][TOWN], here[CORSAIRS])
    elif phase == 3:
        Warlocks=Crusaders=Amazons=Corsairs=Bishops=Necromancers=Architects=0
        if here[CORPSES] > 5*here[NECROMANCERS]:
            Necromancers = 1
        if here[PEONS] > 50*here[BISHOPS]:
            Bishops = 1
        if here[WARLOCKS] < strength[0][CRUSADERS]:
            Warlocks = 2
            Amazons = 2
        if here[WARLOCKS] < here[AMAZONS]:
            Warlocks += 1
        if here[GOLD] > 200:
            Architects = 1
        if rich[-1][GOLD] > 100+2*here[GOLD]:
            Corsairs = 1
        output = 'R %s %s %s %s %s %s %s' % (Warlocks,Crusaders,Amazons,Corsairs,Bishops,Necromancers,Architects)
    elif phase == 6:
        if here[GOLD] > 300:
            output = 'C %s %s %s %s' % (strength[0][TOWN],here[GOLD]/300,here[GOLD]/300,here[GOLD]/300)
    elif phase == 7:
        target = strength[0]
        if getstrength(target) < getstrength(here)*3/5:
            output = 'A %s %s %s 0' % (target[TOWN],here[WARLOCKS]*3/4,target[AMAZONS])
    elif phase == 8:
        if here[CORPSES] > 10:
            output = 'R %s' % (here[NECROMANCERS]*5)
    elif phase == 9:
        pass  # move people or gold here
    elif phase == 11 and here[GOLD] > 300:
        output = 'B T'   # Build a temple!

    print output if output else 'W'
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like Java to me.

Comment: I think you meant python

Comment: @Thrax you mean missing colon

Comment: @soktinpk: Yes this is python; I don't know how I got java.

Comment: @TheBestOne I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

## Serenity, Lua

Focuses on reaching Serenity through religion. Tries to convert the infidels and wait for towns to reach a critical state before expading its faith by building new temples.

```
function explode(d,p)
  local t, ll; t={}; ll=0
  if(#p == 1) then return {p} end
    while true do
      l=string.find(p,d,ll,true)
      if l~=nil then table.insert(t, string.sub(p,ll,l-1)); ll=l+1
      else table.insert(t, string.sub(p,ll)); break
      end
    end
  return t
end

function soldiers(t)
  local s
  s = t["WARLOCKS"] + t["CRUSADERS"] + t["AMAZONS"]
  return s
end

function reserve(t)
  local s
  s = t["GOLD"] - (3 * soldiers(t))
  return s
end

parameters = {"PLAYER", "TOWN", "GOLD", "CORPSES", "WARLOCKS", "CRUSADERS", "AMAZONS", 
"CORSAIRS", "BISHOPS", "NECROMANCERS", "ARCHITECTS", "PEONS", "TEMPLES", "BARRACKS", 
"ESTATES", "PALACES"}

if (#arg < 1) then
  print("5 5 5 10 10 1 3 59")  
else

  args = explode(";", arg[1])

  local round = tonumber(args[1])
  local phase = tonumber(args[2])
  local playerID = tonumber(args[3])
  local thisTownID = tonumber(args[4])
  local thisTown = {}
  local towns = {}
  local enemyTowns = {}
  local myTowns = {}
  local output = "W"
  local stock = 200
  local peons = 33
  local bishops = 20

  for i=5,#args,1 do
    local town = explode("_", args[i])
    towns[town[2]] = {}
    for key, value in pairs(town) do 
      towns[town[2]][parameters[key]] = tonumber(value)
    end
  end

  for i, town in pairs(towns) do 
    if town["PLAYER"] == playerID then
      if town["TOWN"] == thisTownID then thisTown = town end
      table.insert(myTowns, town)
    else
      table.insert(enemyTowns, town)
    end
  end

  if phase == 2 then
    local richestTown
    for i, town in pairs(myTowns) do
      if richestTown == nil then richestTown = town end
      if richestTown["GOLD"] > town["GOLD"] then richestTown = town end
    end
    if thisTown["CORSAIRS"] > 0 then output = "S "..richestTown["TOWN"].." "..thisTown["CORSAIRS"] end
  elseif phase == 3 then 
    local necromancers = 0
    local architects = 0
    if thisTown["NECROMANCERS"] < 1 then necromancers = 1 end
    if thisTown["ARCHITECTS"] < 1 then architects = 1 end
    if reserve(thisTown) > stock and thisTown["PEONS"] > peons then output = "R 0 0 0 0 "..math.max(0, math.min(thisTown["BISHOPS"] - bishops, math.min(thisTown["PEONS"] - peons, math.floor((reserve(thisTown) - stock) / 20)))).." "..necromancers.." "..architects end
  elseif phase == 6 then
    local biggestTown
    for i, town in pairs(enemyTowns) do
      if biggestTown == nil then biggestTown = town end
      if soldiers(biggestTown) > soldiers(town) then biggestTown = town end  
    end
    local units = math.min(thisTown["BISHOPS"], math.floor((reserve(thisTown) - stock) / 50))
    if (reserve(thisTown) > stock) then output = "C "..biggestTown["TOWN"].." "..math.floor(units/3).." "..math.floor(units/3).." "..math.floor(units/3) end
  elseif phase == 7 then 
    for i, town in pairs(enemyTowns) do
      if soldiers(town) <= 3 and soldiers(thisTown) >= 9 then output = "A "..town["TOWN"].." 3 3 3"; break end
    end
  elseif phase == 8 then
    if thisTown["CORPSES"] > 0 and thisTown["NECROMANCERS"] > 0 then output = "R "..math.min(thisTown["NECROMANCERS"] * 5, thisTown["CORPSES"]) end
  elseif phase == 9 then
    local smallestTown, poorestTown
    for i, town in pairs(myTowns) do
      if smallestTown == nil then smallestTown = town end
      if poorestTown == nil then poorestTown = town end
      if soldiers(smallestTown) < soldiers(town) then smallestTown = town end  
      if poorestTown["GOLD"] < town["GOLD"] then poorestTown = town end  
      if (soldiers(thisTown) - soldiers(smallestTown) >= 18) then output = "M "..thisTown["TOWN"].." 3 3 3" break end
      if (thisTown["GOLD"] - poorestTown["GOLD"] >= 600) then output = "T "..thisTown["TOWN"].." 300" break end
    end
  elseif phase == 11 then
     if reserve(thisTown) > (stock + 200) then output = "B T" end
  end

  print(output)

end
```

Run with `lua Serenity.lua` (requires Lua 5.2)

Answer (score 4):

## Sehtimianer, Java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Sehtimianer {
private static final int GOLD_MAX_DEBT = 200;
private static final int BIRTH_ROUND = 5;
private static final int ZOMBIE_WAKING_CHANCE = 10;
private static final int NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY = 5;
private static final int DEMON_SUMMON_CHANCE = 10;
private static final int BISHOP_PRAYER_CAPACITY = 50;
private static final int CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO = 5;

public static final int GOLD_PER_WARLOCK = -1;
public static final int GOLD_PER_CRUSADER = -1;
public static final int GOLD_PER_AMAZON = -1;
public static final int GOLD_PER_CORSAIR = -2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_BISHOP = -2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_NECRO = -2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_ARCHITECT = -2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_PEON = 5;

public static final int GOLD_PER_RESURRECTION = 20;
public static final int GOLD_PER_CONVERSION = 50;
public static final int GOLD_PER_STEAL = 10;

public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_WARLOCK = 10;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_CRUSADER = 10;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_AMAZON = 10;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_CORSAIR = 12;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_BISHOP = 20;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_NECRO = 20;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_ARCHITECT = 15;
public static final int GOLD_RECRUIT_DEFAULT = 20;

public static final int GOLD_PER_TEMPLE = 2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_BARRACKS = 2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_ESTATE = 2;
public static final int GOLD_PER_PALACE = 10;

public static final int GOLD_COST_BUILDING = 200;

public static final int COMPLETION_PER_ARCHITECT = 8;
public static final int COMPLETION_NEEDED = 100;
public static final int ARCHITECTS = (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * COMPLETION_NEEDED / COMPLETION_PER_ARCHITECT);

int round;
int phase;
int playerID;
int thisTownID;

List<Town> towns;
List<Town> myTowns;
List<Town> playerTowns;
List<Town> outlawTowns;

Town thisTown;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("9 9 9 24 5 2 13 29");
    } else {
        new Sehtimianer().actions(args[0].split(";"));
    }
}

private void actions(String[] args) {

    round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    towns = new ArrayList<Town>();
    myTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();
    playerTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();
    outlawTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();

    for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++) {
        towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
    }

    for (Town town : towns) {
        if (town.isMine()) {
            myTowns.add(town);
            if (town.isThisTown()) {
                thisTown = town;
            }
        } else {
            if (town.getOwnerId() == -1) {
                outlawTowns.add(town);
            } else {
                playerTowns.add(town);
            }
        }
    }
    if (outlawTowns.size() == 0 && playerTowns.size() == 0) {
        System.out.print("WIN : D");
        return;
    }

    if (phase == 2) {
        steal();
    } else if (phase == 3) {
        recruit();
    } else if (phase == 6) {
        convert();
    } else if (phase == 7) {
        attack();
    } else if (phase == 8) {
        resurrect();
    } else if (phase == 9) {
        move();
    } else if (phase == 11) {
        build();
    }
}

private List<Town> calcStrongestPlayers() {
    if (playerTowns.size() == 0) {
        return outlawTowns;
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> playerTownCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Integer count;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (Town town : playerTowns) {
        count = playerTownCount.get(town.getOwnerId());
        if (count == null) {
            count = Integer.valueOf(1);
        } else {
            count = Integer.valueOf(count + 1);
        }
        playerTownCount.put(town.getOwnerId(), count);

        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    Set<Integer> strongestPlayers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : playerTownCount.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == maxCount) {
            strongestPlayers.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    return playerTowns.stream().filter(a -> strongestPlayers.contains(a.getOwnerId())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private void steal() {
    // S destinationId corsairs
    List<Town> afterFilter = calcStrongestPlayers().stream().filter(a -> a.getGold() > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (afterFilter.size() == 0) {
        afterFilter = calcStrongestPlayers();
    }
    Town poorestTown = afterFilter.stream().min((a, b) -> a.gold - b.gold).get();
    System.out.println("S " + poorestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getCorsairs());
}

private boolean willAttackSoon() {
    Town strongestTown;
    if (playerTowns.size() > 0) {
        strongestTown = playerTowns.stream().max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();
        if ((thisTown.getSoldiers() + thisTown.getBishops()) / 3 <= strongestTown.getSoldiers()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    strongestTown = calcStrongestPlayers().stream().max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();

    int deltaWarlocks = thisTown.getWarlocks() - (strongestTown.getWarlocks() + strongestTown.getAmazons());
    int deltaCrusaders = thisTown.getCrusaders() - (strongestTown.getCrusaders() + strongestTown.getWarlocks());
    int deltaAmazons = thisTown.getAmazons() - (strongestTown.getAmazons() + strongestTown.getCrusaders());

    return (deltaWarlocks + deltaCrusaders + deltaAmazons) > 0;
}

private void recruit() {
    // R warlocks crusaders amazons corsairs bishops necros architects
    int peonsAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getPeons() - round);

    int corsairNeed = calcCorsairsNeeded(thisTown);
    int goldForNecros = Math.min(thisTown.getCorpses(), thisTown.getNecros() * NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY) * GOLD_PER_RESURRECTION;
    int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - thisTown.getBishops() * GOLD_PER_CONVERSION - goldForNecros - GOLD_COST_BUILDING + calcWages(thisTown)
            - (calcCashflow(thisTown) < GOLD_MAX_DEBT ? (corsairNeed * CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO * GOLD_PER_STEAL) : 0);
    int corsairGoldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() + calcWages(thisTown) - goldForNecros;
    boolean onlyCorsair = false;
    if (goldAvailable < 0) {
        if (corsairGoldAvailable > 0) {
            onlyCorsair = true;
            goldAvailable = corsairGoldAvailable;
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
            return;
        }
    }

    int necroNeed = Math.max(0, (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * thisTown.getCorpses() / NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY) - thisTown.getNecros());
    necroNeed = Math.max(necroNeed, Math.min(peonsAvailable, calcOtherNecrosNeeded() / 3));
    int architectNeed = Math.max(0, ARCHITECTS - thisTown.getArchitects());

    int necros = 0;
    if (!onlyCorsair) {
        int necroCost = GOLD_RECRUIT_NECRO + GOLD_PER_RESURRECTION * NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY - GOLD_PER_NECRO;
        necros = Math.min(necroNeed, goldAvailable / necroCost);
        goldAvailable -= necros * necroCost;
        peonsAvailable -= necros;
    }

    if (willAttackSoon()) {
        corsairNeed = calcCorsairSpread(thisTown) * 2 - thisTown.getCorsairs();
    }
    corsairNeed = (int) Math.max(corsairNeed, calcOtherCorsairsNeeded());

    int corsairCost = GOLD_RECRUIT_CORSAIR - GOLD_PER_CORSAIR;
    int corsairs = Math.min(corsairNeed, peonsAvailable);
    corsairs = Math.min(corsairs, goldAvailable / corsairCost);
    goldAvailable -= corsairs * corsairCost;
    peonsAvailable -= corsairs;

    int architects = 0;
    if (!onlyCorsair) {
        int architectCost = GOLD_RECRUIT_ARCHITECT - GOLD_PER_ARCHITECT;
        architects = Math.min(architectNeed, peonsAvailable);
        architects = Math.min(architects, goldAvailable / architectCost);
        goldAvailable -= architects * architectCost;
        peonsAvailable -= architects;
    }

    int bishops = 0;
    if (!onlyCorsair) {
        int peonParts;
        if (round <= 50) {
            peonParts = 20;
        } else if (round <= 70) {
            peonParts = 15;
        } else if (round <= 90) {
            peonParts = 10;
        } else if (round <= 95) {
            peonParts = 5;
        } else {
            peonParts = 3;
        }
        int peonsLeft = Math.max(0, thisTown.getPeons() - (necros + corsairs + architects));
        bishops = (int) Math.min(Math.min(peonsAvailable, peonsLeft / peonParts), goldAvailable / (GOLD_RECRUIT_BISHOP + GOLD_PER_CONVERSION - GOLD_PER_BISHOP));
    }

    if (corsairs > 0 || bishops > 0 || necros > 0 || architects > 0) {
        System.out.println("R 0 0 0 " + corsairs + " " + bishops + " " + necros + " " + architects);
    } else {
        System.out.println("W");
    }
}

private int calcCashflow(Town town) {
    int taxes = (town.getSurvivingPeons() * GOLD_PER_PEON);
    taxes += ((town.getWarlocks() + town.getBishops() + town.getNecros()) * (town.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE));
    taxes += ((town.getCrusaders() + town.getAmazons()) * (town.getBarracks() * GOLD_PER_BARRACKS));
    taxes += ((town.getSurvivingPeons() + town.getCorsairs()) * (town.getEstate() * GOLD_PER_ESTATE));
    taxes += (town.getPalace() * GOLD_PER_PALACE);

    int wages = calcWages(town);

    return taxes + wages;
}

private int calcWages(Town town) {
    int wages = (town.getWarlocks() * GOLD_PER_WARLOCK);
    wages += (town.getCrusaders() * GOLD_PER_CRUSADER);
    wages += (town.getAmazons() * GOLD_PER_AMAZON);
    wages += (town.getCorsairs() * GOLD_PER_CORSAIR);
    wages += (town.getBishops() * GOLD_PER_BISHOP);
    wages += (town.getNecros() * GOLD_PER_NECRO);
    wages += (town.getArchitects() * GOLD_PER_ARCHITECT);
    return wages;
}

private int calcCorsairSpread(Town calcTown) {
    int outlaws = 0;
    for (Town town : outlawTowns) {
        outlaws += town.getPopulation();
    }

    return (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * Math.floorDiv(outlaws, (playerTowns.size() + myTowns.size())) / CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO);
}

private int calcCorsairsNeeded(Town town) {
    return Math.max(0, calcCorsairSpread(town) - town.getCorsairs());
}

private int calcFreeCorsairs(Town town) {
    return Math.max(0, town.getCorsairs() - calcCorsairSpread(town));
}

private int calcOtherNecrosNeeded() {
    int necrosNeed = 0;
    for (Town town : myTowns) {
        if (town == thisTown) {
            continue;
        }
        necrosNeed += Math.max(0, (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * town.getCorpses() / NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY) - town.getNecros());
    }
    int necrosAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getNecros() - (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * thisTown.getCorpses() / NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY));
    return Math.max(0, necrosNeed - necrosAvailable);
}

private int calcOtherCorsairsNeeded() {
    int corsairsNeed = 0;
    for (Town town : myTowns) {
        if (town == thisTown) {
            continue;
        }
        corsairsNeed += calcCorsairsNeeded(town);
    }
    return Math.max(0, corsairsNeed - calcFreeCorsairs(thisTown));
}

private void convert() {
    // C destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons
    final int MIN_CONVERT_PERCENTAGE = 10;

    int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - thisTown.getCorpses() * GOLD_PER_RESURRECTION - GOLD_COST_BUILDING
            - (calcCashflow(thisTown) < GOLD_MAX_DEBT ? (calcCorsairsNeeded(thisTown) * CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO * GOLD_PER_STEAL) : 0);
    if (goldAvailable < 0) {
        System.out.println("W");
        return;
    }

    final int canConvert = Math.min(thisTown.getBishops(), goldAvailable / GOLD_PER_CONVERSION);
    if (canConvert == 0) {
        System.out.println("W");
        return;
    }

    List<Town> useTowns = calcStrongestPlayers();

    List<Town> afterFilter = useTowns.stream().filter(a -> a.getSoldiers() > canConvert / MIN_CONVERT_PERCENTAGE).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if (afterFilter.size() == 0) {
        if (playerTowns.size() > 0) {
            useTowns = playerTowns;
        } else {
            useTowns = outlawTowns;
        }
    }
    afterFilter = useTowns.stream().filter(a -> a.getSoldiers() > canConvert).collect(Collectors.toList());
    float getNear = 1.0f;
    while (afterFilter.size() == 0) {
        getNear -= 0.1f;
        final float toLower = getNear;
        afterFilter = useTowns.stream().filter(a -> a.getSoldiers() > canConvert * toLower).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    Town smallestTown = afterFilter.stream().min((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();

    Town convertTown;
    if (smallestTown.getSoldiers() < canConvert / MIN_CONVERT_PERCENTAGE) {
        convertTown = useTowns.stream().max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();
    } else {
        convertTown = smallestTown;
    }

    int leftToConvert = canConvert;
    int warlocks = Math.min(leftToConvert, convertTown.getWarlocks());
    leftToConvert -= warlocks;
    int crusaders = Math.min(leftToConvert, convertTown.getCrusaders());
    leftToConvert -= crusaders;
    int amazons = Math.min(leftToConvert, convertTown.getAmazons());
    leftToConvert -= amazons;

    System.out.println("C " + convertTown.getId() + " " + warlocks + " " + crusaders + " " + amazons);
}

private void attack() {
    // A destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons

    Town strongestTown;
    if (playerTowns.size() > 0) {
        strongestTown = playerTowns.stream().max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();
        if (thisTown.getSoldiers() / 3 <= strongestTown.getSoldiers()) {
            System.out.println("W");
            return;
        }
    }

    strongestTown = calcStrongestPlayers().stream().max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();

    int warlockNeed = strongestTown.getWarlocks() + strongestTown.getAmazons();
    int crusaderNeed = strongestTown.getCrusaders() + strongestTown.getWarlocks();
    int amazonNeed = strongestTown.getAmazons() + strongestTown.getCrusaders();
    int deltaWarlocks = thisTown.getWarlocks() - warlockNeed;
    int deltaCrusaders = thisTown.getCrusaders() - crusaderNeed;
    int deltaAmazons = thisTown.getAmazons() - amazonNeed;

    if ((deltaWarlocks + deltaCrusaders + deltaAmazons) > 0) {
        // calc Needed Troops
        int warlocks = Math.min(thisTown.getWarlocks(), warlockNeed);
        int crusaders = Math.min(thisTown.getCrusaders(), crusaderNeed);
        int amazons = Math.min(thisTown.getAmazons(), amazonNeed);
        if ((warlocks + crusaders + amazons) == 0) {
            warlocks = 1;
            crusaders = 1;
            amazons = 1;
        } else {
            while (deltaWarlocks < 0 || deltaCrusaders < 0 || deltaAmazons < 0) {
                if (deltaWarlocks < 0) {
                    deltaCrusaders += deltaWarlocks;
                    crusaders -= deltaWarlocks;
                    deltaWarlocks = 0;
                }
                if (deltaCrusaders < 0) {
                    deltaAmazons += deltaCrusaders;
                    amazons -= deltaCrusaders;
                    deltaCrusaders = 0;
                }
                if (deltaAmazons < 0) {
                    deltaWarlocks += deltaAmazons;
                    warlocks -= deltaAmazons;
                    deltaAmazons = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("A " + strongestTown.getId() + " " + warlocks + " " + crusaders + " " + amazons);
    } else {
        System.out.println("W");
    }
}

private void resurrect() {
    // R corpses
    int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold();
    if (goldAvailable < 0) {
        System.out.println("W");
        return;
    }

    int raise = Math.min(thisTown.getCorpses(), goldAvailable / GOLD_PER_RESURRECTION);
    if (raise > 0) {
        System.out.println("R " + raise);
    } else {
        System.out.println("W");
    }
}

private void move() {
    if (myTowns.size() == 1) {
        System.out.println("W");
        return;
    }

    // M destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons corsairs bishops necros architects
    // T DestinationId Gold

    int thisStolenGold = calcCorsairsNeeded(thisTown) * CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO * GOLD_PER_STEAL;
    int thisGoldAvailable = Math.max(-GOLD_MAX_DEBT, thisTown.getGold() - thisStolenGold);
    int thisCashFlow = calcCashflow(thisTown);

    if (thisGoldAvailable + thisCashFlow <= 0) {
        // Give up the town
        Town sendToTown = myTowns.stream().filter(a -> a.getId() != thisTown.getId()).max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();
        System.out.print("M " + sendToTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getWarlocks() + " " + thisTown.getCrusaders() + " " + thisTown.getAmazons() + " " + thisTown.getCorsairs() + " "
                + thisTown.getBishops() + " " + thisTown.getNecros() + " " + thisTown.getArchitects());
        return;
    }
    thisGoldAvailable += thisCashFlow;

    int thisCostOfBishop = thisTown.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE + GOLD_PER_BISHOP;
    int thisCostOfNecro = thisTown.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE + GOLD_PER_NECRO;
    int thisCostOfWarlock = thisTown.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE + GOLD_PER_WARLOCK;
    int thisCostOfCrusader = thisTown.getBarracks() * GOLD_PER_BARRACKS + GOLD_PER_CRUSADER;
    int thisCostOfAmazon = thisTown.getBarracks() * GOLD_PER_BARRACKS + GOLD_PER_AMAZON;
    int thisCostOfCorsair = thisTown.getEstate() * GOLD_PER_ESTATE + GOLD_PER_CORSAIR;

    int thisCorsairsAvailable = calcFreeCorsairs(thisTown);
    int thisNecrosAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getNecros() - (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * thisTown.getCorpses() / NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY));
    int thisBishopsAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getBishops() - (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * thisTown.getPeons() / BISHOP_PRAYER_CAPACITY));
    int thisArchitectsAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getArchitects() - ARCHITECTS);

    int strongestTownSoldiers = 0;
    if (playerTowns.size() > 0) {
        Town strongestTown = playerTowns.stream().max((a, b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();
        strongestTownSoldiers = strongestTown.getSoldiers();
    }
    int thisSoldiersAvailable = Math.max(0, thisTown.getSoldiers() - strongestTownSoldiers);
    int thisWarlocksAvailable = thisSoldiersAvailable / 3;
    thisSoldiersAvailable -= thisWarlocksAvailable;
    int thisCrusadersAvailable = thisSoldiersAvailable / 2;
    thisSoldiersAvailable -= thisCrusadersAvailable;
    int thisAmazonsAvailable = thisSoldiersAvailable;
    int warlockDelta = thisWarlocksAvailable - thisTown.getWarlocks();
    int crusaderDelta = thisCrusadersAvailable - thisTown.getCrusaders();
    int amazonDelta = thisAmazonsAvailable - thisTown.getAmazons();
    while (warlockDelta > 0 || crusaderDelta > 0 || amazonDelta > 0) {
        if (warlockDelta > 0) {
            thisWarlocksAvailable -= warlockDelta;
            thisCrusadersAvailable += warlockDelta;
            crusaderDelta += warlockDelta;
            warlockDelta = 0;
        }
        if (crusaderDelta > 0) {
            thisCrusadersAvailable -= crusaderDelta;
            thisAmazonsAvailable += crusaderDelta;
            amazonDelta += crusaderDelta;
            crusaderDelta = 0;
        }
        if (amazonDelta > 0) {
            thisAmazonsAvailable -= amazonDelta;
            thisWarlocksAvailable += amazonDelta;
            warlockDelta += amazonDelta;
            amazonDelta = 0;
        }
    }

    // Calc loosing income for each x the town sends
    int tempThisGoldAvailable = thisGoldAvailable;
    if (thisCostOfCorsair > 0) {
        thisCorsairsAvailable = Math.min(thisCorsairsAvailable, tempThisGoldAvailable / thisCostOfCorsair);
        tempThisGoldAvailable -= thisCorsairsAvailable * thisCostOfCorsair;
    } // else dont plus the gold - would get too complicated
    if (thisCostOfWarlock > 0) {
        thisWarlocksAvailable = Math.min(thisWarlocksAvailable, tempThisGoldAvailable / thisCostOfWarlock);
        tempThisGoldAvailable -= thisWarlocksAvailable * thisCostOfWarlock;
    }
    if (thisCostOfCrusader > 0) {
        thisCrusadersAvailable = Math.min(thisCrusadersAvailable, tempThisGoldAvailable / thisCostOfCrusader);
        tempThisGoldAvailable -= thisCrusadersAvailable * thisCostOfCrusader;
    }
    if (thisCostOfAmazon > 0) {
        thisAmazonsAvailable = Math.min(thisAmazonsAvailable, tempThisGoldAvailable / thisCostOfAmazon);
        tempThisGoldAvailable -= thisAmazonsAvailable * thisCostOfAmazon;
    }
    if (thisCostOfNecro > 0) {
        thisNecrosAvailable = Math.min(thisNecrosAvailable, tempThisGoldAvailable / thisCostOfNecro);
        tempThisGoldAvailable -= thisNecrosAvailable * thisCostOfNecro;
    }
    if (thisCostOfBishop > 0) {
        thisBishopsAvailable = Math.min(thisBishopsAvailable, tempThisGoldAvailable / thisCostOfBishop);
        tempThisGoldAvailable -= thisBishopsAvailable * thisCostOfBishop;
    }

    boolean checkGoldNeed;
    boolean needsGold;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        checkGoldNeed = i == 0;
        for (Town town : myTowns) {
            if (town == thisTown) {
                continue;
            }
            needsGold = false;

            int costOfBishop = town.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE + GOLD_PER_BISHOP;
            int costOfNecro = town.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE + GOLD_PER_NECRO;
            int costOfWarlock = town.getTemple() * GOLD_PER_TEMPLE + GOLD_PER_WARLOCK;
            int costOfCrusader = town.getBarracks() * GOLD_PER_BARRACKS + GOLD_PER_CRUSADER;
            int costOfAmazon = town.getBarracks() * GOLD_PER_BARRACKS + GOLD_PER_AMAZON;
            int costOfCorsair = town.getEstate() * GOLD_PER_ESTATE + GOLD_PER_CORSAIR;

            int corsairsNeed = calcCorsairsNeeded(town);
            int sendCorsairs = Math.min(corsairsNeed, thisCorsairsAvailable);
            int goldStolen = corsairsNeed * CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO * GOLD_PER_STEAL;
            int goldAvailable = town.getGold() - goldStolen;
            int goldAvailableWithCorsairs = Math.max(-GOLD_MAX_DEBT, goldAvailable + sendCorsairs * CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO * GOLD_PER_STEAL);
            goldAvailable = Math.max(-GOLD_MAX_DEBT, goldAvailable);
            int cashflow = calcCashflow(town);
            if (goldAvailable + cashflow < 0) {
                needsGold = true;
            }
            tryToSwim: if (goldAvailableWithCorsairs < 0) {
                int potentialCashflow = cashflow + sendCorsairs * costOfCorsair;
                if (goldAvailableWithCorsairs + potentialCashflow >= 0) {
                    break tryToSwim;
                } else {
                    int potentialGoldAvailable = goldAvailableWithCorsairs + potentialCashflow;
                    if (costOfWarlock > 0) {
                        potentialGoldAvailable += thisWarlocksAvailable * costOfWarlock;
                    }
                    if (costOfCrusader > 0) {
                        potentialGoldAvailable += thisCrusadersAvailable * costOfCrusader;
                    }
                    if (costOfAmazon > 0) {
                        potentialGoldAvailable += thisAmazonsAvailable * costOfAmazon;
                    }
                    if (costOfNecro > 0) {
                        potentialGoldAvailable += thisNecrosAvailable * costOfNecro;
                    }
                    if (costOfBishop > 0) {
                        potentialGoldAvailable += thisBishopsAvailable * costOfBishop;
                    }
                    if (potentialGoldAvailable >= 0) {
                        System.out.print("M " + town.getId() + " " + thisWarlocksAvailable + " " + thisCrusadersAvailable + " " + thisAmazonsAvailable + " " + sendCorsairs + " "
                                + thisBishopsAvailable + " " + thisNecrosAvailable + " 0");
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // Last hope, check if enough gold can rescue the town from revolt
                int goldNeeded = -(town.getGold() - goldStolen + cashflow);
                if (thisGoldAvailable >= goldNeeded) {
                    System.out.println("T " + town.getId() + " " + goldNeeded);
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("W");
                continue;
            }

            if (checkGoldNeed && !needsGold) {
                continue;
            }

            goldAvailable = goldAvailableWithCorsairs;
            goldAvailable += cashflow + sendCorsairs * costOfCorsair;
            int sendNecros = 0;
            int sendBishops = 0;
            int sendWarlocks = 0;
            int sendCrusaders = 0;
            int sendAmazons = 0;
            int sendArchitects = 0;

            int soldiersNeed = Math.max(0, strongestTownSoldiers - town.getSoldiers());
            int lastNeededSoldiers = 0;
            while (soldiersNeed > 0 && (thisWarlocksAvailable > 0 || thisCrusadersAvailable > 0 || thisAmazonsAvailable > 0) && soldiersNeed != lastNeededSoldiers) {
                lastNeededSoldiers = soldiersNeed;
                if (thisWarlocksAvailable > 0) {
                    goldAvailable += costOfWarlock;
                    if (goldAvailable < 0) {
                        goldAvailable -= costOfWarlock;
                    } else {
                        soldiersNeed--;
                        thisWarlocksAvailable--;
                        sendWarlocks++;
                    }
                }
                if (thisCrusadersAvailable > 0) {
                    goldAvailable += costOfCrusader;
                    if (goldAvailable < 0) {
                        goldAvailable -= costOfCrusader;
                    } else {
                        soldiersNeed--;
                        thisCrusadersAvailable--;
                        sendCrusaders++;
                    }
                }
                if (thisAmazonsAvailable > 0) {
                    goldAvailable += costOfAmazon;
                    if (goldAvailable < 0) {
                        goldAvailable -= costOfAmazon;
                    } else {
                        soldiersNeed--;
                        thisAmazonsAvailable--;
                        sendAmazons++;
                    }
                }
            }

            int necrosNeed = Math.max(0, (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * town.getCorpses() / NECRO_RAISE_CAPACITY) - town.getNecros());
            int necrosCanAfford = costOfNecro < 0 ? Math.min(necrosNeed, goldAvailable / -costOfNecro) : necrosNeed;
            if (necrosCanAfford > 0) {
                sendNecros = Math.min(necrosCanAfford, thisNecrosAvailable);
                goldAvailable += sendNecros * costOfNecro;
            }

            int bishopsNeed = Math.max(0, (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * town.getPeons() / BISHOP_PRAYER_CAPACITY) - town.getBishops());
            int bishopsCanAfford = costOfBishop < 0 ? Math.min(bishopsNeed, goldAvailable / -costOfBishop) : bishopsNeed;
            if (bishopsCanAfford > 0) {
                sendBishops = Math.min(bishopsCanAfford, thisBishopsAvailable);
                goldAvailable += sendBishops * costOfBishop;
            }

            int architectsNeed = Math.max(0, (int) Math.ceil(1.0 * COMPLETION_NEEDED / COMPLETION_PER_ARCHITECT) - thisTown.getArchitects());
            int architectsCanAfford = Math.min(architectsNeed, goldAvailable / Math.abs(GOLD_PER_ARCHITECT));
            sendArchitects = Math.min(architectsCanAfford, thisArchitectsAvailable);

            if (sendWarlocks > 0 || sendCrusaders > 0 || sendAmazons > 0 || sendCorsairs > 0 || sendBishops > 0 || sendNecros > 0 || sendArchitects > 0) {
                System.out.print("M " + town.getId() + " " + sendWarlocks + " " + sendCrusaders + " " + sendAmazons + " " + sendCorsairs + " " + sendBishops + " " + sendNecros + " "
                        + sendArchitects);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("W");
}

private void build() {
    // B building building building...
    // (T: Temple, B: Barracks, E: Estate, P: Palace)

    int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (calcCashflow(thisTown) < GOLD_MAX_DEBT ? (calcCorsairsNeeded(thisTown) * CORSAIR_SURVEILLANCE_RATIO * GOLD_PER_STEAL) : 0);
    if (goldAvailable >= GOLD_COST_BUILDING) {
        char building = 'E';
        int templeUnits = thisTown.getWarlocks() + thisTown.getBishops() + thisTown.getNecros();
        int barracksUnits = thisTown.getCrusaders() + thisTown.getAmazons();
        int estateUnits = thisTown.getCorsairs() + thisTown.getPeons();
        if (templeUnits > barracksUnits) {
            if (templeUnits > estateUnits) {
                building = 'T';
            }
        } else {
            if (barracksUnits > estateUnits) {
                building = 'B';
            }
        }
        System.out.println("B " + building);
    } else {
        System.out.println("W");
    }
}

private class Town {

    private final int ownerId;
    private final int id;
    private final int gold;
    private final int corpses;
    private final int warlocks;
    private final int crusaders;
    private final int amazons;
    private final int corsairs;
    private final int bishops;
    private final int necros;
    private final int architects;
    private final int peons;
    private final int temple;
    private final int barracks;
    private final int estate;
    private final int palace;

    public Town(String string) {
        String[] args = string.split("_");
        ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        warlocks = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
        crusaders = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
        amazons = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
        corsairs = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
        bishops = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
        necros = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
        architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
        peons = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
        temple = Integer.parseInt(args[12]);
        barracks = Integer.parseInt(args[13]);
        estate = Integer.parseInt(args[14]);
        palace = Integer.parseInt(args[15]);
    }

    public int getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getGold() {
        return gold;
    }

    public int getCorpses() {
        return corpses;
    }

    public int getWarlocks() {
        return warlocks;
    }

    public int getCrusaders() {
        return crusaders;
    }

    public int getAmazons() {
        return amazons;
    }

    public int getCorsairs() {
        return corsairs;
    }

    public int getBishops() {
        return bishops;
    }

    public int getNecros() {
        return necros;
    }

    public int getArchitects() {
        return architects;
    }

    public int getPeons() {
        return peons;
    }

    public int getSurvivingPeons() {
        int peons = this.peons;
        int zombies = Math.floorDiv(corpses, ZOMBIE_WAKING_CHANCE);
        peons = Math.max(0, peons - zombies);
        int demons = Math.floorDiv(peons - (bishops * BISHOP_PRAYER_CAPACITY), DEMON_SUMMON_CHANCE);
        peons = Math.max(0, peons - demons);
        if (round % BIRTH_ROUND == 0) {
            peons += Math.floorDiv(peons, 2);
        }
        return peons;
    }

    public int getTemple() {
        return temple;
    }

    public int getBarracks() {
        return barracks;
    }

    public int getEstate() {
        return estate;
    }

    public int getPalace() {
        return palace;
    }

    public int getSoldiers() {
        return getWarlocks() + getCrusaders() + getAmazons();
    }

    public int getUnits() {
        return getSoldiers() + getCorsairs() + getBishops() + getNecros() + getArchitects();
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return getUnits() + getPeons();
    }

    public boolean isMine() {
        return getOwnerId() == playerID;
    }

    public boolean isThisTown() {
        return id == thisTownID;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I was working on something like this. Am I correct in saying this gets crazy rich?

Comment: Yeah, it gets really really much income xD

Answer (score 4):

## Butter

This butter acts much the same as the previous butter. Unlike the previous butter, this gets rich uncommonly fast. Unfortunately, the Young Earls, along with the Lannisters, like butter on their waffles. Therefore, butter is quickly consumed.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Butter {

    int round;
    int phase;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;

    public Butter(String... args) {
        args = args[0].split(";");

        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13");
        } else {
            System.out.println(new Butter(args[0]).spread());
        }
    }

    private String spread() {

        if (phase == 2) {               // Steal
            //Command : S destinationId corsairs
            return steal();
        } else if (phase == 3) {        // Recruit
            //Command : R warlocks crusaders amazons corsairs bishops necromancers architects
            return recruit()    ;
        } else if (phase == 6) {        // Convert
            //Command : C destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons
            return convert();
        } else if (phase == 7) {        // Attack
            //Command : A destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons
            return attack();
        } else if (phase == 8) {        // Resurrect
            //Command : R corpses
            return resurrect();
        } else if (phase == 9) {        // Move
            //Command : M destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons corsairs bishops necromancers architects
            return move();
        } else if (phase == 11) {       // Build
            //Command : B building building building... (T: Temple, B: Barracks, E: Estate, P: Palace)
            return build();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException(phase + "");
    }

    private String steal() {
        if (thisTown.getCorsairs() <= 0){
            return "W";
        }
        int mostGold = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Town richestTown = null;
        for (Town town : otherTowns){
            if (town.getGold() > mostGold){
                mostGold = town.getGold();
                richestTown = town;
            }
        }
        return "S " + richestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getCorsairs();
    }

    private String recruit() {
        int gold = thisTown.getFreeGold();

        int peons = thisTown.getPeons();
        int warlocks = thisTown.getWarlocks();
        int crusaders = thisTown.getCrusaders();
        int amazons = thisTown.getAmazons();
        int corsairs = thisTown.getCorsairs();
        int bishops = thisTown.getBishops();
        int necromancers = thisTown.getNecromancers();
        int architects = thisTown.getArchitects();

        int totalPeople = peons+warlocks+crusaders+amazons+corsairs+bishops+necromancers+architects;
        int averagePeople = totalPeople / 8;
        int extraPeons = peons - averagePeople;
        if (extraPeons <= 0 || gold <= 0){
            return "W";
        }

        int warlocksToAdd = warlocks < averagePeople ? 0 : warlocks - averagePeople;
        int crusadersToAdd = crusaders < averagePeople ? 0 : crusaders - averagePeople;
        int amazonsToAdd = amazons < averagePeople ? 0 : amazons - averagePeople;
        int corsairsToAdd = corsairs < averagePeople ? 0 : corsairs - averagePeople;
        int bishopsToAdd = bishops < averagePeople ? 0 : bishops - averagePeople;
        int necromancersToAdd = necromancers < averagePeople ? 0 : necromancers - averagePeople;
        int architectsToAdd = architects < averagePeople ? 0 : architects - averagePeople;

        warlocksToAdd = warlocksToAdd * 11 > gold ? gold / 11 : warlocksToAdd;
        gold -= warlocksToAdd * 11;
        crusadersToAdd = crusadersToAdd * 11 > gold ? gold / 11 : crusadersToAdd;
        gold -= crusadersToAdd * 11;
        amazonsToAdd = amazonsToAdd * 11 > gold ? gold / 11 : amazonsToAdd;
        gold -= amazonsToAdd * 11;
        corsairsToAdd = corsairsToAdd * 14 > gold ? gold / 14 : corsairsToAdd;
        gold -= corsairsToAdd * 14;
        bishopsToAdd = bishopsToAdd * 22 > gold ? gold / 22 : bishopsToAdd;
        gold -= bishopsToAdd * 22;
        necromancersToAdd = necromancersToAdd * 22 > gold ? gold / 22: necromancersToAdd;
        gold -= necromancersToAdd * 22;
        architectsToAdd = architectsToAdd * 17 > gold ? gold / 17 : architectsToAdd;
        gold -= architectsToAdd * 17;

        warlocksToAdd = warlocksToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : warlocksToAdd;
        extraPeons -= warlocksToAdd;
        crusadersToAdd = crusadersToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : crusadersToAdd;
        extraPeons -= crusadersToAdd;
        amazonsToAdd = amazonsToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : amazonsToAdd;
        extraPeons -= amazonsToAdd;
        corsairsToAdd = corsairsToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : corsairsToAdd;
        extraPeons -= corsairsToAdd;
        bishopsToAdd = bishopsToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : bishopsToAdd;
        extraPeons -= bishopsToAdd;
        necromancersToAdd = necromancersToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : necromancersToAdd;
        extraPeons -= necromancersToAdd;
        architectsToAdd = architectsToAdd > extraPeons ? extraPeons : architectsToAdd;

        return "R " + warlocksToAdd + " " + crusadersToAdd + " " + amazonsToAdd + " " + corsairsToAdd + " " +
                bishopsToAdd + " " + necromancersToAdd + " " + architectsToAdd;
    }

    private String convert() {
        return "W";
    }

    private String attack() {
        for (Town town : otherTowns){
            if (town.getSoldiers() * 4 < thisTown.getSoldiers()){
                return "A " + town.getId() + " " + thisTown.getWarlocks() / 2 + " " + thisTown.getCrusaders() / 2 + " "
                        + thisTown.getAmazons() / 2;
            }
        }
        return "W";
    }

    private String move() {
        int totalWarlocks = 0;
        int totalCrusaders = 0;
        int totalAmazons = 0;
        int totalCorsairs = 0;
        int totalBishops = 0;
        int totalNecromancers = 0;
        int totalArchitects = 0;
        for (Town town : myTowns){
            totalWarlocks += town.getWarlocks();
            totalCrusaders += town.getCrusaders();
            totalAmazons += town.getAmazons();
            totalCorsairs += town.getCorsairs();
            totalBishops += town.getBishops();
            totalNecromancers += town.getNecromancers();
            totalArchitects += town.getArchitects();
        }
        int averageWarlocks = totalWarlocks / myTowns.size();
        int averageCrusaders = totalCrusaders / myTowns.size();
        int averageAmazons = totalAmazons / myTowns.size();
        int averageCorsairs = totalCorsairs / myTowns.size();
        int averageBishops = totalBishops / myTowns.size();
        int averageNecromancers = totalNecromancers / myTowns.size();
        int averageArchitects = totalArchitects / myTowns.size();

        Town worstTown = null;
        int biggestDifference = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Town town : myTowns){
            int difference = 0;
            difference += town.getWarlocks() < averageWarlocks ? averageWarlocks - town.getWarlocks() : 0;
            difference += town.getCrusaders() < averageCrusaders ? averageCrusaders - town.getCrusaders() : 0;
            difference += town.getAmazons() < averageAmazons ? averageAmazons - town.getAmazons() : 0;
            difference += town.getCorsairs() < averageCorsairs ? averageCorsairs - town.getCorsairs() : 0;
            difference += town.getBishops() < averageBishops ? averageBishops - town.getBishops() : 0;
            difference += town.getNecromancers() < averageNecromancers ? averageNecromancers - town.getNecromancers() :
                    0;
            difference += town.getArchitects() < averageArchitects ? averageArchitects - town.getArchitects() : 0;
            if (difference > biggestDifference){
                worstTown = town;
                biggestDifference = difference;
            }
        }
        int neededWarlocks = worstTown.getWarlocks() < averageWarlocks ? averageWarlocks - worstTown.getWarlocks() : 0;
        int neededCrusaders = worstTown.getCrusaders() < averageCrusaders ? averageCrusaders - worstTown.getCrusaders()
                : 0;
        int neededAmazons = worstTown.getAmazons() < averageAmazons ? averageAmazons - worstTown.getAmazons() : 0;
        int neededCorsairs = worstTown.getCorsairs() < averageCorsairs ? averageCorsairs - worstTown.getCorsairs() : 0;
        int neededBishops = worstTown.getBishops() < averageBishops ? averageBishops - worstTown.getBishops() : 0;
        int neededNecromancers = worstTown.getNecromancers() < averageNecromancers ? averageNecromancers - worstTown.
                getNecromancers() : 0;
        int neededArchitects = worstTown.getArchitects() < averageArchitects ? averageArchitects - worstTown.
                getArchitects() : 0;
        return "M " + worstTown.getId() + " " + neededWarlocks + " " + neededCrusaders + " " + neededAmazons + " " +
                neededCorsairs + " " + neededBishops + " " + neededNecromancers + " " + neededArchitects;
    }

    private String resurrect() {
        return "R " + thisTown.getCorpses();
    }

    private String build() {
        if (thisTown.getGold() > 500){
            return "B P";
        }
        if (thisTown.getGold() > 200){
            return "B T";
        }
        return "W";
    }

    private class Town {

        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int gold;
        private final int corpses;
        private final int warlocks;
        private final int crusaders;
        private final int amazons;
        private final int corsairs;
        private final int bishops;
        private final int necromancers;
        private final int architects;
        private final int peons;
        private final int temples;
        private final int barracks;
        private final int estates;
        private final int palaces;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            warlocks = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            crusaders = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
            amazons = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
            corsairs = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
            bishops = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
            necromancers = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
            architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
            peons = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
            temples = Integer.parseInt(args[12]);
            barracks = Integer.parseInt(args[13]);
            estates = Integer.parseInt(args[14]);
            palaces = Integer.parseInt(args[15]);
        }
        public int getOwnerId() {
            return ownerId;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public int getGold() {
            return gold;
        }
        public int getCorpses() {
            return corpses;
        }
        public int getWarlocks() {
            return warlocks;
        }
        public int getCrusaders() {
            return crusaders;
        }
        public int getAmazons() {
            return amazons;
        }
        public int getCorsairs() {
            return corsairs;
        }
        public int getBishops() {
            return bishops;
        }
        public int getNecromancers() {
            return necromancers;
        }
        public int getArchitects() {
            return architects;
        }
        public int getPeons() {
            return peons;
        }
        public int getTemples() {
            return temples;
        }
        public int getBarracks() {
            return barracks;
        }
        public int getEstates() {
            return estates;
        }
        public int getPalaces() {
            return palaces;
        }
        public int getBuildings() {
            return getTemples() + getBarracks() + getEstates() + getPalaces();
        }
        public int getSoldiers() {
            return getWarlocks() + getCrusaders() + getAmazons();
        }
        public int getUnits() {
            return getSoldiers() + getCorsairs() + getBishops() + getNecromancers() + getArchitects();
        }
        public int getCitizens() {
            return getUnits() + getPeons();
        }
        public boolean isMine(){
            return getOwnerId() == playerID;
        }
        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }
        public int neededGold(){
            return 2 * getUnits() - getSoldiers();
        }
        public int getFreeGold(){
            return gold - neededGold();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Commander, Java

Commander is one of the 2 default bots I created along with the controller (the other one being Sleeper who does nothing). Commander is a conqueror and he'll try to use every last of his resources to reach complete domination.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Commander {

    int round;
    int phase;
    int playerID;
    int thisTownID;

    List<Town> towns;
    List<Town> myTowns;
    List<Town> otherTowns;

    Town thisTown;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("15 10 12 10 7 5 1 40");
        } else {
            new Commander().conquer(args[0].split(";"));
        }
    }

    private void conquer(String[] args) {

        round = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        phase = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        playerID = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        thisTownID = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        towns = new ArrayList<>();
        myTowns = new ArrayList<>();
        otherTowns = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 4; i < args.length; i++){
            towns.add(new Town(args[i]));
        }

        for (Town town : towns){
            if (town.isMine()){
                myTowns.add(town);
                if (town.isThisTown()){
                    thisTown = town;
                }
            } else {
                otherTowns.add(town);
            }
        }

        if (phase == 2) {               // Steal
            //Command : S destinationId corsairs
            steal();
        } else if (phase == 3) {        // Recruit
            //Command : R warlocks crusaders amazons corsairs bishops necromancers architects
            recruit()   ;
        } else if (phase == 6) {        // Convert
            //Command : C destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons 
            convert();
        } else if (phase == 7) {        // Attack
            //Command : A destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons
            attack();   
        } else if (phase == 8) {        // Resurrect
            //Command : R corpses
            resurrect();    
        } else if (phase == 9) {        // Move
            //Command : M destinationId warlocks crusaders amazons corsairs bishops necromancers architects
            move();
        } else if (phase == 11) {       // Build
            //Command : B building building building... (T: Temple, B: Barracks, E: Estate, P: Palace)
            build();
        }
    }

    private void steal() {
        Town richestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.gold - b.gold).get();
        System.out.println("S " + richestTown.getId() + " " + thisTown.getCorsairs());
    }

    private void recruit() {

        int maxUnitsToRecruits = Math.floorDiv(thisTown.getPeons() - thisTown.getUnits(), 2);
        int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (thisTown.getUnits() * 5);
        int unitsRecruited = 0;
        int cost = 10;
        int[] recruits = new int[3];
        int i = 0;
        int necromancers = Math.max(0, 5 - thisTown.getNecromancers());
        while (goldAvailable >= 0 && unitsRecruited <= maxUnitsToRecruits) {
             i = (i >= recruits.length - 1 ? 0 : i+1);
             recruits[i]++;
             unitsRecruited++;
             goldAvailable-=cost;
        }
        if (unitsRecruited > 0) {
            System.out.println("R " + recruits[0] + " " + recruits[1] + " " + recruits[2] + " 0 0 " +  necromancers + " 0");
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }

    private void convert() {

        Town biggestTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.getCitizens() - b.getCitizens()).get();
        int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (thisTown.getUnits() * 5);
        int bishopsAvailable = thisTown.getBishops();
        int unitsConverted = 0;
        int cost = 50;
        int[] converts = new int[3];
        int i = 0;
        while (goldAvailable >= 0 && unitsConverted <= bishopsAvailable) {
             i = (i >= converts.length - 1 ? 0 : i+1);
             converts[i]++;
             goldAvailable-=cost;
        }
        System.out.println("C " + biggestTown.getId() + " " + converts[0] + " " + converts[1] + " " + converts[2]);  
    }

    private void attack() {

        Town lessDefendedTown = otherTowns.stream().max((a,b) -> a.getSoldiers() - b.getSoldiers()).get();
        int neededWarlocks =  thisTown.getWarlocks() - lessDefendedTown.getWarlocks();
        int neededCrusaders = thisTown.getCrusaders() - lessDefendedTown.getCrusaders();
        int neededAmazons = thisTown.getAmazons() - lessDefendedTown.getAmazons() ;

        if (neededWarlocks > 0 && neededCrusaders > 0 && neededAmazons > 0) {
            System.out.println("A " + lessDefendedTown.getId() + " " + (lessDefendedTown.getWarlocks() + 1) + " " + (lessDefendedTown.getCrusaders() + 1) + " " + (lessDefendedTown.getAmazons() + 1));  
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }

    }

    private void move() {
        System.out.println("W");
    }

    private void resurrect() {
        int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (thisTown.getUnits() * 5);
        int corpsesAvailable = thisTown.getCorpses();
        int availableNecromancers = thisTown.getNecromancers();
        int raiseCapacity = availableNecromancers * 5;
        int raisedCorpses = 0;
        while (corpsesAvailable >= 0 && raiseCapacity >= 0 && goldAvailable >= 0) {
            raisedCorpses++;
            corpsesAvailable--;
            goldAvailable -= 20;
            raiseCapacity--;
        }
        if (raisedCorpses > 0) {
            System.out.println("R " + raisedCorpses);
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }

    private void build() {
        int goldAvailable = thisTown.getGold() - (thisTown.getUnits() * 5);
        if (goldAvailable >= 400) {
            System.out.println("B B");
        } else {
            System.out.println("W");
        }
    }

    private class Town {

        private final int ownerId;
        private final int id;
        private final int gold;
        private final int corpses;
        private final int warlocks;
        private final int crusaders;
        private final int amazons;
        private final int corsairs;
        private final int bishops;
        private final int necromancers;
        private final int architects;
        private final int peons;
        private final int temples;
        private final int barracks;
        private final int estates;
        private final int palaces;

        public Town(String string){
            String[] args = string.split("_");
            ownerId = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            id = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            gold = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            corpses = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            warlocks = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            crusaders = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
            amazons = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);
            corsairs = Integer.parseInt(args[7]);
            bishops = Integer.parseInt(args[8]);
            necromancers = Integer.parseInt(args[9]);
            architects = Integer.parseInt(args[10]);
            peons = Integer.parseInt(args[11]);
            temples = Integer.parseInt(args[12]);
            barracks = Integer.parseInt(args[13]);
            estates = Integer.parseInt(args[14]);
            palaces = Integer.parseInt(args[15]);
        }
        public int getOwnerId() {
            return ownerId;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public int getGold() {
            return gold;
        }
        public int getCorpses() {
            return corpses;
        }
        public int getWarlocks() {
            return warlocks;
        }
        public int getCrusaders() {
            return crusaders;
        }
        public int getAmazons() {
            return amazons;
        }
        public int getCorsairs() {
            return corsairs;
        }
        public int getBishops() {
            return bishops;
        }
        public int getNecromancers() {
            return necromancers;
        }
        public int getArchitects() {
            return architects;
        }
        public int getPeons() {
            return peons;
        }
        public int getTemples() {
            return temples;
        }
        public int getBarracks() {
            return barracks;
        }
        public int getEstates() {
            return estates;
        }
        public int getPalaces() {
            return palaces;
        }
        public int getBuildings() {
            return getTemples() + getBarracks() + getEstates() + getPalaces();
        }
        public int getSoldiers() {
            return getWarlocks() + getCrusaders() + getAmazons();
        }
        public int getUnits() {
             return getSoldiers() + getCorsairs() + getBishops() + getNecromancers() + getArchitects();
        }
        public int getCitizens() {
            return getUnits() + getPeons();
        }
        public boolean isMine(){
            return getOwnerId() == playerID;
        }
        public boolean isThisTown(){
            return id == thisTownID;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Machiavelli, Python 2

Lord Machiavelli is experienced in the politics and military domains required
to succeed. He has developed a complex logic that directs his cunning strategy,
now he watches from the shadows as his plan unfolds...

```
import sys, re
from random import *
from operator import itemgetter
import cPickle

(PLAYER, TOWN, GOLD, CORPSES, WARLOCKS, CRUSADERS, AMAZONS, 
CORSAIRS, BISHOPS, NECROMANCERS, ARCHITECTS, PEONS, 
TEMPLES, BARRACKS, ESTATES, PALACES) = range(16)

def getfighters(t): return sum(t[WARLOCKS:WARLOCKS+3])
def threat(t): return t[2] + sum(t[4:12])*12 + sum(t[12:16])*200
def spyon(t): return ( t[2] + min(30,t[3])*5 + t[11]*10 + 
    sum(t[12:16])*200 - getfighters(t)*20 )
def needs(t): return [bandits/5+1, t[PEONS]/50+1, t[CORPSES]/5+1, 7]
def wants(t): return [max(0, g-h) for g,h in zip(needs(t), t[7:11])]
def helpcheck(t): return sum(wants(t))

def choose(frequency, picks, span):
    'Return <picks> counts using samples from <frequency> in list <span>'
    choices = [choice(frequency) for i in range(picks)]
    return [choices.count(i) for i in range(span)]

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 5, 15, 10, 20, 3, 4, 7, 36
else:
    parts = sys.argv[1].split(';')
    turn, phase, me, thistown = [int(parts.pop(0)) for i in range(4)]
    towns = [map(int, re.split(r'_', town)) for town in parts]
    # Analysis:
    enemy = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] != me]
    mytowns = [t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] == me]
    here = [t for t in mytowns if t[TOWN] == thistown][0]
    otherids = [t[TOWN] for t in enemy]
    fighters = sorted(enemy, key=getfighters)
    rich = sorted(enemy, key=itemgetter(GOLD))
    threats = sorted(enemy, key=threat)
    attractive = sorted(enemy, key=spyon)
    # Useful numbers:
    avgfighters = sum(map(getfighters, enemy)) / len(enemy)
    wages = getfighters(here) + sum(here[CORSAIRS:CORSAIRS+4]) * 2
    outlaws = sum(sum(t[4:12]) for t in towns if t[PLAYER] == -1)
    freetowns = len([t for t in towns if t[PLAYER] != -1])
    bandits = outlaws / freetowns
    # Depends on above
    needhelp = sorted(mytowns, key=helpcheck)
    needhelp.remove(here)

    try:
        plans = cPickle.load(open('Machiavelli.txt', 'rb'))
    except:
        plans = {}
    bribes, raises, gobuild = plans.get(thistown, (0,0,''))

    output = 'W'
    if phase == 2:
        output = 'S %s 100' % rich[-1][TOWN]  # take from the rich ...
    elif phase == 3:
        # Decide strategy here:
        cash = here[GOLD] - wages
        forces = getfighters(here)
        raises = min(here[NECROMANCERS]*5, here[CORPSES], cash/20)
        cash -= raises * 20
        bribes = trainftr = trainextra = 0
        gobuild = ''
        if forces < avgfighters:
            bribes = min(here[BISHOPS], cash/50)
            cash -= bribes * 50
            trainftr = min(max(0, here[PEONS]-30), cash/10)
            cash -= trainftr * 10
        if cash > 200 and turn % 2 == 0:
            gobuild = choice('EEB')
            cash -= 200
        bribes2 = min(here[BISHOPS] - bribes, cash/50)
        cash -= bribes2 * 50
        bribes += bribes2
        trainextra = min(max(0, here[PEONS]-30), cash/50)
        # Write plan to file:
        plans[thistown] = (bribes, raises, gobuild)
        cPickle.dump(plans, open('Machiavelli.txt', 'wb'), -1)

        # Output recruitment decision:
        if trainftr + trainextra:
            getutil = wants(here)
            if sum(getutil) > trainextra:
                utilbias = ( [0]*getutil[0]*3 + [1]*getutil[1]*3 + 
                            [2]*(getutil[2]) + [3]*(getutil[3]) )
                getutil = choose(utilbias, trainextra, 4)
            getftr = choose([0,1,1,2], trainftr, 3)
            getpers = getftr + getutil
            if sum(getutil) < trainextra:
                othernum = trainextra - sum(getutil)
                others = choose([0,1,1,2,3,4,6], othernum, 7)
                getpers = [p+q for p,q in zip(getpers, others)]
            output = 'R %u %u %u %u %u %u %u' % tuple(getpers)
    elif phase == 6:
        if bribes:
            soldiers = choose([0,1,2], bribes, 3)
            target = fighters[-1][TOWN]
            output = 'C %s %s %s %s' % tuple([target] + soldiers)
    elif phase == 7:
        if getfighters(here) > avgfighters * 1.3:
            myarmy = here[WARLOCKS : WARLOCKS+3]
            raiders = sum(myarmy) / 2
            for n in range(raiders):
                force = [min(myarmy[i], n) for i in (0,1,2)]
                if sum(force) >= raiders:
                    break
            for target in attractive[::-1]:
                if raiders > getfighters(target) * 2.5:
                    output = 'A %s %s %s %s' % tuple([target[TOWN]] + force)
                    break
    elif phase == 8:
        if raises:
            output = 'R %s' % raises
    elif phase == 9:
        if needhelp:
            town = needhelp[-1]
            excess = [max(0, g-h) for g,h in zip(here[7:11], needs(here))]
            send = [min(g, h) for g,h in zip(excess, wants(town))]
            if sum(send) > 0:
                output = 'M %u 0 0 0 %u %u %u %u' % tuple([town[TOWN]] + send)
    elif phase == 11:   
        if gobuild:
            output = 'B %s' % gobuild
    print output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Monarch (Ruby)

Monarch is more than a mere King, so he'll not fight others until he's sure that his army can crush his opponents and show his overwhelming power. Meanwhile, he gets cozy in his base and asks for tributes from the insignificant insects. Anf of course, he likes Ruby and rubies.

```ruby
$BONUS = 1.5
class Town

  attr_accessor :player, :town, :gold, :corpses, :warlocks, :crusaders, :amazons, 
    :corsairs, :bishops, :necromancers, :architects, :peons, :temples, :barracks, 
    :estates, :palaces

  def initialize(arg)
    args = arg.split("_")
    @player = args[0].to_i
    @town = args[1].to_i
    @gold = args[2].to_i
    @corpses = args[3].to_i
    @warlocks = args[4].to_i
    @crusaders = args[5].to_i
    @amazons = args[6].to_i
    @corsairs = args[7].to_i
    @bishops = args[8].to_i
    @necromancers = args[9].to_i
    @architects = args[10].to_i
    @peons = args[11].to_i
    @temples = args[12].to_i
    @barracks = args[13].to_i
    @estates = args[14].to_i
    @palaces = args[15].to_i
  end  
  def soldiers
    @warlocks + @crusaders + @amazons
  end 
  def units
    self.soldiers + @corsairs + @bishops + @necromancers + @architects
  end  
  def citizens
    self.units + @peons
  end  
  def buildings
    @temples + @barracks + @estates + @palaces
  end
  def cash
    @gold - (self.units * 2) - 50
  end
  def flesh
    @peons - (self.units * 2 / 5)
  end
end

def stronger(aW, aC, aA, dW, dC, dA)
  aW - [[0, aW - dW].max, dA].min + ([[0, aW - dW].max, dA].min * $BONUS) + aC - [[0, aC - dC].max, dW].min + ([[0, aC - dC].max, dW].min * $BONUS) + aA - [[0, aA - dA].max, dC].min + ([[0, aA - dA].max, dC].min * $BONUS)  > dW - [[0, dW - aW].max, aA].min + ([[0, dW - aW].max, aA].min * $BONUS) + dC - [[0, dC - aC].max, aW].min + ([[0, dC - aC].max, aW].min * $BONUS) + dA - [[0, dA - aA].max, aC].min + ([[0, dA - aA].max, aC].min * $BONUS) 
end

if ARGV.size < 1 
  puts "12 12 12 8 2 2 2 50"
else
  args = ARGV[0].split(";")

  round = args[0].to_i
  phase = args[1].to_i
  thisPlayer = args[2].to_i
  thisTownId = args[3].to_i
  towns, myTowns, enemyTowns = Array.new, Array.new, Array.new

  args[4..-1].each {|arg|arg.split(";").each {|t|towns.push(Town.new(t))}}
  towns.each {|town|town.player == thisPlayer ? myTowns.push(town) : enemyTowns.push(town)}
  thisTown = towns[towns.index{|t|t.town == thisTownId}]
  strongestTown = enemyTowns.sort{|x,y|y.soldiers<=>x.soldiers}.fetch(0)  
  weakestTown = enemyTowns.sort{|x,y|x.soldiers<=>y.soldiers}.fetch(0)  
  baseTown = myTowns.sort{|x,y|y.peons<=>x.peons}.fetch(0)    

  case phase
  when 2
    puts "S " + strongestTown.town.to_s + " " + thisTown.corsairs.to_s
  when 3
    if (thisTown.cash > 90)
      recruits = [[(thisTown.cash - 90) / 10, thisTown.flesh].min / 5, 0].max
      puts "R " + recruits.to_s + " " + recruits.to_s + " " + (recruits*3).to_s + " " + [0, 2 - thisTown.corsairs].max.to_s + " " + [0, 2 - thisTown.bishops].max.to_s + " " + [0, 2 - thisTown.necromancers].max.to_s + " " + [0, 2 - thisTown.architects].max.to_s
    else
      puts "W"
    end
  when 6
    converts = [[thisTown.cash / 50, thisTown.bishops].min / 5, 0].max
    puts "C " + strongestTown.town.to_s + " " + (converts*3).to_s + " " + converts.to_s + " " + converts.to_s
  when 7
    if round > 10
      if stronger(thisTown.warlocks / 6, thisTown.crusaders / 6, thisTown.amazons / 6, strongestTown.warlocks, strongestTown.crusaders, strongestTown.amazons)
        puts "A " + strongestTown.town.to_s + " " +  (thisTown.warlocks/4).to_s + " " + (thisTown.crusaders/4).to_s + " " + (thisTown.amazons/4).to_s
      elsif stronger(thisTown.warlocks / 6, thisTown.crusaders / 6, thisTown.amazons / 6, weakestTown.warlocks, weakestTown.crusaders, weakestTown.amazons)
        puts "A " + weakestTown.town.to_s + " " +  (thisTown.warlocks/4).to_s + " " + (thisTown.crusaders/4).to_s + " " + (thisTown.amazons/4).to_s
      else
        puts "W"
      end
    else
      puts "W"
    end
  when 8
    puts "R 10"
  when 9
    if thisTown.town != baseTown.town
      if thisTown.soldiers > 0 
        puts "M " + baseTown.town.to_s + " " + thisTown.warlocks.to_s + " " + thisTown.crusaders.to_s + " " + thisTown.amazons.to_s
      else
        puts "T " + baseTown.town.to_s + " " + thisTown.cash
      end
    else
      puts "W"
    end
  when 11
    if thisTown.town == baseTown.town and thisTown.cash > 200 
      puts "B B" 
    else
      puts "W"
    end
  else
    puts "W"
  end
end
```

To run this script, you need a Ruby 1.9.3 interpreter.

Run with : `ruby Monarch.rb`

Answer (score 1):

I only can write 30000 signs in one answer xD
So here are my bugs that i found:

Moogie already reported this one: `int totalConvertible = (warlocksConvertible + crusadersConvertible + amazonsConvertible);`

executeMovement: `if (source.getCorsairs() >= corsairsCount) {`

executeTheft: used Source instead of Destination. But could you check, if the calculation is correct then? My recommendation would be: `int goldReserve = destination.getGold() + GOLD_MAX_DEBT > 0 ? destination.getGold() + GOLD_MAX_DEBT : GOLD_MAX_DEBT - Math.abs(destination.getGold());`

And executeRecruitment had an bug, that if the town had not enough peons, they could recruit more than they had peons, if they could afford the recruitment.
So I rewrote the method that it concerns peons and gold available:

```
private void executeRecruitment(Command support) {

    Town source = support.getSource();
    try {
        String[] args = support.getArgs();

        if (support.getCommand().equals("R") && args.length == 7) {
            int goldAvailable = source.getGold();
            if (goldAvailable <= 0) {
                return;
            }

            int warlocksCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
            int crusadersCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
            int amazonsCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
            int corsairsCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[3]));
            int bishopsCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[4]));
            int necromancersCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[5]));
            int architectsCount = Math.max(0, Integer.parseInt(args[6]));

            int originalWarlocksCount = warlocksCount;
            int originalCrusadersCount = crusadersCount;
            int originalAmazonsCount = amazonsCount;
            int originalCorsairsCount = corsairsCount;
            int originalBishopsCount = bishopsCount;
            int originalNecromancersCount = necromancersCount;
            int originalArchitectsCount = architectsCount;

            int unitsToRecruits = warlocksCount + crusadersCount + amazonsCount + corsairsCount + bishopsCount + necromancersCount + architectsCount;
            int peonsAvailable = source.getPeons();
            int recruitableUnits = Math.min(unitsToRecruits, peonsAvailable);
            if (recruitableUnits != unitsToRecruits) {
                RandomNumberGenerator random = new RandomNumberGenerator();
                int[] recruits = random.genNumberWithLimits(recruitableUnits, new int[] { warlocksCount, crusadersCount, amazonsCount, corsairsCount, bishopsCount, necromancersCount,
                        architectsCount });
                warlocksCount = recruits[0];
                crusadersCount = recruits[1];
                amazonsCount = recruits[2];
                corsairsCount = recruits[3];
                bishopsCount = recruits[4];
                necromancersCount = recruits[5];
                architectsCount = recruits[6];
            }

            int wouldCost;
            int index = 1;
            boolean tooExpensive = true;
            do {
                wouldCost = warlocksCount * GOLD_RECRUIT_WARLOCK + crusadersCount * GOLD_RECRUIT_CRUSADER + amazonsCount * GOLD_RECRUIT_AMAZON + corsairsCount * GOLD_RECRUIT_CORSAIR
                        + bishopsCount * GOLD_PER_BISHOP + necromancersCount * GOLD_RECRUIT_NECROMANCER + architectsCount * GOLD_RECRUIT_ARCHITECT;
                if (goldAvailable < wouldCost) {
                    RandomNumberGenerator random = new RandomNumberGenerator();
                    int[] recruits = random.genNumberWithLimits(recruitableUnits - index, new int[] { originalWarlocksCount, originalCrusadersCount, originalAmazonsCount, originalCorsairsCount,
                            originalBishopsCount, originalNecromancersCount, originalArchitectsCount });
                    warlocksCount = recruits[0];
                    crusadersCount = recruits[1];
                    amazonsCount = recruits[2];
                    corsairsCount = recruits[3];
                    bishopsCount = recruits[4];
                    necromancersCount = recruits[5];
                    architectsCount = recruits[6];
                } else {
                    tooExpensive = false;
                }
                index++;
            } while (tooExpensive);

            int recruted = warlocksCount + crusadersCount + amazonsCount + corsairsCount + bishopsCount + necromancersCount + architectsCount;
            if (recruted > 0) {
                source.setWarlocks(source.getWarlocks() + warlocksCount);
                source.setCrusaders(source.getCrusaders() + crusadersCount);
                source.setAmazons(source.getAmazons() + amazonsCount);
                source.setCorsairs(source.getCorsairs() + corsairsCount);
                source.setBishops(source.getBishops() + bishopsCount);
                source.setNecromancers(source.getNecromancers() + necromancersCount);
                source.setArchitects(source.getArchitects() + architectsCount);
                source.setPeons(source.getPeons() - recruted);
                source.setGold(source.getGold() - wouldCost);

                if (GAME_MESSAGES)
                    System.out.println(source.getOwner().getDisplayName() + " recruted " + recruted + " units (" + warlocksCount + " Wa / " + crusadersCount + " Cr / " + amazonsCount + " Am / "
                            + corsairsCount + " Co / " + bishopsCount + " Bi / " + necromancersCount + " Ne / " + architectsCount + " Ar)");
            }
        } else if (support.getCommand().equals("W")) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            if (DEBUG)
                System.out.println("Phase " + phase + " (Recruitment) : Invalid command by " + source.getOwner().getDisplayName() + "{" + source.getId() + "}");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Exception in executeRecruitment() by " + source.getOwner().getDisplayName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for taking the time to check the controller (Thanks @Moogie too). I've applied your corrections and will run several test games in a few hours.